# How to exclude a key from an interface in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript, you can combine two interface types like this

```
interface Foo {
    var1: string
}

interface Bar {
    var2: string
}

type Combined = Foo & Bar
```

Instead of combining keys, I want to exclude keys from one interface to another. Is there anyway you can do it in TypeScript?

The reason is, I have an HOC, which manages a property value for other wrapped component like this

```
export default function valueHOC<P> (
  Comp: React.ComponentClass<P> | React.StatelessComponent<P>
): React.ComponentClass<P> {
  return class WrappedComponent extends React.Component<P, State> {
    render () {
      return (
        <Comp
          {...this.props}
          value={this.state.value}
        />
      )
    }
}
```

With that I can write

```
const ValuedComponent = valueHOC(MyComponent)
```

then

```
<ValuedComponent />
```

but the problem is, the returned component type is also using the props type from given component, so TypeScript will complain and ask me to provide the `value` prop. As a result, I will have to write something like

```
<ValuedComponent value="foo" />
```

Which the value will not be used anyway. What I want here is to return an interface without specific keys, I want to have something like this

```
React.ComponentClass<P - {value: string}>
```

Then the `value` will not be needed in the returned component. Is it possible in TypeScript for now?

Comment: You may check out `Pick<T, K keyof T>`. But you can't pick things out dynamically.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

In TypeScript 2.8 you can now do the following:

```
interface Foo {
    attribute1: string;
    optional2?: string;
    excludePlease: string;
}

// Typescript 3.5+ defines Omit for you.
// In earlier Typescript versions define Omit:
// type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>

// Use Omit to exclude one or more fields (use "excludePlease"|"field2"|"field3" etc to exclude multiple)
type Bar = Omit<Foo, "excludePlease">
const b: Bar = {
    attribute1: ''
};
```

So in relation to your question the following might be what you want:

```
export default function valueHOC<P> (
  Comp: React.ComponentClass<P> | React.StatelessComponent<P>
): React.ComponentClass<Omit<P, "value">> {
  return class WrappedComponent extends React.Component<Omit<P, "value">, State> {
    render () {
      return (
        <Comp
          {...this.props}
          value={this.state.value}
        />
      )
    }
}
```

Comment: Whilst this works, it will make optional parameters required. You can do this to prevent that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48216010/616589

Comment: I don't dispute the accuracy of the answer, but that's an absurdly round the houses way of achieving a simple end - it will take anyone reading it some non-trivial amount of time to work out just what the hell is going in. Is there any logic at all as to why the typescript team went this way?

Comment: @havlock sorry I recently edited it to simplify and improve the answer but I forget to also use the simplified `Omit` code in the simplify example.  Is that better now?

Comment: @AJP I was moaning about typescript, not your answer, but thanks - yes, that is slightly more straightforward. Still absolutely bonkers that they make us jump through such ridiculous syntax to achieve something simple - I fear for the language if they really think this sort of thing is OK.

Comment: @havlock :)  Would be interesting to see examples of other typed languages where this is dealt with better :)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work well when combining the props type back together.

'Pick<OuterProps, Exclude<keyof OuterProps, "c">> & { c: number; }' is not assignable to type 'OuterProps'

http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgBIHkDCAFKB7ABwGdkBvAKGWQQC5kQBXAWwCNoBucgX3PJgZAIwwPCGQALPAgA86BpCi5CJCAA9IIACYkMOfMQB8ACgL6idOQqXEAlGUrIwATwIoAkiBDRrJALzJ0JmAwWXlvMwAaZABrCCc8GDQsHwNOKigIMAYoMSNQL0UzOg8CnztfA3sqKgRRIjBHCHqaS3DlZH8KauqAOj78tuIIh27aZABGEeQuNOnuIA

Comment: apparently there is already a bug for this: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28938

Answer (score 20):

```
interface MyDialogProps extends Omit<DialogProps, 'onClose'> {
  id: string;
  onClose: (reason: string) => void;
}

export const MyDialog: React.FC<MyDialogProps> = ({ id, onClose, ...props) => (
  <Dialog onClose={() => onClose("whatever")} {...props} />
);
```

Comment: this should be the accepter answer, as well as Fabio's. The accepted answer creates a Type and not an Interface!

Answer (score 14):

#### Example with several properties to "omit" using only `interface`

```js
interface ABC {
    a: string;
    b: string;
    c: string;
}

type PropsABCOmitted = 'a' | 'c';
interface BD extends Omit<ABC, PropsABCOmitted> {
    d: string;
}

// instance example of interface BD:
const test: BD = {
    b: 'b',
    d: 'c'
};
```

Answer (score 7):

There is [utility-types](https://github.com/piotrwitek/utility-types) library that has `Subtract` mapped type:

```
import { Subtract } from 'utility-types';

type Props = { name: string; age: number; visible: boolean };
type DefaultProps = { age: number };

type RequiredProps = Subtract<Props, DefaultProps>;
// Expect: { name: string; visible: boolean; }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't remove properties from already existing interfaces. Even trying to extend existing interface with the interface having `value` property set as optional will return an error.

To avoid this issue, modify the typings of the target component so `value` property is optional.

e.g.

```
// ...
class MyComponent extends React.Component<{value?: string}, State> {
// ...
}
```

and then component produced when using High Order Function

```
const valuedComponent = valueHOC(MyComponent);
```

won't ask for `value` prop.