# Exclude property from type

Tags: typescript

I'd like to exclude a single property from the type. How can I do that?

For example I have

```ts
interface XYZ {
  x: number;
  y: number;
  z: number;
}
```

And I want to exclude property `z` to get

```ts
type XY = { x: number, y: number };
```

Answer (score 795, accepted):

### For versions of TypeScript at or above 3.5

In TypeScript 3.5, the [`Omit`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) type was added to the standard library. See examples below for how to use it.

### For versions of TypeScript below 3.5

In TypeScript 2.8, the `Exclude` type was added to the standard library, which allows an omission type to be written simply as:

```
type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>
```

### For versions of TypeScript below 2.8

You cannot use the `Exclude` type in versions below 2.8, but you can create a replacement for it in order to use the same sort of definition as above. However, this replacement will only work for string types, so it is not as powerful as `Exclude`.

```
// Functionally the same as Exclude, but for strings only.
type Diff<T extends string, U extends string> = ({[P in T]: P } & {[P in U]: never } & { [x: string]: never })[T]
type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Diff<keyof T, K>>
```

---

And an example of that type in use:

```
interface Test {
    a: string;
    b: number;
    c: boolean;
}

// Omit a single property:
type OmitA = Omit<Test, "a">; // Equivalent to: {b: number, c: boolean}

// Or, to omit multiple properties:
type OmitAB = Omit<Test, "a"|"b">; // Equivalent to: {c: boolean}
```

Comment: Great! You are declaring `Diff<T, U>` (with `T` and `U` as types available for keys) as a `T`-keyed subset of an intersection of 3 types: type with key same as a value for `T`, type with `never` for `U` and type with `never` for all keys. Then you pass it through indexer to get correct values types. Am I right?

Comment: Yep! But this does have a drawback. For example, `Omit<{a?: string, b?: boolean}, "b">` results in `{a: string | undefined}`, which still accepts `undefined` as a value, but loses the optional modifier on `a`. :(

Comment: That's sad.. Interesting that way with declare and spread keeps optional modifier... Is there some other way to keep it?

Comment: Replace your `Omit` by `type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Diff<keyof T, K>>;` and it'll be perfect :)

Comment: @Qwertiy It works! Many thanks! I edited the post. But I wonder what the difference was, since what was there was literally identical to the type definition for `Pick` as far as I can see.

Comment: I don't see a definition of `Pick` in [news](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html), but in the [code](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/f6603cd9f2bc4a30705a682e446b2cb04dfe3fc4/src/lib/es5.d.ts#L1320) it's really the same...

Comment: Excellent! I believe this should be used in any introduction to advanced Typescript!

Comment: Note that only properties are considered.  The new type will not contain any calling signatures of the original type.

Comment: Note that for TS 3.5, the standard library's definition of `Omit` differs from that given here. In the stdlib, it is `type Omit<T, K extends keyof any> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;` The change, while slight, [has caused some debate](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30825), so be aware of the difference.

Comment: Note that this doesn't complain if the property you are trying exclude doesn't exist. For example, `Omit<Test, "doesNotExist">` is still valid. If you don't want that, you can use `StrictOmit` from [ts-essentials](https://github.com/krzkaczor/ts-essentials#StrictOmit) instead. This is useful if you want to make sure renaming the property accidentally doesn't break the omit rule.

Comment: @CRice Could you please have a look at my issue as you seems quite good with this.

Answer (score 180):

Omit ...

##### single property

```
type T1 = Omit<XYZ, "z"> // { x: number; y: number; }
```

##### multiple properties

```
type T2 = Omit<XYZ, "y" | "z"> // { x: number; }
```

##### properties conditionally

e.g. all string types:

```
type Keys_StringExcluded<T> = 
  { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends string ? never : K }[keyof T]

type XYZ = { x: number; y: string; z: number; }
type T3a = Pick<XYZ, Keys_StringExcluded<XYZ>> // { x: number; z: number; }
```

Shorter version with TS 4.1 [key remapping / `as` clause](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-1/#key-remapping-mapped-types) in mapped types ([PR](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40336)):

```
type T3b = { [K in keyof XYZ as XYZ[K] extends string ? never : K]: XYZ[K] } 
// { x: number; z: number; }
```

##### properties by `string` pattern

e.g. exclude getters (props with 'get' string prefixes)

```
type OmitGet<T> = {[K in keyof T as K extends `get${infer _}` ? never : K]: T[K]}

type XYZ2 = { getA: number; b: string; getC: boolean; }
type T4 = OmitGet<XYZ2> //  { b: string; }
```

Note: Above [template literal types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40336) are supported with TS 4.1. You can [also write](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gtgS2AcQsAPAFQHxQLxQDeUA2gNJQIB2UA1hCAPYBmUmUAhgM5QUQAewCFQAmPAAYBzNABJCXYACdqkgL7ioAfihUIANwiKoALl4BdU5nJmoqgFChIUABoBNAFr4iUacACCplQArnAARoYA3FChpgrKVJJRvgDCpqGMjAA2EBxUUfaO0JgALF7wSKgYbu64APS1UN4xUHEq%20UA) `get${string}` instead of `get${infer _}` here.

##### More infos

[`Pick`, `Omit` and other utility types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html)

[How to Pick and rename certain keys using Typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59071058/how-to-pick-and-rename-certain-keys-using-typescript) (rename instead of exclude)

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAGgmgLSgXigbygDwFxQHYCuAtgEYQBOA3FCLgM7DkCWeA5tQF66GkXUC+AKEEB6EVACMuAKKYAxgBsCAE2h0WrBdDDkA9pHKhBoSFAAqElFADyRJsAA88BABooAIg7uAfFDHosbmIyKhog3lChUXEAJhl5JVUoIgIFYCYwLSgdfQp0iDpjcGgzGKtbeydEN3cQdygAHw8vX38MHHxgvih+KGF-AGYAQ1wAYV08ZXsmCaGFBRAoCASVbT0DfLooAFooAAsKaDmFKAZmNigTAqLTAGkIEDoAfQBlRg1ZRVXlBzNfVAwAG1blAWFAANYPXQAM3MAF1cGZgXClphgBBJlszhooAB+fAQABuFCguBB-EBkJAMPhNxKwysAAUmHJwVVXFB7o9Xu82J9EhAfs5vK1xO1wiFOBLulFBiRTntdIYScTyOoJlAAO72PbmF5QAAsADoJHTzAN5QCoMDQXgIVDYc4oEMts5kaj0ZjTrzWHiCarSZyEbBEO7em1Ap0IlKo5Kev1xAaoAAKMz640SACUYwmU3Ss3mi2WXySOQ2TAKUBIi2xFzAQ2A6PIdt2B3I0GLAqgrAgjYodBEAHIe8BB9l29CmJhrlcbHZgABxXu-f4BG1gqk0szOrYg5ae5RbAAGI4AJGgWNCSU9+Ee-XgiSSycGkbcUUJZ84ylaRwBBaWhCQ9A+tQI6jLgJC6LoWhDHgAhmmYSaoBUi7Ll+opQAEQHeuc7DxkAA)

Comment: You should get the Oscript

Answer (score 55):

With typescript 2.8, you can use the new built-in `Exclude` type. The [2.8 release notes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html) actually mention this in the section "Predefined conditional types":

> Note: The Exclude type is a proper implementation of the Diff type
>   suggested here. [...] We did not include the Omit type because
>   it is trivially written as `Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>`.

Applying this to your example, type XY could be defined as:

```
type XY = Pick<XYZ, Exclude<keyof XYZ, "z">>
```

Answer (score 31):

I've found [solution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20XYZ%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20x%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20y%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20z%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20var%20%7B%20z%2C%20...xy%20%7D%3A%20XYZ%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20XY%20%3D%20typeof%20xy%3B%20%2F%2F%20%7B%20x%3A%20number%3B%20y%3A%20number%3B%20%7D) with declaring some variables and using spread operator to infer type:

```
interface XYZ {
  x: number;
  y: number;
  z: number;
}

declare var { z, ...xy }: XYZ;

type XY = typeof xy; // { x: number; y: number; }
```

It works, but I would be glad to see a better solution.

Comment: This is a great pre-2.8 solution. `typeof` is one of the more underappreciated features of typescript.

Comment: Clever, I like it :)! (for pre 2.8)

Comment: How I can add z with type string in your result

Comment: @user602291, `type Smth = XY & { z: string };`?

Comment: This one is perfect for old version of typescript. I could not get the accpeted answer to work for 2.3, yet this one worked great.

Answer (score 15):

In [Typescript 3.5+](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-5-rc/#the-omit-helper-type):

```
interface TypographyProps {
    variant: string
    fontSize: number
}

type TypographyPropsMinusVariant = Omit<TypographyProps, "variant">
```

Answer (score 9):

If you prefer to use a library, use [ts-essentials](https://github.com/krzkaczor/ts-essentials).

```
import { Omit } from "ts-essentials";

type ComplexObject = {
  simple: number;
  nested: {
    a: string;
    array: [{ bar: number }];
  };
};

type SimplifiedComplexObject = Omit<ComplexObject, "nested">;

// Result:
// {
//  simple: number
// }

// if you want to Omit multiple properties just use union type:
type SimplifiedComplexObject = Omit<ComplexObject, "nested" | "simple">;

// Result:
// { } (empty type)
```

PS: You will find lots of other useful stuff there ;)

Answer (score 5):

## Typescript 3.5

As of Typescript 3.5, the Omit helper will be included: [TypeScript 3.5 RC - The Omit Helper Type](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-5-rc/#the-omit-helper-type)

You can use it directly, and you should remove your own definition of the Omit helper when updating.

Answer (score 3):

I do like that:

```
interface XYZ {
  x: number;
  y: number;
  z: number;
}
const a:XYZ = {x:1, y:2, z:3};
const { x, y, ...last } = a;
const { z, ...firstTwo} = a;
console.log(firstTwo, last);
```

Comment: what prints out from this?

Comment: @frlzjosh run it and find out?

Comment: Yes I should've updated myself on that regard. I ran it on an online typescript compiler. This is a great solution, although I have found Omit, and Picks to be more readable