# Generic type arguments in JSX elements with withStyles

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

In React with material-ui I am trying to create a JSX component that accepts generic parameters and also uses the `withStyles` HOC to inject my styles.

The first approach was like this:

```
const styles = (theme: Theme) => createStyles({
  card:    {
    ...
  }
});

interface Props<T> {
  prop: keyof T,
  ...
}

type PropsWithStyles<T> = Props<T> & WithStyles<typeof styles>;

export default withStyles(styles)(
    class BaseFormCard<T> extends React.Component<PropsWithStyles<T>> {
      ...
    }
),
```

But when trying to use this, the generic types are lost

```
<BaseFormCard<MyClass> prop={ /* no typings here */ } />
```

The only solution I could find was to wrap the export in a function which takes the generic parameter and constructs the component.

```
export default function WrappedBaseFormCard<T>(props: Props<T>): ReactElement<Props<T>> {

  const wrapper = withStyles(styles)(
        class BaseFormCard<T> extends React.Component<PropsWithStyles<T>> {
          ...
        }
    ) as any;

  return React.createElement(wrapper, props);
}
```

However this is ridiculously complicated and even comes with runtime cost, although it is only trying to solve problems typings.

There has to be a better way to use JSX components with generic parameters and HOCs.

This is closely related to the issue here https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/11921, but there was never satisfying solution and the issue is now closed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The more I think about the question, the more I like [Frank Li's approach](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/11921#issuecomment-398566947).  I'd make two modifications: (1) introduce an extra SFC to avoid a cast, and (2) grab the outer props type from the wrapped component `C` instead of hard-coding it.  (If we hard-coded `Props<T>`, TypeScript would at least check that it is *compatible* with `this.C`, but we are at risk of requiring props that `this.C` doesn't actually require or failing to accept optional props that `this.C` actually accepts.)  It's jaw-dropping that referencing a property type from a type argument in the `extends` clause works, but it seems to!

```
class WrappedBaseFormCard<T> extends React.Component<
  // Or `PropsOf<WrappedBaseFormCard<T>["C"]>` from @material-ui/core if you don't mind the dependency.
  WrappedBaseFormCard<T>["C"] extends React.ComponentType<infer P> ? P : never,
  {}> {
  private readonly C = withStyles(styles)(
    // JSX.LibraryManagedAttributes handles defaultProps, etc.  If you don't
    // need that, you can use `BaseFormCard<T>["props"]` or hard-code the props type.
    (props: JSX.LibraryManagedAttributes<typeof BaseFormCard, BaseFormCard<T>["props"]>) =>
      <BaseFormCard<T> {...props} />);
  render() {
    return <this.C {...this.props} />;
  }
}
```

I think any complaints about runtime overhead of this approach are probably nonsense in the context of a whole React application; I'll believe them when someone presents data supporting them.

Note that Lukas Zech's approach using an SFC is very different: every time the props to the outer SFC change and it is called again, `withStyles` is called again, generating a `wrapper` that looks to React like a whole new component type, so React throws away the old `wrapper` instance and a new inner `BaseFormCard` component gets created.  This would have undesirable *behavior* (resetting state), not to mention greater runtime overhead.  (I haven't actually tested this, so let me know if I'm missing something.)

Comment: Thanks for point out the problem with my solution. The wrapper IS recreated every time the parent component renders, which of course renders the implementation useless.

Comment: Your solution seems to solve the problem and the runtime overhead for this seems neglectable.

It seems to be the best solution so far, tough it still is extremely complicated...

Answer (score 4):

This works enough for me using Visual Studio:

```
import React from "react";
import { withStyles, WithStyles } from "@material-ui/styles";

const styles = {
  root: { ... },
};

export interface Props<T> { ... }
export interface State<T> { ... }

export class TableComponent<T> extends React.PureComponent<Props<T> & WithStyles<typeof styles>, State<T>> {
  render () {
    return <div className={this.props.classes.root} />;
  }
}

export const Table = (withStyles(styles)(TableComponent) as any) as new <T>() => TableComponent<T>;

export default Table;
```

Comment: Nice. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that doesn't create a wrapper component. Instead it creates a type that is like the component type just without the 'classes' property.

```js
   // TypeUtils.tsx
   // from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48215950/exclude-property-from-type
   export type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>
```

Using this helper type you can create the type you want and cast your styled component to that type

```js
   type FixedCheckBoxType = <T>(props: Omit<FormCheckBoxProps<T>, 'classes'>) => JSX.Element;
   export const FormCheckBox = withStyles(checkboxStyles)(UnstyledFormCheckBox) as FixedCheckBoxType;
```

There might be a better way to do this, but ideally this would be done automatically by material-ui itself.

Answer (score 1):

There needs to be an overload of `withStyles` typings for every possible number of type parameters

Comment: And every possible combination of constraints for those type parameters.  Given that constraints can depend on other type parameters, this would require faking higher-kinded types.