# How to build up a target object from generic partials in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, generics, partial

I am using typescript@2.3.4.

I have a target object:

```
interface MyTarget {
    a: string;
    b: string;
    c: string;
    d: string;
}
```

I want to create multiple converts of partial objects using generics.

One such convert might look like this:

```
const convert = <T extends object>(t: T): MyTarget => {
    return {
        c: "c",
        d: "d",
        ...t,
    };
};
```

Yet this yields into:

```
error TS2698: Spread types may only be created from object types.
```

even though I guard the generic `T` to be an `object`.

I then remember that there is a `Partial` type, hence I tried this:

```
const convert = (partial: Partial<MyTarget>): MyTarget => {
    return {
        c: "c",
        d: "d",
        ...partial,
    };
};
```

Yet the `Partial` makes all properties optional. I don't want that and it would now throw:

```
src/Partial.ts(14,5): error TS2322: Type '{ a?: string; b?: string; c: string; d: string; }' is not assignable to type 'MyTarget'.
  Property 'a' is optional in type '{ a?: string; b?: string; c: string; d: string; }' but required in type 'MyTarget'.
```

I want to create an instance of `MyTarget` with every field set as an requirement. I do want to keep typesafety, which is why I don't want to this even though it works:

```
const convert = (partial: Partial<MyTarget>): MyTarget => {
    return {
        c: "c",
        d: "d",
        ...partial,
    } as MyTarget; // loses type checks, really don't want to
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using an older version of TS (in newer version spread expressions are typed correctly).

Regardless of this, the true issue is that the object literal might not be a full `MyTarget`. Your code would allow this call

```
convert({a : "" })// return value is not really MyTarget since it will not contain b
```

What you really want is the parameter to be  `MyTarget` except `c` and `d`:

```
interface MyTarget {
    a: string;
    b: string;
    c: string;
    d: string;
}
type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>
const convert = (t: Omit<MyTarget, 'c' | 'd'>) : MyTarget => {
    return {
        c: "c",
        d: "d",
        ...t,
    };
};
```

Comment: Nice one, shame though that [Exclude only exists since 2.8](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html). I am currently in no position to upgrade.

Comment: @k0pernikus Uh ..so really, really old (meaning 1  year +) I belive there is a version of `Omit` for older versions. What version exactly are you on ?

Comment: @k0pernikus here is a version of `Omit` for older versions, should be a drop in replacement, but I have not tested: http://ideasintosoftware.com/typescript-advanced-tricks/

Comment: The linked Omit type is not behaving as I expected: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54535539/how-to-create-an-omit-type-for-tsc2-3

Comment: The `typeof` approach pointed out here works fine: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48215951/457268

Comment: @k0pernikus creative solution if you don't mind the extra runtime stuff just to get the type. Guess I have become too spoiled with mapped and conditional types :)

Comment: We are still on 2.3 for this project, so no: I don't mind the extra runtime stuff at all. I embrace the performance impact to have another argument for a future upgrade ;)

Answer (score 0):

I went with [Qwertiy's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48215951/457268):

```
interface XYZ {
  x: number;
  y: number;
  z: number;
}

declare var { z, ...xy }: XYZ;

type XY = typeof xy; // { x: number; y: number;}
```

which works perfectly for tsc@2.3.