# How to create an Omit type for tsc@2.3?

Tags: typescript

Note: The [underlying issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54533141/how-to-build-up-a-target-object-from-generic-partials-in-typescript/54533227?noredirect=1#comment95868111_54533227) was asked separately. This is a follow-up to a provided solution.

---

Typescript allows to create an Omit type since 2.8 via `Exclude`.

I want to use Omit in on an older codebase using typescript@2.3.

On [this blog](http://ideasintosoftware.com/typescript-advanced-tricks/) an implementation is shown which is:

```
type Diff<T extends string, U extends string> = ({[P in T]: P } & {[P in U]: never } & { [x: string]: never })[T];  
type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Diff<keyof T, K>>;
```

Yet this one behaves weirdly for me, as:

```
inteface MyTarget {
    a: string;
    b: string;
    c: string;
}

type MyPartial = Omit<MyTarget, "a" | "b">;

const foo: MyPartial = {
    c: "foo",
};
```

will complain that my `foo` is lacking properties:

```
src/helper/types/Omit.ts(12,7): error TS2322: Type '{ c: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Pick<MyTarget, "a" | "b" | "c">'.
  Property 'a' is missing in type '{ c: string; }'.
```

Yet the whole idea is to generate a type that lacks certain fields.

How do I create a proper `Omit` type in TypeScript without upgrading to a more current typescript version?

Comment: Related or maybe even duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48215950/exclude-property-from-type

Comment: Hm in 2.4 `'a' & never`  resolves to `never`. In 2.3 `'a' & never`  resolved to `a`. I don't think we can do this in 2.3 :(