# Exclude extended properties from an interface

Tags: typescript

I have an interface `Contact` which extends `mongoose.Document` interface:

```html
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';

export interface Contact extends mongoose.Document {
    firstname: string;
    lastname: string;
    address: string;
    phone: string;
    email: string;
}
```

And sometimes, I need to use this interface `Contact` like below:

```html
const contacts: Contact[] = [
    {
        firstname: 'Marley',
        lastname: 'Schultz',
        address: '531 Walter Roads',
        phone: '1-898-444-3407 x33699'
        email: 'Deon_Hammes@gmail.com',
    }
];
```

Since `Contact` extends `mongoose.Document`, TypeScript complains that `mongoose.Document` ' s  properties  ( `increment`, `model`, `isDeleted`, ... ) are missing.

Is there a way to get a type from `Contact` but with `mongoose.Document` ' s properties excluded ?

Comment: An interface can extend multiple other interfaces, why not have `interface Contact { ... }` with the raw properties and `interface ContactDocument extends Contact, mongoose.Document {}`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe A good workaround, thank you!

Comment: You can use Pick<T, K> to pick out particularly properties of an interface, or build an Omit type which omits certain types: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48215950/exclude-property-from-type