# How to Omit a property from a type?

Tags: typescript, types

I have a question about the Omit type in Typescript, so I know the Omit type is the opposite of `Pick` and is build like this:

`type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>`

But I don't know how to construct a Omit type. I have an interface of `Student` that looks like this:

```
interface Student { 
name: string, 
surname: string, 
age: number, 
email: string 
}
```

I need a function that takes a Student as input with some given properties and outputs the Omited Student. The function should look like this:

`let omit_student = <K extends keyof Student>(student: Student, ...props: K[] ): Omit<Student, K> => null!`

But I don't know how I can dynamicaly omit the given properties from Student and what should happen in the body of the funtion.

Calling the function like this: `omit_student(student1, "name", "age")`
should output the following type:

```
{ 
surname: string, 
email: string 
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a common source on confusion that object types in TypeScript are not *exact* (as requested in [ms/TS#12936](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936)).  A value of type `Student` is *known* to have `name`, `surname`, `age`, and `email` properties of the appropriate types, but it is not known to have *only* these properties.  This allows you to [extend](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#extending-types) types by adding known properties to them:

```
interface Student { 
    name: string, 
    surname: string, 
    age: number, 
    email: string 
}

interface HogwartsStudent extends Student {
    house: string,
    spells: string[]
}
```

In the above, a `HogwartsStudent` is a special type of `Student`.  If I give you a `Student`, you don't know that she is *not* a `HogwartsStudent`, so you can't be sure that she has no `house` or `spells` property.

The `Omit<T, K>` type alias produces a *supertype* of `T`.  That is, `T` extends `Omit<T, K>`.  Every value of type `T` is also a value of type `Omit<T, K>`.  All you are "omitting" with `Omit<T, K>` is the known presence and type of properties with keys in `K`.

---

What you are asking for is not only to remove the known keys from the type, but to remove the actual properties from the produced object.  This needs to happen at runtime in exactly the way you'd do it in JavaScript:

```
function omit_student<K extends Array<keyof Student>>(
  student: Student, ...props: K): Omit<Student, K[number]> {
    const newStudent: Omit<Student, K[number]> = Object.assign({}, student);
    for (let prop of props) {
        delete (newStudent as any)[prop];
    }
    return newStudent;
}
```

Notice that I've used a [rest tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#tuples-in-rest-parameters-and-spread-expressions) for the `K` parameter, but you can probably do it your way also.

Answer (score 1):

To declare the `Omit` type use [CRice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48215950/exclude-property-from-type)'s answer:

```
interface Student { 
    name: string, 
    surname: string, 
    age: number, 
    email: string 
}

type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>

let student: Student = { name: "John", surname: "Doe", age: 21, email: "John.Doe@test.com" }
let omit_student: Omit<Student, "name" | "age"> = student
```

This will create a new type with only the `surname` and `email`. This will however only complain at compile-time (when using other properties than `surname` or `email`), you have to write a filter method yourself to comply with the interface you describe with `Omit`

```
function omitStudent(student: Student, ...args: string[]): Omit<Student, "name" | "age"> {
    for (let key of args) {
        delete student[key]
    }
    return student
}

console.log(student);
console.log(omitStudent(student, "name", "age"));
```

Though I realize this is probably not as 'dynamic' as you asked in the question.

Comment: The problem with this is that it doesn't do anything you just asign student to omit_student. when you `console.log(omit_student)` it prints the orignal student, with all the properties