# Is there a way to convert the underlying object when converting between types in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, javascript-objects

So lets say i have two interfaces

```
interface InterfaceOne {
     myString: string,
     myNum: number
}

interface interfaceTwo extends InterfaceOne {
     myBool: boolean
}
```

with the following typescript code

```
let somedata: interfaceTwo = {
     myString: "hello world",
     myNum: 42,
     myBool: false
```

is there a way I can convert `somedata` into a `InterfaceOne` while removing the key `myBool` from the object?

Comment: Every `InterfaceTwo` is an `InterfaceOne` so you don't have to remove anything from `somedata` to get that to happen.  But no matter what you do with interfaces, it won't affect the object at runtime; the type system from TS is erased upon compiling to JS.  If you want to delete properties you will have to do that explicitly.  See [this code](https://tsplay.dev/NDG8Vw).

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55704071/how-to-omit-a-property-from-a-type

Answer (score 0):

you can, but not how you have it. you are hardcoding InterfaceTwo in yow code, if you remove myBool it wont become interfaceOne, thats not how Object Oriented Programing works, instead it will throw an error. if you want yow var to be either A or B do not extend use both

```js
interface InterfaceOne {
    myString: string,
    myNum: number
}

interface InterfaceTwo {
    myBool: boolean
}


let somedata: InterfaceOne | InterfaceTwo = {
    myString: "hello world",
    myNum: 42,
    myBool: false
}
```