# TSLint error for destructuring in function parameters

Tags: typescript, parameter-passing, tslint, destructuring

I would like to remove the tslint error I get on the following (in the object desctructuring parameter):

```js
export function renameProperty(
    oldProp: string,
    newProp: string,
    {[oldProp]: old, ...others}
): any {
    return {
        [newProp]: old,
        ...others
    };
}
```

The error I get is on line 5:

`TSLint: expected parameter: '{[oldProp]: old, ...others}' to have a typedef (typedef)`

of course, I could do the following, but I'd rather simply do what satisfies Typescript's typing requirements.

```js
export function renameProperty(
    oldProp: string,
    newProp: string,
    // tslint:disable-next-line:typedef
    {[oldProp]: old, ...others}
): any {
    return {
        [newProp]: old,
        ...others
    };
}
```

Any answers on how to type def the `{[oldProp]: old, ...others}` line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question, but looks like there is no definitive answer. But here is one attempt:

```js
export function renameProperty<
    T extends {},
    OP extends keyof T,
    NP extends string,
    R = Omit<T, OP> & Record<NP, T[OP]>
>(oldProp: OP, newProp: NP, { [oldProp]: value, ...others }: T): R {
    return {
        [newProp]: value,
        ...others
    } as any; // *
}
```

This has advantage, that returns proper type with `oldProp` erased and `newProp` added.

i.e

```
const c = renameProperty("foo", "bar", { foo: 1, baz: "spam", holy: "grenade" });
console.log(c.foo, c.bar, c.baz, c.holy);
    /// complains here, that 'foo' is not available in c
    /// typeof c.bar === "number"
```

*
Unfortunately, TS is not able to infer proper type from `{[newProp]: value}`  and resulting type is `{ [x: string]: ... }` so unfortunately dreadful `as any` is needed (at least i didn't find a way to remove it - not sure if this is a bug or limitation).

`Omit`: [Exclude property from type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48215950/exclude-property-from-type)

Comment: @Zbigiew Zagorski :  I am on Typscript version 3.4.5, and according to the link you provided re: Omit, I added the following line to the top of the file containing the function. Does that sound correct?  -- `type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;`

Comment: @KimGentes: Yes, that's exactly what i meant. For some reason, `Omit` is not included in typescript library, so everyone have to repeat this when needed.

Comment: TS 3.5 will finally have Omit in standard library: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-5/#the-omit-helper-type

Comment: Thanks for letting me know!