# Type safety when omitting properties K from T

Tags: angular, typescript, types

#### Problem description

I have a scenario where I have a function that expects an object of Type `T` excluding certain properties of `T`.

I have managed to create a Type that exclude specific properties `K` from `T` without problem *(Following this explanation: [Exclude property from type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48215950/exclude-property-from-type))*

Now my problem is that Typescript won't give me a type error for when I expect it to, in some scenarios I can still pass an object with properties `K` that should be excluded.

#### Example

I'll provide a small scenario to illustrate:

Take the following types and the given interface:

```
export type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>

export type DataExclude<T, K extends keyof T> = Partial<Omit<T, K>>


export interface Data {
  ID: number,
  payload: any,
  size: number,
}
```

Now say I want a function that takes an argument of type `Data` excluding `"ID"`, I can write:

```
 printDataPartial(partialData: DataExclude<Data,"ID">){
    console.log(partialData)
 }
```

Now I expect this function to take an object with any property from `Data` except `"ID"` (and it doesn't have to be every property, hence the `Partial<>` in the `DataExclude` type). But it won't accept `ID` as a property

#### Result

Here are some use cases:

```
partialData: Partial<Data> = {payload: {stuff:'!!!'}, size: 99}
partialDataID: Partial<Data> = {ID:1, payload: {stuff:'???'}, size: 99}
fullData: Data = {ID: 2, payload: {stuff: "..."}, size: 42}


ngOnInit(){
    //OK
    this.printDataPartial(this.partialData, "Partial Data (no ID): ");

    //Not so OK, the partial data has ID in it
    this.printDataPartial(this.partialDataID, "Partial Data (with ID): ");

    //Not OK, always has ID so should give an error
    this.printDataPartial(this.fullData, "Full Data: ");

    //OK, gives an error because ID is present
    this.printDataPartial({ID: 3, payload: {stuff: "as it comes"}, size: 100}, "Manually typed object (with ID)");

    //Not OK, the same with casting
    this.printDataPartial(<Data>{ID: 3, payload: {stuff: "as it comes"}, size: 100}, "Manually typed object with casting (with ID): ");

    //I know this is an alternative to get a type error early but I'd like to know if there's a way do it differently as the function itself won't give me an error
    let partialIncorrect: DataExclude<Data,"ID"> =  {ID:4, payload: {stuff:'???'}, size: 99};   
    this.printDataPartial(partialIncorrect, "Incorrect on initialised: ")

  }
```

I also made a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nbwrar) to test easily.

---

In short, I would like to know if there's a way to get a type error to show up in the editor if the provided argument of the function has `ID` in its properties, and I would like to use type safety to do so, not just loop through each property of the given argument manually.

Comment: Omit only for type, if u need excluse it inoutput log, need write code for do it

Comment: I'm confused because my function parameter expects a type without the ID property, so it should give me an error in the editor, not at runtime, just like it does when I put the ID property manually in the object I pass in. Or am I missing something?