# React + Material-UI + Typescript: Inherit props from button to add different variants

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I would like to extend the default Material-UI button to add more variants such as "square."

How can I define the prop interface to inherit/combine props.

Here's my code:

```
import React from "react";
import { Button as MuiButton } from "@material-ui/core";
import { ButtonProps as MuiButtonProps } from "@material-ui/core/Button";

interface ButtonProps extends MuiButtonProps {
  variant?: "square";
}

const defaultProps = {};

const Button: React.FC<ButtonProps> = ({variant, children, ...props}) => {
  return (
    <MuiButton variant={variant} {...props}>
       {props.children}
    </MuiButton>;
  )
};

Button.defaultProps = defaultProps;

export default Button;
```

Ideally, I would like to use this component like so:

```
<ExtendedButton href="/" variant="square">Click Me!</ExtendedButton>
```

Answer (score 5):

The TYpeScript does not allows to override property when extending interfaces. So you should firstly exclude property from `MuiButtonProps` and then redefine it in `ButtonProps`.

```
import React from "react";
import { Button as MuiButton } from "@material-ui/core";
import { ButtonProps as MuiButtonProps } from "@material-ui/core/Button";

interface ButtonProps extends Pick<MuiButtonProps, Exclude<keyof MuiButtonProps, "variant">> {  
    variant?: "square" | MuiButtonProps["variant"];
}
```

Property exclusion with `Pick` and `Exclude` is for TypeScript 3.5 and below to 2.8. You may see [another options](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48216010/7141073) to exclude properties depending on TypeScript version you use.

And as you wish to extend current type of existing property `variant`, you can use index access operator to get type of original `variant` property to union it with additional `"square"` type.

Comment: This will not work, the variant property defined in MuiButtonProps is defined as: variant?: "text" | "outlined" | "contained". I would like to extend these props and add "square" as an option for my new component.

Comment: I've modified answer. Take a look please

Comment: When you pass the incoming prop that may include variant: "square" to the MuiButton, it will throw an error, right? Since it doesn't know "square". How do you filter out properties to match the type definition to a Mui component implementation that you are extending?