# Can you make a smaller, more restricted type from an existing type?

Tags: typescript, types

Assuming I have this type declaration:

```
type Foo = 'a' | 'b' | 'c';
type Bar = 'a' | 'b' ;
```

Is it possible to express `Bar` as a subset of `Foo` ?

I understand it's always possible to express `Foo` as a superset of `Bar`, but in my case the other way around would feel more in line with the domain.

Comment: Surprisingly, a dupe target exists for `Omit` but not for `Exclude` (which is what I think you are looking for). Writing an answer now... For reference: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48215950/4174897

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You simply have to use the `Exclude` [pre-defined conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#predefined-conditional-types):

```
type Foo = 'a' | 'b' | 'c';
type Bar = Exclude<Foo, 'c'>;

const Bar = 'a';
```

Do note that the following works fine, even if it may not feel right at first glance:

```
type Bar = Exclude<Foo, 'd'>
```

See [playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKByAhqqAfNAjLXVAY1QG4AoUSKAIXQCdkoBRAD2IBsBXAEwgA88OABo0pAHwUKxOADsAzsCgBbEADVGALjqNmGchSA).

---

You can also combine it with [index types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types) for interesting purposes:

```
type Foo = 'a' | 'b' | 'c';
type AnObject = { c: boolean }
type Bar = Exclude<Foo, keyof AnObject>

const myVar: Bar = "a";
```

Answer (score 2):

E.g.

```
type Bar = Exclude<Foo, 'c'>
```

(documented in https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#predefined-conditional-types)