# Can I change return type of method in extended class?

Tags: javascript, typescript, clean-architecture

I need class `B` extend interface `C`, however I would like to use implementation of `A::methodA` to calculate result of `B::methodA`.

```js
interface C {
  methodA(): number
}

class A {
  methodA(): string {
    return '42'
  }
}

class B extends A implements C {
  methodA(): string {
    return Number(super.methodA()).
  }
}
```

Can I use implementation of class `A` with inheritance or is association my only hope?

Comment: Can you make the names a bit of obvious in terms of what you _actually_ need to do? Because as presented, there is isn't really a reason to ever do this: `methodA` would normally have a name that, if propertly picked, already implies the result is going to be a string and having a subclass that also tries to implement a conflicting interface is just really weird.

Comment: Trying to make inheritance do this will be [painful and messy](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMLIN4Chm+QWwjAAsB7AEwEEAKASgC5kQBXfAI2iwF8ssEAbOAGchySphx5CJCjQbIhYKKADmEvBuRQizKCGQByACwAmA5Nw8eWAPQ3kSiHDBjkwt8gSkQiqMwRgpFDIpDAeAO7A5NAERGRUdHzeisgA+pSMIBDhyHTIALwAfLkA8vjAYAA8lAA0yABE0vGU9cUAZJixMgnyvqrIAD5MrBzBXLQFYgDcvALCogBCyBAAHpAg5KLpyMD4AA78EITgoujYGk2yeeeauNpguvoAciPQ1ELMe9AAdJc9tBZkFYsEA).  Inheritance is fragile for things like this; there's a reason people suggest composition instead.

Answer (score 0):

you can define the return type of method `A()` on interface `C` to `number | string,` it has to be a compatible return type.

```
interface C {
  methodA(): number | string
}

class A {
  methodA(): string {
    return '42'
  }
}

class B extends A implements C {
  methodA(): string {
    return super.methodA();
  }
}
```

EDIT: so considering your scenario below, it might not be the best solution but you could use the utility type [Omit](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittk) and create a new type from `C` to avoid the validation of `method1` (more examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48215950/exclude-property-from-type))

```
interface C {
  methodA(): number
  //methodB(): string,
  //methodC(): number
  //..
}
type C1 = Omit<C, "methodA">;

class A {
  methodA(): string {
    return '42'
  }
}

class B extends A implements C1 {
  methodA(): string {
    return super.methodA();
  }
}
```

Comment: good suggestion, however it will not work. Interface `C` is actually imported from a domain. My `A` and `B` classes actually use much more complicated types... and currently I am doing mapping from one type to another in class `B`.  Unfortunatelly I cannot import anything to domain from outside, if I want to use clean architecture

Comment: you can try using the Omit utility type

Answer (score 0):

You may make the methodA in class A return type any instead of string.

```js
interface C {
   methodA(): number
}

class A {
  protected methodA(): any {
    return '42'
  }
}

class B extends A  implements C {
    methodA(): number {
      return Number(super.methodA());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When developing software using OO constructs (such as inheritance) you should be mindful of the [**SOLID principles**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID).  These principles aim to make your code more understandable, flexible, and maintainable.  They are broadly considered to be best practice.

So, while you can use the workarounds suggested by previous answers (e.g. union types) to permit a different return type in the overridden method ... You should consider whether this results in clear, maintainable code.

In particular, doing this may violate the **Liskov substitution principle**, which states that:

> "Objects in a program should be replaceable with instances of their subtypes without altering the correctness of that program."

Answer (score -1):

In javaScript we are likely talking about inheritance between Objects and not classes, 
Here's a simple implementation of your example this using Prototype

```
class A {
    constructor (){}
    methodA() {
        return '42'
    }
}

class B extends A{
    constructor (){
        super();
    } 
    methodA(){};
}

b = new B();
a = new A();

B.prototype.methodA = function (nbr){ return 1 * nbr};
console.log("B " + b.methodA('4'))
```