# How to Pick and rename certain keys using Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have an interface `User`:

```js
interface User {
    _id     : string;
    name    : string;
    email   : string;
    password: string;
    phone   : number;
}
```

I have another interface `UpdatedBy`:

```js
interface UpdatedUser {
    id  : string;
    name: string;
}
```

I know I can use `Pick`, but I want to rename `_id` to `id` in the `UpdatedUser` interface.

```js
type UpdatedUser = Pick<User, '_id' | 'name'>; // How can I turn _id into id?
```

---

Update: I basically want to do a cleaner version of this:

```js
export interface UpdatedUser extends Pick<User, 'name'> {
    id  : Extract<User, '_id'>;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what happen when you try to rename it ?

Comment: I didn't rename it, yet. I just want the `id` in UpdatedUser to refer to the `_id` in User.

Comment: @yaharga gave a fix for `PickRenameMulti` and some improvement with `PickRenameMultiV2` in my updated answer, in case you are interested.

Comment: @ford04 Thanks for the update, appreciate it!

Comment: Take a look at my `PickAs<Source, 'a:x' | 'b:y' | 'c'>` type [below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59071058/how-to-pick-and-rename-certain-keys-using-typescript/75963430#75963430).

Answer (score 50, accepted):

There is no built-in type for a renaming [`Pick`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys), fortunately we can create one with reasonable effort.

#### Simple variant

```
type IdRenamed = Omit<User, "_id"> & { id: User["_id"] }
// { name: string; email: string; password: string; phone: number; id: string;}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdrIN4FgBQyRyA%20sACYBcy6YUoA5gNwHHIhwC2E1t9IzVsQic4wADa86jFoWIAHOOnQB3APZQqNaQNlt5ACzUge7AK6cARtFkBfAgQTHaySLQAicMHGQBeHMgU1ABEAIzBADTsXKbBADJmwJHIImKSyMEwamoAApZwUMmKyuqaIegAzAhQFWBFRibUoQBMFcj2%20AQA9F3IAMJKKKHUALJwIGZw4sgACsAIANbI4%20TIAEoQHNwEYACe8igAkuQbWxCr-gDynMBgADwY0FHBZOTBAHzIAGQBQWiYUAA2i8KMEALrtRzOMCuYbIY6nGIXVwQDxeOBAA)

#### Dynamic version for single property

```
type PickRename<T, K extends keyof T, R extends PropertyKey> =
    Omit<T, K> & { [P in R]: T[K] }

type T21 = PickRename<User, "_id", "id"> // same type as above
type T22 = PickRename<User, "foo", "id"> // error, foo is no property
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdrIN4FgBQyRyA%20sACYBcy6YUoA5gNwHHIhwC2E1t9IzVsQic4wADa86jFoWIAHOOnQB3APZQqNaQNlt5ACzUge7AK6cARtFkBfAgQTHaySLQAicMHGQBeHMgU1ABEAIzBADTsXKbBADJmwJHIImKSyMEwamoAApZwUMmKyuqaIegAzAhQFWBFRibUoQBMFcj2%20AQA9F3IAMJKKM3UAMoQilBeKAAKwAgA1gBKEBzcrgCe8ihZUDSM4ijyUGpbUGDrBOdbyLMLy6sQADwAKlEA0ikAHpAg5OjI8wg6zUMGQr2Qiy%20Pz%20N2Op3ObyBAD4-EIiAB5TjAMAvd4ogBkAQA2tNAiAIQBdajPIlvCntBz4K4oZ7NUJ%20G5zJYrGKPDDQKLBMjkZLBCjBJGXTYs5rNDm3bkPPmYKCCrJqUXilE9FJQY6q5DqwL-EBqZBHE7Qc6OZxgVxs6lsjluMCebxAA)

[TS 4.1](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-1/#key-remapping-mapped-types) Alternative: use [mapped type `as` clauses](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40336). Its advantage is that `readonly` or optional (`?`) modifiers of properties are preserved (see homomorphic mapped types [1](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/12563), [2](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/12826) for more details).

```
type PickRename<T, K extends keyof T, R extends PropertyKey> = {
    [P in keyof T as P extends K ? R : P]: T[P]
} // type instantiation same as previous example
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-EmtPpqyZZiIy1mXlEu1m3lmiqpOMTPxVqYx6cz8GzR0g+cLxfUogI8guxl6xH6eCT9qTVKT3G8oBBI6CmRw01orfbDnEwbJ5BcuGwel0AiEiDCoAAhEA)

#### Dynamic version for multiple properties

```
type PickRenameMulti<T, R extends
    { [K in keyof R]: K extends keyof T ? PropertyKey : "Error: key not in T" }
    > = Omit<T, keyof R> & UnionToIntersection<
        { [P in keyof R & keyof T]: { [PP in R[P]]: T[P] } }[keyof R & keyof T]
    >

type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends
    ((k: infer I) => void) ? I : never

type T31 = PickRenameMulti<User, { _id: "id"; name: "firstName" }>
type T32 = PickRenameMulti<User, { foo: "id" }> // error, foo is no property
```

Note: See the great [`UnionToIntersection`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374908/transform-union-type-to-intersection-type) type for more details on the helper.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdrIN4FgBQyRyA+sACYBcy6YUoA5gNwHHIhwC2E1t9IzVsQic4wADa86jFoWIAHOOnQB3APZQqNaQNlt5ACzUge7AK6cARtFkBfAgQTHaySLQAicMHGQBeHMgU1ABEAIzBADTsXKbBADJmwJHIImKSyMEwamoAApZwUMmKyuqaIegAzAhQFWBFRibUoQBMFcj2+AQA9F3IAMJKKBXUAMoQilBeKAAKwAgA1gBKEBzcrgCe8ihZUMicZuJgwPLiKPJQaltQRxDo3b0AYhrI1mCQu6DowAwGYMjkwGUEAQfzABhQYE2KFANFE4lOuwmYHQyDgIHIyBUXgQBlc4M4yCgtzU4gAbignCBMAgzEdyeJ1gA6AiQrbIWYLZarCAAWQORwAPAAVKKLFIAD0g6LuciI2GQAG0ANKBEDIeYQdZqGDIRYAXWoKogkpW5BRGq1OqFyAA-OyLldIUrNcgQgBRKAXKDUC3sNR-GFC4LtIREAB8fmQAHlOMAwMKohbtbqIwAyNAgYDGIVqACS4Gg1KOxgFobYAQV01V6s1ybF6aTVoNFemVZhi0reubQs77XaCsbuuQDdrTbLYfuyAAEhBxFcWVCM1mQDn8+8i8uBagI-4ABSoCVSs2okDrW3IXfzaioACUfgjpLUFFd7Ag5Kgd+NR5lbF3l+ooAwFguZ3r4D5PuQd52rmL4mO+Dj4KyKBChUoSRhySwrDEfKHMAW6YFAUTymQWjBBQwRMNE3AhDAwBQLQAByMTBrYE6IYuKHNOhcyYdyOGChg0BEcgWRqCE5HtBGPQpJ6GhRKJgQoiAajIOclzQJCjjOH88rctQtH0WATHcFEjJmUSLi2JGbhgJ43haVSoKodQKFof48pmYyFlgPJdGMTEIadPgxryBoOntEAA)

TS 4.1 again eases up syntax and produces homomorphic mapped types:

```
type PickRenameMulti<T, R extends
    { [K in keyof R]: K extends keyof T ? PropertyKey : "Error: key not in T" }
    > = { [P in keyof T as P extends keyof R ? R[P] : P]: T[P] }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdrIN4FgBQyRyUEcAJgPYgA2AnsgPrDkD8AXMumFKAOYBuAsWQg4AWwiduvEIOHEI4uMBocuPfkMLEADnHToA7pSjlpmudpG6AFtSmiAruIBG0bQF8CBBNW7IkNwAInBgcMgAvDjILJwARACM8QA0ohKO8QAyTsCpyEoqNAkwlJQAAq5wUPn6hiZmCegAzAhQzWC19iCOiQBMzcje%20AQA9KPIAMIGKM2cAMoQ%20lBhKAAKwAgA1gBKEGKSgXS6KKVQyOJONGDAujQoulCUJ1A3EOgEYMfrm7v7GQBZK43AA8ABU0jsCgAPSAgcgfHREbDIADaAGlYiBkFsIHRKDBkDsALqcTEQWH7BE4vEE5Bg5CsZBrJ4vL7ovHIBIAUSgTygnFxDBAlDAWPp8SGCiIAD4ojFUWtxUK6QyDMyYXDqSrCVCmTtFcSuczSfTDVKRvgvid6c1EvKNts9gcIEDrsAQRhoGkUcxzMh4ix4gJ0pISsAoNwAHIZSWeGWfb62voO37OwHAj1eqA%205ClSgJINDOXjAp80xpfOxdCiSjIR7PaBfXz%20MUol2cGAR6MZNIAOgHpACnnlQTAoXCLZAATAds4YLt8pRA77Q7Ale7YBjh2GpajopQYFsYRIZCotAYcHhyGeN2ocBoF0o5GAXegNbOsXIyCv38Kqh-UgNFUR9HneaAADcIHIHx8ApXRTDbIYgA)

#### TS 4.1: Drop `_` prefix from all property keys

```
type DropUnderscore<T> = {
    [K in keyof T as K extends `_${infer I }` ? I : K]: T[K]
};
type T4 = DropUnderscore<User> // "_id" and "_email" renamed to "id", "email"
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdrIN4FgBQyRyUEcAJgPYgA2AnsgPrDkD8AXMumFKAOYBuAsWQg4AWwgcuPfkMLFGEcXGA1O3XiEHDiABzjp0Ad0pRyG2dvki9AC2oROIAK7iARtHkBfAgQTU3MiQ3AAicGBwyAC8OMgsnABEAIyJADSiEk7IiQAyLsDpyMqq6jkwlJQAAu5wUEUGRqbmSegAzAhQbWANDiDZyQBMbci++AQA9BPIAMKGKAAsnKFQlHpMyHqkMMAAHsgwq+LIcDQ0m6t60GAMANYQdOgEN1fIK2uoIOTQ6AGkADwAFQAfDEcLoiABtADS8RAyHudEoMGQgJO6GQsIgu0gXwxAANGAASbCgGBYACSo3xyFYyCpnGhAF1OICYUyCN55C8UICFmD3npPt8oL8zBB-hhoKCpjlmOREicvnKSmpFaQxJJyMFKDkWEVEqqaIl-IEwMElqj+bEQmBwpEgA)

Comment: I was almost to put very similar utility type. Ech you were fast. Nice job!

Comment: Unfortunately none of these will retain JSDoc comments what `extends` normally does.

Comment: Take a look at my `PickAs<Source, 'a:x' | 'b:y' | 'c'>` type [below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59071058/how-to-pick-and-rename-certain-keys-using-typescript/75963430#75963430).

Answer (score 8):

A *slightly* cleaner version would be ...

```
export interface UpdatedUser extends Pick<User, 'name'> {
  id: User['_id'];
}
```

... but I'm not sure how to rename it on-the-fly as you're suggesting. It's an interesting use-case.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with [ford04's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59071783/1493081) is that it doesn't keep optional/required property of renamed keys. Here is how you can rename a prop while accounting for the key being optional or required:

```
type KeyRenamed<T, K extends keyof T, R extends PropertyKey> = Omit<
  T,
  K
> &
  (undefined extends T[K] ? { [P in R]?: T[K] } : { [P in R]: T[K] });
```

```
type NameOptional = {
    name?: string;
}

type NameRequired = {
    name: string;
}

type DisplayNameRequired = KeyRenamed<NameRequired, 'name', 'displayName'>
type DisplayNameOptional = KeyRenamed<NameOptional, 'name', 'displayName'>

const displayNameOptional: DisplayNameOptional = { displayName: 'Ali' } 
const displayNameOptional_missing: DisplayNameOptional = {  } // no error, since displayName is kept optional after rename
const displayNameRequired: DisplayNameRequired = { displayName: 'Ali' } 
const displayNameRequired_missing: DisplayNameRequired = {  } // error, since displayName is kept required after rename
```

You can apply the same thing to those more advanced types in that answer, if for example you want to rename multiple keys at once.

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKApgHgDg9gTgFwAQIJ5TEg0mVAlMAOwEMBbMAEwB4AVAGmyUgSIoGckBrXGAMyXpI8TCC0LskABTgwMiVDlQA+JAF4kAeVIBLBFVBIBdA9lAqAZCYAUAV3Fhe2wpRFiJNANpYAukgD8SADeSB6SSE5C3n4AXAJevgC+SLHBoeGEkbGePkgJAJQA3KCgaBhIAHJkYBpQCNowJAA2akEmhiTkMUhsCHBOAOZFIAnFIKWYleQEAI422nAu6oFtSB1gsT19hIOgIyAl6JgAItpsUI3EqJNgM3MLFC2KBGvU17fzlAwA5Gtf3xSnc6Xa5fJQHMonM4XK5VGp1BrEZrqJ5EKqvWG1epNb6-f6A6EgsH7EAAYwaPSQAKhwIx8KasUhQJh5DhWMRLWCVKZ11iXwAgo1tF9ckhQGTCBSuQTaWzGgB9HRsNgDBn4mkszEIpFBQxJAD0etWMCYcBkcAYysIJMwUvVmFOXDAtSQsjp7OIvBYcCQCzWYvJyFtzJuYFmHwoqupwfe9w5lLVwd5AqFIv9EsDCbeobulAVp0t-Uj3KqMcWOpFBpNZotTmt8aj13CHG4zoWYdjHq9PtR5FAQA)

Answer (score 1):

I really liked [ford04's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59071783/1446188) **Dynamic version for multiple properties**, but I wanted optional keys to remain optional, like in [Alireza Mirian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68390476/1446188).

So I've combined the two here.

```
type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends (
    k: infer I,
) => void
    ? I
    : never;

export type RenameProperties<
    T,
    R extends {
        [K in keyof R]: K extends keyof T ? PropertyKey : "Error: key not in T";
    },
> = Omit<T, keyof R> &
    UnionToIntersection<
        {
            [P in keyof R & keyof T]: undefined extends T[P]
                ? { [PP in R[P]]?: T[P] }
                : { [PP in R[P]]: T[P] };
        }[keyof R & keyof T]
    >;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have another, **much simpler**, solution which is **easier to use** with a syntax inspired by destructuring. It also works well with intellisense when picking the keys from the original object.

[image: Screenshot from VSCode showing property key suggestions when using Pick.]

[typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-AgmYJpkU5CI5Op9jpuOIvkCg1lTXagFQIGdXKox0Ys1dDBwcSujCUak27o9iiDroer0oJtAuph+lNUDIBXbWrsnZ0ho88RAA)

###### Inspiration

```
const {a: x, b: y} = {a: 1, b: 'b'}
// x = 1
// y = 'b'
```

#### Proposal

```
type A = { a: string, b: number, c: boolean, d: any }
type B = PickAs<A, 'a:x' | 'b:y' | 'c'>
// B = { x: string; y: number; c: boolean; }
```

## Solution

```
type PickAs<T, K extends Exclude<keyof T, K extends `${infer A}:${string}` ? A : never>> =
  Normalize<
    & UnionToIntersection<K extends `${infer A}:${infer B}` ? { [key in B]: T[A] } : never>
    & Pick<T, Extract<K, keyof T>>
  >

type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends 
  (k: infer I) => void ? I : never

type Normalize<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] }
```

### How does this work?

The stripped type looks like this:

```
type PickAs<T, K extends keyof T> = // K = e.g. `'a:x' | 'b:y' | 'c'`
  K extends `${infer A}:${infer B}` // 1
    ? { [P in B]: T[A] } // 2
    : never  // 3 - ignore everything else

// Compare to classic Pick
type Pick<T, K extends keyof T> =
      { [P in K]: T[P] }
```

1. If `K` extends a string `*:*`, extract it's constituents into `A` and `B`
2. Then construct a new type `{ [B]: T[A] }`
3. However, this only works for pairs `'a:c' | 'b:d'`, but not for `'a' | 'b'`.

To support original keys of `T` , we add

```
Pick<T, Extract<K, keyof T>> // From `K` only extract original keys of `T` and Pick.
```

The resulting type may look like this

```
type A = { a: string, b: number, c: boolean, d: any }
type B = PickAs<A, 'a:x' | 'b:y' | 'c'>

// result
type B = ({
    x: string;
} | {
    y: number;
}) & Pick<A, "c">
```

Not perfect.

1. `UnionToIntersection` resolves `{x} | {y}` into `{x} & {y}`.
2. `Normalize` merges `{x} & {y} & Pick<A,'c'>` into one object. `{ x, y, c }`

And the last thing to do is to add intellisense support.

```
// Before:
type PickAs<T, K extends keyof T>;
// After:
type PickAs<T, K extends Exclude<keyof T, K extends `${infer A}:${string}` ? A : never> | `${string}:${string}`>;
```

- If a key `K` matches `?:?`, take the first constituent `{A}:?` and return it *(`? A : never`)* instead of the whole string `?:?`. `Exclude<keyof T, A>` then removes it from the allowed pool of values, which makes it disappear from intellisense.
- `` | `${string}:${string}` ``  then adds the string back, so that the extends clause doesn't give error that `abc:xyz` *"is not assignable to type keyof T"*