# How to rename interface keys?

Tags: typescript, types

The task is to rename interface keys. Nesting level can vary. For example:

```
interface Foo {
  _id: string
  nested: {
    _id: string
    nested: {
      _id: number
    }
  }
}

// how to create another type that looks like type below?

type Bar = {
  id: string
  nested: {
    id: string,
    nested: {
      id: number
    }
  }
}
```

So, in this example I want to rename all `_id` keys to `id`, but type should remain the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try out the following type:

```
// T := your object type, K := key to change, R := new key name

type PickRename<T, K extends string, R extends string> =
  T extends object ? K extends keyof T ?
  ({ [P in R]: PickRename<T[K], K, R> } &
    { [P in Exclude<keyof T, K>]: PickRename<T[P], K, R> }) extends infer I ?
  { [PP in keyof I]: I[PP] } : never
  : T
  : T
```

#### Explanation using your example

1. If `T` is an `object` and key `K` (`"_id"`) is contained, process the object, otherwise we just return `T`.
2. Drop the old property `K` (`_"id"`) and add the renamed property `R` (`"id"`); process each property recursively further.
3. The `extends infer I ? { [PP in keyof I]: I[PP] } : never`  part is just for DX/UX/formatting purposes to make the intersected type more readable.

```
/*
type T1 = {
    id: string;
    nested: {
        id: string;
        nested: {
            id: number;
        };
    };
}
*/
type T1 = PickRename<Foo, "_id", "id">
```

To expand this to multiple properties, you can have a look at possible `PickRename` implementations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59071058/how-to-pick-and-rename-certain-keys-using-typescript/59071783#59071783).

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=27&ssc=42&pln=27&pc=46#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChnID6wAJgFzIDOYUoA5vsiBNROTowce9bSAwQLNW7PIMHcKIAK4BbAEbROyAL6M1a3AHotyABboA7sjBYEUCHEjI4IdGD3QTATwAOKB1eQAbTAGtKH2A-DzcURV9DAH5cMDDkACE4KGQAXg4CUgpeekZhSFFlLKoaegAaZXy2CjFxZGKZBSVxNQINXG0tTuQAZXRvaTBgdBAyTo6492QABWAEPwAlCBA4WQgAHgAVMuQAaWQIAA9IEBJAnP4dhYPj5bOSvjoAPjTGTZuT+-R5ACsIBDAyCiew+d0CIWc6BgyHewMYAApsMgANrTeogZALAC6FFm8yWKzWW2RuyxO12VxeKmQADJkMokaj0cgAKKHBADEgbCFQmHkp44mZzRbLVYbTaosl7SmqACUoNOgVAMCcAEkgfSCIzpmjQMgedDVYLVajpljVMgpBAAG7NS0wxgUTYTeKbACMaSF+NFRIw6B2ACJuAHA6QA08OjobHYHE5INR0ZBYIgILhQEn4Eg0JgAEwZIjFWpcYoXASCGCYbKlfjqPIsAo1ZTyZJVx7KSQPXLiKqFOoF9iNRRQZQEZsAL1bXcErVUuE0kxQmzz6TxIsJGz9OcDwdDJHDQA)

Comment: Wooow! Thank a lot! That's fantastic!

Comment: I'm banging my head on this. I like the simplicity of this, but it doesn't work with nested arrays. I tried stuffing `T extends (infer U)[] ? PickRename<U, K, R>[]` in there, but doesn't seem to work. Any sage wisdom would be appreciated!

Comment: ^It works by replacing the second to last line with `: { [P in keyof T]: TransformType2<T[P]> }`. Cheers.

Comment: @Piittis you could do something like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChnID6wAJgFzIDOYUoA5vsiBNROcgNp4EHHvW0QDHkxaR2XRiL4UQAVwC2AI2hTkAXwC6jLbnW5cYAJ4AHFAAVgCANYAlCCDgKIAHgAqAGmQBpZBAAekCAklFQ09F62foEOIWGCdAB8yAC8yG7RQXFwIEYcmsgA-IzYnObIoMjWEEboMOmaFJY29o7O7hzmml7ekcnqyGSMGQFZoehKAFYQCGBFPpmxodW19RnFBAAUpZ0VIMi2jcjNdg5Orm4c3t0+fRrIAGRqO+WVAKL+CAA2ciSuK3V0j1EkcTq1zh0uj07uoAJSLYKhUAwaDIACSRRKZVe+wB9TRRzRnS691kEAAbqiKBlqQZjGZ0gBGVLHKynNquDDoLwAIj4PN5pB5iSAA).

Comment: @ford04 I'm making some progress. That one breaks down if there is a object without _id in the middle of the path. I have bit simpler version, since I only need to replace $type -> type. But I'm having problems with some optional fields becoming required, Example link in next comment due to length limitation.

Comment: @ford04 [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJxBuyDeAoZZAGwhAHMwALAfgC5kBnMKUMvAXz1ElkRQEEADoJK4CyAO7AAJlTqNmrDnjxgAnoJQAxKAFdgYZAF5keAD64AJOs30A5OkyY77ZADI0WTOas2I9oREIF3dkQJIVbmh4JGQtAHt4sUJrDX8FFnJxGD0Deh19MAAacRAIJghpAHkAIwArenxCFL97PwBGOxLm5HjBMGB4zCJ5Jky2Qk5OPAgAD0F4qEM-ZAAVKAwGGEWAW1W0gB5VgD5jPFXkOcgQaQZe+ogEQ2pxO1TNO0vZ69vkAGsIGp4jA1shqMgABQ4ZCtNYAbTefjsAF1kK4PNC4QAFZCgZAAUVmCCIumkEAOAKBINWRWQiLSdmOyPo6022yge0Oq2xyNO7AAlMhaOJMTi8ZTgWtmWsNiAtrt9pojjy+XgWQBuFQrVbtYwytkKw4JeLHPAIIZMGHtFm6kxNZA5QqNcSEWEOLxwLriKZAA). Maybe my union types are wonky somehow.

Comment: @Piittis we are drifting a bit away from the original question, so in short: there is a concept called [homomorphic mapped types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59790508/what-does-homomorphic-mapped-type-mean). If you want to preserve optional properties or `readonly`, you better keep them enabled:

Comment: [PG](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-VDTu6TqjHCAA)