# What does "homomorphic mapped type" mean?

Tags: typescript

I've seen the term "homomorphic mapped type" in a few TypeScript PRs. Here's an example: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21919

> In --strictNullChecks mode, when a homomorphic mapped type removes a ? modifier from a property in the underlying type it also removes undefined from the type of that property

What is a homomorphic mapped type? What exactly is the homomorphism? Is there a good example of a **non**-homomorphic mapped type

The reason for my confusion is that a [homomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphism) is map between two structures that preserves a particular operation. What is the operation in question here? That is, where `f` is the mapping, what is `op` in the following equation:

`f(x op y) = f(x) op f(y)`

#### What I tried

I tried going on the assumption that `op` is `&`, the operation that intersects two types.

A homomorphic mapping would then be one such that:

`F<T & U> = F<T> & F<U>`

An example of a homomorphic mapping (from [the TS handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types)) is:

```
type Partial<T> = { [P in keyof T]?: T[P] }
```

because `Partial<T & U>` is always the same as `Partial<T> & Partial<U>`.

The problem is that I can't come up with any way to make a mapped type non-homomorphic!

Even silly ones like this seem homomorphic:

```
type Silly<T> = { [P in "foo"]: number}
```

What's confusing for me is that `Silly` seems to be a homomorphism (`Silly <T & U>` = `Silly<T> & Silly<U>`).

This *seems* to contradict what the [handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) says a homomorphic mapped type:

> ...homomorphic, which means that the mapping applies only to properties of T and no others. The compiler knows that it can copy all the existing property modifiers before adding any new ones

`Silly` preserves `&` but is not a homomorphic mapped type by the definition in the handbook.

Comment: A mapping of the form `{ [P in keyof T]: something possibly involving T[P] but not T }` is homomorphic by both the `&` and `|` operations on types. Your `Silly` type is a trivial homomorphism; like a homomorphism which maps all elements of one group to the identity element of another group. I think the sentence you quoted from the docs is not a good definition of "homomorphic".

Comment: @kaya3 can you come up with an example of a mapped type that is not a homomorphism in `&` or `|` (by the real definition of "homomorphism", not the one in the TS docs)?

Comment: For example, `Example<T> = { [k in keyof T]: T }` is not homomorphic, because if `type Foo = {a: number}` and `type Bar = {b: string}` then `Example<Foo & Bar>` is `{a: Foo & Bar, b: Foo & Bar}` but `Example<Foo> & Example<Bar>` is `{a: Foo} & {b: Bar}`. Likewise for `|`.

Comment: No, homomorphic mapped types has nothing to do with `F<T|U>` or `F<T&U>` and their relationship with `F<T>` and `F<U>`.  `type Example<T> = {[K in keyof T]: T}` is indeed a homorphic mapped type, because if you do `Example<{readonly a: string}>` the `a` property of the resulting type will be `readonly`.  I will write up an answer.

Comment: Yes, so the Typescript docs use a definition of "homomorphic" which doesn't comport with the meaning of that word in mathematics; at least, it doesn't comport with the mathematical meaning in any way I can discern.

Comment: The homomorphism is the relationship between the properties of `T` and the properties of `F<T>`.  If `F<T>` is a homomorphic mapped type, and if `A` is an object type with a property of type `K`, then `F<A>[K]` will be optional/readonly iff `A[K]` is.  There are other shortcuts the compiler can take when it knows that such an `F<T>` is homomorphic.

Comment: OK, so if we consider `ReadonlyProperty<T, K extends keyof T>` for fixed `K` to be a unary operation on the type `T` which makes just the property `K` readonly, then `Mapped` is homomorphic because `ReadonlyProperty<Mapped<T>, K>` is the same as `Mapped<ReadonlyProperty<T, K>>`. I guess that does fit with the mathematical definition, though it would be more natural to say that the mapping `Mapped<...>` commutes with the mapping `ReadonlyProperty<..., K>`.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

In TypeScript, a homomorphic mapped type is specifically a type in which the compiler recognizes that you are mapping the properties of an existing object type.  In such cases, the output object type will have the same `readonly` and/or optional (`?`) property modifiers on its properties as the ones on the input type do.

This was originally implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#12447](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/12447) (which called it "isomorphic" instead).

---

There are a few ways I know of to make a mapped type homomorphic, and some other ways to make it... not.

In what follows, let's use this type as something to map over:

```
type Foo = {
    norm: string,
    opt?: string,
    readonly ro: string,
    readonly both?: string
};
```

---

Main homomorphic mapped type technique, `in keyof`:

```
type Hom1<T> = { [P in keyof T]: number };
type Hom2<T, U> = { [K in keyof (T & U)]: K extends keyof T ? "L" : "R" };
type Hom3 = { [Q in keyof { readonly a: string, b?: number }]: Q };
```

In the above, you are explicitly iterating over `keyof` something.  Let's see what you get when we use them on our `Foo` type:

```
type Hom1Foo = Hom1<Foo>;
/* type Hom1Foo = {
    norm: number;
    opt?: number | undefined;
    readonly ro: number;
    readonly both?: number | undefined;
}*/

type Hom2FooDate = Hom2<Foo, { z: boolean }>
/*type Hom2FooDate = {
    norm: "L";
    opt?: "L" | undefined;
    readonly ro: "L";
    readonly both?: "L" | undefined;
    z: "R";
} */

type Hom3Itself = Hom3
/* type Hom3Itself = {
    readonly a: "a";
    b?: "b" | undefined;
} */
```

You can see that in all the outputs, the read-only and optionality markers were copied over from the inputs.  This is the main technique for producing homomorphic mapped types and by far the most common.

---

Secondary homomorphic mapped type technique, `in K` where `K` [`extends`](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) `keyof T` is a generic type parameter and `T` is a generic type parameter:

```
// <K extends keyof T, T> ... {[P in K]: ...}
type Hom4<T, K extends keyof T> = { [P in K]: 1 };
```

This specifically gives us the ability to copy property modifiers from just *some* of the keys of an object, and was implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#29787](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29787), primarily to make [the `Pick<T, K>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys) homomorphic.  Let's see how `Hom4` behaves with `Foo`:

```
type Hom4AllKeys = Hom4<Foo, keyof Foo>;
/* type Hom4AllKeys = {
    norm: 1;
    opt?: 1 | undefined;
    readonly ro: 1;
    readonly both?: 1 | undefined;
}*/

type Hom4SomeKeys = Hom4<Foo, "opt" | "ro">;
/* type Hom4SomeKeys = {
    opt?: 1 | undefined;
    readonly ro: 1;
}*/
```

---

Now just about any other use of mapped types gives a *non*-homomorphic type.  This is not really an issue if you don't see yourself as mapping over the keys of a different object type.  For example:

```
type NonHom0 = { [P in "a" | "b" | "c"]: 0 };
/* type NonHom0 = {
    a: 0;
    b: 0;
    c: 0;
}*/
```

The properties of `NonHom0` are neither optional nor read-only; why would they be?  There's no other type with keys `a`, `b`, and `c` to copy them from.  Things get a little trickier if you start imagining that you're copying a property from some other object type, but the compiler doesn't see it that way:

```
type NonHom1 = { [P in "norm" | "opt" | "ro" | "both"]: Foo[P] };
/* type NonHom = {
    norm: string;
    opt: string | undefined;
    ro: string;
    both: string | undefined;
}*/

type KeysOfFoo = keyof Foo
type NonHom2 = { [K in KeysOfFoo]: 1 }
/* type NonHom2 = {
    norm: 1;
    opt: 1;
    ro: 1;
    both: 1;
} */

type NonHom3 = { [Q in Extract<keyof Foo, string>]: Foo[Q] };
/* type NonHom3 = {
    norm: string;
    opt: string | undefined;
    ro: string;
    both: string | undefined;
}*/
```

In those cases the mapping is non-homomorphic; the output types have neither read-only nor optional properties.  (the `| undefined` is still present on properties that used to be optional, but the properties themselves are not optional).  It's true that you're still iterating over the keys of `Foo`, but the compiler no longer sees a relationship with `Foo`.  In `NonHom1`, the keys just happen to be the same, but there's no `keyof`, so the compiler doesn't recognize the mapping as homomorphic.  In `NonHom2`, you're using `keyof`, but the compiler eagerly evaluates `KeysOfFoo` so that by the time you get to `NonHom2`, it's the same mapping as in `NonHom1`.  In `NonHom3`, you're iterating over just the `string` keys of `Foo` (which is all of them), but again, the compiler loses the thread and no longer recognizes `in Extract<keyof Foo, string>` as a trigger for homomorphic mapping.  There are [workarounds, see microsoft/TypeScript#24679](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24679#issuecomment-394710628), but the point here is that if you stray from `in keyof` or `in K`-where-`K extends keyof T`-and-both-`K`-and-`T`-are-generic, you will get the non-homomorphic map.

---

Whew, I'm done.  I don't want to write the word "homomorphic" for a few days after this.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvAsAKCjqA7OAJwFsAuKAZ2EIEs8BzAGi1yjjGAH5yraHnsuQhACGAEzh4ANiCiE4PanSYshoidNkAjOMAAW3SkoZYAvgG4sWAPTW0qANoBpKHSgBrCCDgAzKADpAgF1yQMDTLFBIKAAJOGIARgAeABUAPmQ0KAcABVc8Dy9fKBSQ-ABXYi0IQigLSPBoOOIAJlTGKABVDJRUbJc3T28-AAoUqAAyLoBKMpcIAA9gCDwxCkLhkqhOKAAiABldqHJdgCUj+swopviAZky+hwBFfI3ivuFxSRkoEUU+JhQLSGPCVaq1UxlF6XBrRZoJeCIFDwpKItKWTDWABUUGusXiCIQD1UOAIJHIoKqNQxrHYXApYJqUAAPlByqsID46BAxDS1F9NHIFBUqYQ+ThPhofjp9CDGbVWeyxJzubyzFjrFYro18a1EQARETLTLNNqIjp9ABe5B0cCkogKpjSNixeNNBqN0F6JPwRDIe0O4rYHEMByOio5XLwPKDku+snkJ0DPrjgplBiT4bZkdVQete3OGNMUA1WrddwAksAKBApH5kXcXbidc1blWa3XiYIJep478TiJdkHgSctFmlSro2rMMXS5gbHYkvMlis1m8-CkOukAoE0LlXk4ymEItq4fEACztKDL5ardZDYrb3rZPJuQ-kBJ1DGwm7Ec8AQSkKQnC8dYGz-VEEA6B8-DRDFsWbM8-0A4DQK7VgyX9BIgzpQxPwjZUoxjFNe0FRMoGwkiBWlXQMwolls0I3N1U1edT1-c8AGV4ggECQDA3VL3NPY6SzXZ5F2dEm3LP9uOIXi0O9btg3peiCMnYjlNTH5yMomc5y1WxfTwPR4jMwgwD0GgAGMyx1AA5SRmgABgeF9Xl2QcGN2MdvOs3Yylcy4ELxRy8Bc9DcD+KBnOHchYp9az4qLAz2KgML4Tc-c3F2TCxNE7yJO89MAvIRFciCL9pIcpz4ki0k-X+ZQcI4JqGAYiciOnVhyN4ZqfXTNr6A6nMpxS1if2vUCAHkfERTIYNgBBJoy+IWiygYCj4ihZsRMpPxPEKavCtb6t9ckKJa4AP1jYU9NYQbLrMEsJrS1biHuZ9nleABRJZCBEazgCSRbhL6hg0jKcqnkq4KcVC2qPrOzChquoaRqYsaU2FcH6GHWj0fUrrxqAA)

Comment: Thanks @jcalz. How are homomorphic mapped types homomorphisms? What are `f` and `op` in `f(x op y) = f(x) op f(y)`?

Comment: The term seems to have been introduced in [this pull request](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/12563) where it is also called "structure preserving".  I don't know exactly what the intended homomorphism is; I could only guess that they're talking about the arity-1 (unary) operators that have to do with which properties are read-only and/or optional, and not any binary operator like your `op`.  For example, let's say there's a unary operator `Opts<T>` which returns the list of optional keys in `T`, then `Opts<F<T>>` = `F<Opts<T>>` for homomorphic mapped types `F<T>`.

Comment: came here from https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31025 - thank you for your explanation!!

Comment: This was significant for me because I was iterating over the keys of an intersection. Changing `keyof A & keyof B` to `keyof (A & B)` made all the difference. Thank you TS wizard jcalz!

Comment: @qiu Notably (if I'm reading correctly) those are very different things: `keyof A & keyof B` is all of the keys which are in both `A` and `B`, while `keyof (A & B)` is the keys which are in `A & B`, which is an object which conforms to both `A` and `B`. So `keyof (A & B)` is actually equal to `keyof A | keyof B`—it's the union of all of the keys in both types.