# Mapping a deep object and optional parameters

Tags: typescript

I've created a generic which map object, but I have a problem. I need to save optional parameters too

```
export declare type DeepMap<Values, T> = {
    [K in keyof Values]: 
        Values[K] extends any[] 
            ? Values[K][number] extends object 
                   ? DeepMap<Values[K][number], T>[] | T | T[] : T | T[]
            : Values[K] extends object
            ? DeepMap<Values[K], T>
            : T;
};
```

I have an original type:

```
type Obj1 = {
  a: number;
  b: {
    a: number;

  };
  c?: {
    a: number;
  } 
}
```

I want to get a new type in next way:

```
type MappedObj1 = {
  a: string;
  b: {
    a: string;

  };
  c?: {
    a: string;
  } 
}
```

But now I have only this structure

```
type MappedObj1 = {
  a: string;
  b: {
    a: string;

  };
}
```

My optional type was lost

Could you help me please how can I map a deep object and save all parameters with optionals ?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAE2AYwDYEMrDjAnmbAEWGDAFl0wAeANXVQFdgBnAGjgBUA%20OAXjgDeAWABQccXADaAaTgBLAHZwA1sFwQAZnDqMWAXQBccURNPb6TZjL1xQMYAoTM46Bbkk2TZ7wH5zuq2k9SQUGAFsAI2AoGzsHJzgICIArFHgvb0zTP2JSCmodS2sQ8KiY9m4POAAfThrOKqMOeo4PDKy4I0KWa1sQe0dnJNTkGHasnJJySloLHqCKrnHMpoBuUQBfdZFRPAI4AHkUgEY%20QS90I1DI6O3xCKNhMQlLuGuy7a8tr2QfR-bXu9bl9jCINqIISI9tgjskAExnJ7iQGlYHPB7nZ7Iq6oqCfZ7fZ7If5Ylw4m54kGbSGQgBumESnTguWm1Fhx3YzBgUEUAHMePwBJcAOTHYXsB5Cgyi4UbdjEqUyjbgkT0qCMows-JUWFwzncvkCwQisUSgyKsVyuAKk2ylWiIA)

Comment: If I'm looking at your example code I'd be inclined to write it [this way](https://tsplay.dev/N7bzrw).   But there's a lot going on in your `DeepMap` type, so it would be nice to know what the use cases are for those clauses... like, why `| T | T[]`?  I'd like some understanding on why that stuff needs to be preserved.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot. I thing,  using ```| T | T[]``` was unnecessary, I forgot to remove it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the example code, I'd be inclined to use the following typing:

```
type DeepMap<T, V> =
    T extends undefined ? undefined :
    T extends object ? { [K in keyof T]: DeepMap<T[K], V> } :
    V;
```

This means that `DeepMap<T, V>` will turn any non-`undefined` primitive into `V`.  For `undefined`, it stays `undefined`.  And for any object, including arrays, it does a recursive mapping of `DeepMap` of its properties.  Since the mapped type is [homomorphic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59790508/what-does-homomorphic-mapped-type-mean), it preserves the optionality of its properties. And since the conditional type is [distributive](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types), it will preserve unions.  This produces the following type for `MappedObj1`:

```
type MappedObj1 = DeepMap<Obj1, string>;
/* type MappedObj1 = {
    a: string;
    b: {
        a: string;
    };
    c?: {
        a: string;
    } | undefined;
} */
```

A note about why I special-cased `undefined`:  Observe that [optional properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties) include `undefined` in their value types.  So `{c?: {a: number}}` is the same as `{c?: {a: number} | undefined}`.  If you want that to map to `{c?: {a: string} | undefined}` and not `{c?: {a: string} | string}`, and if you want both homomorphic and distributive mappings, then you need `undefined` to map to `undefined` and not `string`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gRgKwIxQLxQN4Cgq6gQwC4oA7AVwFs4IAnAbhzzmOzzYOPKtocdwF8GbAMYB+Fn3ZFSlavUn8sirKEhQAIhAhgAsvjAAeACoAaKADUAfGklGoEAB7AIJACYBnKGTcQAZgEsSCFcoUS8fAKCQwlt7JxcPKAB7RAhhYFDMKABtAGkoQKgAawgQJN8oIwBdYk1tPUMjPKqzKyh+KBi2c15VaAbIV3hkNA0tXX0DYaQzd2AaQIBzSwYAegAqKD6oAeDp0dY8aTmFkkWhJgl2I+ITpYuBB6gxK+uOKDuzp46AH3DXPyBYIMDrrVZYLBAA)