# How to extract object values as literal type union typescript

Tags: typescript, types, type-narrowing

I'm implementing a groupBy function and it basically goes like this:

```
export const groupBy = <T extends Record<string, unknown>, U extends keyof T>(
  objArr: T[],
  property: U,
): { [key in T[U]]: T[] } => objArr
    .reduce((memo, x) => {
      const value = x[property];
      if (!memo[value]) {
        memo[value] = [];
      }
      memo[value].push(x);
      return memo;
    }, {} as { [key in T[U]]: Array<T> });
```

I know that the typings are off, I've messed around with it too much:

```
const data = [
   { name: 'corn cob', value: 17, group: 'item' },
   { name: 'Dirty toilet', value: 6, group: 'item' },
   { name: 'snake', value: 2, group: 'animal' },
   { name: 'tesla', value: 17, group: 'car' },
   { name: 'gurgel', value: 23, group: 'car' },
  ];

const result = groupBy(data, 'group')

{
  item: [
    { name: 'corn cob', value: 17, group: 'item' },
    { name: 'Dirty toilet', value: 6, group: 'item' }
  ],
  animal: [ { name: 'snake', value: 2, group: 'animal' } ],
  car: [
    { name: 'tesla', value: 17, group: 'car' },
    { name: 'gurgel', value: 23, group: 'car' }
  ]
}
```

This is the maximum type safe I could find for this and I still get some errors on the `T[U]`.

`Type 'T[U]' is not assignable to type 'string | number | symbol'.`

And the return type is as follows:

```
const result: {
    [x: string]: {
        name: string;
        value: number;
        group: string;
    }[];
}
```

Is there a way I could achieve this kind of return type:

```
const result: {
    item: {
        name: string;
        value: number;
        group: string;
    }[];
    animal: {
        name: string;
        value: number;
        group: string;
    }[];
    car: {
        name: string;
        value: number;
        group: string;
    }[];
}
```

If I could just extract all the input object values of a given key as literals like:

```
const test = [
  { name: 'corn cob', value: 17, group: 'item' },
  { name: 'Dirty toilet', value: 6, group: 'item' },
  { name: 'snake', value: 2, group: 'animal' },
  { name: 'tesla', value: 17, group: 'car' },
  { name: 'gurgel', value: 23, group: 'car' },
] as const ;


type ValueAtKey = (typeof test)[number]['group']; // "item" | "animal" | "car"
```

But how can I do this `const asertion` inside a generic function?

Doing something like this:

```
type SomeMagicType<T extends Record<string, unknown>[], U extends keyof T[number]> = T[number][U];

export const groupBy = <T extends Record<string, unknown>, U extends keyof T>(
  objArr: T[],
  property: U,
): { [key in SomeMagicType<T, U>]: T[] } => objArr
    .reduce((memo, x) => {
      const value = x[property];
      if (!memo[value]) {
        memo[value] = [];
      }
      memo[value].push(x);
      return memo;
    }, {} as { [key in SomeMagicType<T, U>]: Array<T> });
```

If not possible, then how can I remove the abover error. I dont get why `Type 'T[U]' is not assignable to type 'string | number | symbol'` if `T extends Record<string, unknown>`.

[TSPlayground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wOZQgVzAIQE84BeOAHgBU5QZhkATVOAJWCSgfPSgEtkMAGjg5kAa2QQA7sgB8wgKo0QdRszHBCEAGZxKsgBQAoOHAgAjAFYBBKFABcegNoBdQSbhhsYYLEKOFdwBKRwBvOCcNYn5nBRcXR0pXOABfUlkzK1soD1MAOihgBhwEYAMDAFtgCohhECD0uFDc00QUdDgANwBDABscYFI4ECcvCB8-FwBuFtNeXQMAQiqapx7%204BcG5tbduBWINb6BlyHXGb3U2f3qw-WTvLAcVAALA3qLvcKYHChkG5qn1MKWEoTS3WY4UimjgMSScQScGy3UIVAyKSCUyAA)

Comment: The compiler has no idea that `T[U]` will be a key-like thing because you haven't constrained it and you can call `groupBy([{a: null}], "a")` without error, where `T[U]` will be `null`.  If you want that constraint you can do [this](https://tsplay.dev/w2EK4W) instead.  Note that you still have to do something like `as const` in your declaration of `data` or the compiler will forget all the string literal values of the `group` property.  But if you do one big `as const` you get a pretty ugly union type coming out because now the compiler remembers *all* literals. It works though.

Comment: If you want that turned into an answer I can write one up; otherwise, please elaborate on any unmet use case.  I might be able to force the output to look more like `Array<Record<"item" | "car" | "animal", {name: string, value: number, group: string}>>` but it will be a complicated implementation, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mbGdBW); do you care very much?  Let me know which if any of those you want as an answer.

Comment: @jcalz The second implementation is pretty much on spot! I was trying to avoid the `const` assertion because I'm a little afraid some people will utilize the function incorrectly. But the best I can do is explicitly ask for it in the docs. Thank you very much for your time. I'll accept it as soon as you post it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, if you want the return type of `groupBy` to have specific keys like `item`, `animal`, and `car`, you will pretty much need to do something like a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) when you initialize `data`.  Generally speaking, the compiler infers the type of a string-valued property to be `string` and not the specific string [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types). So the type of `x` in `const x = {a: "b"}` will be inferred to be `{a: string}` and not `{a: "b"}`.  Since `"item"`, `"animal"`, and `"car"` are string-valued properties of `data`, you will need to do some work to preserve their values.  The easiest thing to do is this:

```
const data = [
  { name: 'corn cob', value: 17, group: 'item' },
  { name: 'Dirty toilet', value: 6, group: 'item' },
  { name: 'snake', value: 2, group: 'animal' },
  { name: 'tesla', value: 17, group: 'car' },
  { name: 'gurgel', value: 23, group: 'car' },
] as const;
```

although now the compiler remembers quite a whole lot about the structure of `data`:

```
/* const data: readonly [{
    readonly name: "corn cob";
    readonly value: 17;
    readonly group: "item";
}, {
    readonly name: "Dirty toilet";
    readonly value: 6;
    readonly group: "item";
}, {
    readonly name: "snake";
    readonly value: 2;
    readonly group: "animal";
}, {
    readonly name: "tesla";
    readonly value: 17;
    readonly group: "car";
}, {
    readonly name: "gurgel";
    readonly value: 23;
    readonly group: "car";
}] */
```

And you only really care about the literal type of `group`.  You could do something more elaborate like

```
const data = [
  { name: 'corn cob', value: 17, group: 'item' as const },
  { name: 'Dirty toilet', value: 6, group: 'item' as const },
  { name: 'snake', value: 2, group: 'animal' as const },
  { name: 'tesla', value: 17, group: 'car' as const },
  { name: 'gurgel', value: 23, group: 'car' as const },
];
```

which results in

```
/* const data: ({
    name: string;
    value: number;
    group: "item";
} | {
    name: string;
    value: number;
    group: "animal";
} | {
    name: string;
    value: number;
    group: "car";
})[] */
```

which is less ugly I guess.  It's up to you.

---

Anyway, once you have a strongly-typed enough `data`, we can give `groupBy` a call signature that uses it properly.  Let's start:

```
declare const groupBy:
  <T extends Record<string, PropertyKey>, K extends keyof T>(
    objArr: readonly T[],
    property: K,
  ) => Record<T[K], T[]>
```

This is similar to your version (aside from `readonly T[]` which is more permissive than `T[]`, and a rename from `U` to the more conventional `K` for "key").  The important difference here is that I've changed the value type of `T` from `unknown` to `PropertyKey` a [standard library defined type](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/b12d5c5dc5106a9ee040cbf4acc32f80a8032c7f/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L105) equivalent to `string | number | symbol`, the types usable as keys.  So now the compiler knows that `T[K]` is itself keylike, and can be used as such in `Record<T[K], T[]>`.

Of course we don't really want to say that *every* property in `T` needs to be keylike; we only want to constraint the properties at the key `K` to that type.  So we can rewrite the call signature:

```
declare const groupBy:
  <T extends Record<K, PropertyKey>, K extends keyof T>(
    objArr: readonly T[],
    property: K,
  ) => Record<T[K], T[]>
```

Now `T` depends on `K`.  We could relax the constraint that `K extends keyof T` to just `K extends PropertyKey`, since the constraint on `T` now guarantees that `K` is a key.  But that's up to you.

---

Anyway, now this will work, but that huge `const`-asserted type will really come back at us when we look at the type of the result:

```
const resultOrig = groupBy(data, 'group');
/* const resultOrig: Record<"item" | "animal" | "car", ({
    readonly name: "corn cob";
    readonly value: 17;
    readonly group: "item";
} | {
    readonly name: "Dirty toilet";
    readonly value: 6;
    readonly group: "item";
} | {
    readonly name: "snake";
    readonly value: 2;
    readonly group: "animal";
} | {
    readonly name: "tesla";
    readonly value: 17;
    readonly group: "car";
} | {
    readonly name: "gurgel";
    readonly value: 23;
    readonly group: "car";
})[]> */
```

That type is correct, but you mentioned you wanted something less specific for the property values.  You can make the compiler calculate such a type but it's not simple:

```
type WidenLiteral<T> = 
  T extends string ? string : 
  T extends number ? number : 
  T extends boolean ? boolean : 
  T;

declare const groupBy: <T extends Record<K, PropertyKey>, K extends PropertyKey>(
   objArr: readonly T[], property: K) => Record<T[K], { 
     [P in PropertyKey & keyof T]: WidenLiteral<T[P]>; 
 }[]> */
```

What I've done there is written a type `WidenLiteral<T>` that will convert a type  to a widened version where any `string`, `number`, or `boolean` literal types are widened to `string`, `number`, and `boolean` respectively.  So `WidenLiteral<"a" | Date>` will become `string | Date`, and `WidenLiteral<1 | 2 | 3 | 4>` will become `number`.

Then, instead of returning an array of `T[]`, I return an array `{[P in PropertyKey & keyof T]: WidenLiteral<T[P]>}`.  What this does is take the `T` type, and if it's a union, it collapses it into a single type (and forgets about any properties absent from any one of the members of the union), and then it widens the literal properties with `WidenLiteral`.  So if the input is `{a: 0, b: "a", c: true} | {a: 1, b: "b", d: false}`, the output is `{a: number, b: string}`.

Note that this happens automatically when the [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over `T` is not [homomorphic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59790508/what-does-homomorphic-mapped-type-mean), so `{[P in keyof T]: 0}` is homomorphic and would turn `{a: 1, c: 1} | {a: 2, d: 2}` into `{a: 0, c: 0} | {a: 0, d: 0}` but `{[P in (PropertyKey & keyof T)]: 0}` is not homomorphic and would turn `{a: 1, c: 1} | {a: 2, d: 2}` into `{a: 0}`.

Anyway this call signature will turn the mess of `data`'s type into something more pleasant:

```
const result = groupBy(data, 'group');

/* const result: Record<"item" | "animal" | "car", {
    group: string;
    name: string;
    value: number;
}[]> */
```

Great!

---

Oh, but then of course the implementation of `groupBy` will need at least one [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions):

```
const groupBy = <T extends Record<K, PropertyKey>, K extends PropertyKey>(
  objArr: readonly T[],
  property: K,
) => objArr
  .reduce((memo, x) => {
    const value = x[property];
    if (!memo[value]) {
      memo[value] = [];
    }
    memo[value].push(x as any); // <-- here
    return memo;
  }, {} as Record<T[K], { [P in (PropertyKey & keyof T)]: WidenLiteral<T[P]> }[]>);
```

A type assertion is needed there because while `x` is obviously a value of type `T`, it's not so obviously a value of type `{[P in ...]: WidenLiteral<...>}`.  Well, not to the compiler anyway.  The compiler isn't good at that type of higher order reasoning about as-yet unspecified generic types like the `T` inside the body of `groupBy`.

So this is a little less type safe from the implementer's side, and you need to make sure you wrote it correctly.  The compiler can't really catch all mistakes with type assertions.  So `push(x as any)` and `push(123 as any)` look the same to the compiler.

But from the caller's side, this should hopefully work well (as long as the caller is using specific types and not unspecified generics).

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#code/FDDGHsDsGcBcAIAmBDWz4F54G1j3gN7yTIC2ApgFzwDkEATpPBAEY0A08AbsgDYCuVeAEYA7JwDm9cPwAO1GgEtY5UjXgBfdnkLEyQmgBFF9WAE94scIt7lYHbn0HUAbJOlyFy1eq06iJBQK0CQA1uQOPAJCAEzuMvK0yJCKpHy+2vgB+goq0LzIkU5CYvGetKDI9Bn+ekG0Evz0EuS8RdHUMQDMZYl0VTUAuvDI0MxQcADcIAD0AFTjMAgoaNT05MiIULwW2AQ6+Oub2xaBQgBEDEys59P4hxtbkDuOHSKid-dHTy9SCdTnbykW7ALSEA7wb4nOoXYymCxWGx2EH3SGPaFRZzwFyfB7HZ4WP7lQEqYHTMH7VFQgkwgEhZDhFFfdE0zGxXFo-G-DyJc7JVJ8EEUiHUl5nAF5ApMvE-Cxs6hiDmiwk8gGVehCziU5lc045eDnRrNVrSzmy15Y7pKlnc-4G9VC4ZzGYgCBLJCoZAxTA4WriirgRjjNiceXvXpeUnqUaLOCaTK6f1GEzmSzWWz2UPFVwR2hA6NjN1xvxZWm0enhdqW3M0flpNojQsTBAlxP6miSwpZt6leBEvrqguxlsJ7L1GhGlptbuWnp91UVAaN4fx4CDabAeYrlZe6gACm1+H9cHoikgEg5Ycg-FILHI9A5-YBQKF8AAPuDUcfYKfz5fs8QN53g+EJPgadaCuS76fvc36-heEJXkB96PgulxVEKACU2BOi6ICIOQoAFOsK79gAQmYADyoTIGYwiUDoAA8AAq8DkAAHiokCIGMABKhGBogjEnmeEicAACtIsj3uYADS5BmAAfJwslsZx5DcWM4RmOAABm8DMYpe4QuALAAFYAIL0PQaw2hYzE4Qm+CyFJMlmNQskJphmCKfA-EMEJDmyYMnAOYMin4YRxHkKRPIUdRtExAx+AsWpXE8X5An0EJnnwJJ4DSfC8lKSpaUaRl2l6QZvnGaipmWdZtm6gZjkQi5BVuR5Xk+ZlAUsdgwWhThEUgGAzZotA-C8LAlGnhIPrkVRNFmDEe47pwE48jQmHTFuRYIOsk3TbNigSNQ-mCYxJKqOc0F8ik9a3R+6EapwB4inZZaXIG1ymaayoWiUHwfc1YHXWSoLQYeZrQv65xwqmiIZv9n1hjiIPmmDL5QR+0MA3DFbkCjzVhjE1qg2hEG8K+uMY7D+rnJ2xPmmGip0zSYMOjjMEyvT9SGk0U7MxiAFWuztrElzoLYeF8DOsAh1TTNc0AHTqiraSyHuXA9VwKtnCrVgAKqyIVADCozkHumE7SA5jSfAADqigEZAAAy3j0HwLG+VgrEcelYwiee8AAPzwMH83UP76maYBt73mH8fAfA0dlXHLDgOAtjJEnmfZxsTDRxuW4EURVQxft84JBR1CpQH5V8VlOUSa5RUKcp8CqQ3cf5YVckd7VdXmVZNkwzSYWcO1-fuV33kYL5F3Zf1g26BC9zYOJ8BnnlbcDxYABk8CVfpzGDNQzuux7Khe7w-XieFkzwAcGjDXLeFV4tPr17HGVLy3u8OrtxKl3dOGU+5uWKkZHQ9VR5NXNJPHQ09Opd20PPXysDrI6BVusRA-BQBWz3BQUg4BODsXQTzFcbIfTsWwMg+E64ISKH0nuAAhMQ8A2A2SDG8tDfAHCuHFGGFgHCHINAQgEdwlWsh+DQAABZ7nYsuZIZgdrwBmDMeAjEAC02j4ByPvOQD6sAmhMA4Z8CkGhlz-xXiFXQm9t5MD3BA4B8Aj4nwMphc+TsXYaWvveb2DkH6+VfuFW2Y13SK2mgtOKZg1qeg2v2baJcFhVyibAc6zcrovjulTJ69oMJalAguSOHI4KiX-G8a8CcQKhN8vLBW5AjqwDVlUDWyAtY6wXtwFWbJDbgAAGKKHYuQRAe4Yg2yfhoywcjUDwAAO6BlCNAEAQA)

Comment: Complete and very thorough answer as always. Thanks @jcalz