# Typescript: Unexpected result of conditional test for optional properties

Tags: typescript, conditional-statements, option-type

```
export type Test = {
    a: number;
    b?: number;
    c: string;
    d: number[];
    e?: number[];
};

type PropsOfType<T, V> = {
    [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends V ? P : never;
}

type aaa = PropsOfType<Test, number>;
```

Result:

```
type aaa = {
    a: "a";
    b?: undefined;
    c: never;
    d: never;
    e?: undefined;
}
```

Why does the conditional substitution of "P" result in the "undefined" for the "b" and "e" properties? The "e" case is even weirder since "number[]" does not extend the "number".

Comment: `PropsOfType<T, V>` is a [homomorphic mapped type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59790508/what-does-homomorphic-mapped-type-mean) which preserves the optional/readonly modifiers from type `T`.  Since `b` and `e` are optional in the input, they're optional in the output.  And [optional properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties) automatically include `undefined` in their domain (as you'll see if you use quickinfo on `Test` to see `b?: number | undefined` and `e?: number[] | undefined`).

Comment: And note that `number | undefined` does not extend `number`, so `T[P] extends V ? P : never` becomes `never` for `b`, and thus you get `b?: never | undefined` or just `b?: undefined` in the output.  How much of this do you want written up as an answer? Am I missing something about what you're asking?

Comment: Thanks, this is the answer I have been looking for :)

Comment: Okay, so I will write this up as an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at `PropsOfType<T, V>`:

```
type PropsOfType<T, V> = {
  [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends V ? P : never;
}
```

you can see that it's a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) which specifically maps over the keys of `T`, using the syntax `[P in keyof T]`.  While you can always map over any keylike type (such as `[P in "a" | "b" | "c" | "d" | "e"]`) something special happens when you map over `keyof T` for some type `T`.  The mapped type is a [homomorphic mapped type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59790508/what-does-homomorphic-mapped-type-mean) which preserves any `readonly` or optional [property modifiers](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#property-modifiers).  Observe the difference:

```
type RegularMapped = { [P in "a" | "b"]: any }
/* type RegularMapped = {
    a: any;
    b: any;
} */

type HomomorphicMapped = { [P in keyof { readonly a: 0, b?: 1 }]: any }
/* type HomomorphicMapped = {
    readonly a: any;
    b?: any;
} */
```

Note that both `RegularMapped` and `HomomorphicMapped` are evaluated by iterating over the keys `"a"` and `"b"`. Indeed `"a" | "b"` is exactly the same as `keyof { readonly a: 0, b?: 1 }`. One might therefore expect these types to be identical, but they are not, specifically because `HomomorphicMapped` uses the "`in keyof`" syntax.  So while in `RegularMapped`, the `"a"` and `"b"` properties are neither `readonly` nor optional, in `HomomorphicMapped`, `"a"` is `readonly` and `"b"` is optional, copying the modifiers from `{readonly a: 0, b?:1}`.

That means `PropsOfType<T, V>` is homomorphic in the keys of `T`.  This explains why the `b` and `e` properties are optional in the following types:

```
export type Test = {
  a: number;
  b?: number;
  c: string;
  d: number[];
  e?: number[];
};


type AAA = PropsOfType<Test, number>;
/* type AAA = {
    a: "a";
    b?: undefined;
    c: never;
    d: never;
    e?: undefined;
} */
```

Since `Test` has optional properties for `b` and `e`, so does `AAA`.

---

It is also important to note that, assuming you are using [the `--strictNullChecks` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#strictNullChecks) and that you are *not* using [the `--exactOptionalPropertyTypes` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#exact-optional-property-types---exactoptionalpropertytypes), then optional properties automatically get [the `undefined` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#null-and-undefined) added to their type (via [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types)).  And when we examine `Test`, we see this:

```
export type Test = {
  a: number;
  b?: number;
  c: string;
  d: number[];
  e?: number[];
};

/* type Test = {
    a: number;
    b?: number | undefined;
    c: string;
    d: number[];
    e?: number[] | undefined;
} */
```

Recall that the property type of `PropsOfType<T, V>` for the key `P` will be `T[P] extends V ? P : never`.  When evaluating `PropsOfType<Test, number>` you can see that only `Test["a"] extends number` is true.  `Test["b"]` is `number | undefined`, which does not extend `number` (you cannot safely assign a value of type `number | undefined` to a variable of type `number`.  So `"a"` comes out for the `a` property, and `never` comes out for everything else.  That means we should expect this:

```
type AAAShouldBe = {
    a: "a";
    b?: never;
    c: never;
    d: never;
    e?: never;
}
```

And, despite appearances, this *is* what we get!  Inspecting `AAAShouldbe` yields

```
/* type AAAShouldBe = {
    a: "a";
    b?: undefined;
    c: never;
    d: never;
    e?: undefined;
} */
```

which is exactly the same as `AAA`.  The apparent difference is just whether or not we explicitly write `| undefined` for optional property types.  And [the `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type) is a special "bottom" type that gets absorbed in all unions (no values of type `never` exist, so if I have a value which is either a `never` or an `undefined`, then I know I have an `undefined`, so `never | undefined` is reduced to `undefined`).

---

So that's what's going on: optional properties in `Test` become optional properties in `AAA`; optional properties include `undefined`; and only the `"a"` property of `Test` has a type that extends `number`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDmBXANgQwE4FlVkgEygF4oBvKAbQAUoBLAOygCJVGoAfJgI0YF0AuKKjogoAXwBQAegBUUUJFgIUGbLggFiJcVB2CBQkAG5tuzvuHHRUaZPHj50ABIB7ALZvn6MAAsaAY1V8IlIKanooAGsIEGcAMxD0CFQ8ZzpkEVQBAAYAGihOAH4BAEYxfkFhMSlZBygXd3cvXwCcIM0THUTk1PS9CqMO-KL+y2tbe3BoSnRnMABnAHlYgBVJgB5lvIA1AD5grR0qWgYomPjl8uWqHigIAA9gCDo8OagtqAKoagE6CAA3CDoSx2cT3MCeYBySZQZYQOaQ9o6TJQOiIVycQHGHSFH5ojFAkx+ATw9D0eBYqB4XHowHkHgUiDDVE09B0yzGapQhSw+H7QbI5n4inYpl4wHsKCIZ4QWL0dTCqBEqAkskKqkosWs+mDRnU-F0iVSvAyuV4UY2Oy1ACCNuC01mixW6x5wDygsBO2MMi50BtVr5uj6zEYCpxkulst+ZsGSt+AIJgfVccxOuGRpNUfN42tNoAyt5nCg8AAhaCIoMsClh5MJxU-f4pnRJhu13UolvA705q35wvIEtl0j8gTB0NpiOmhWxjuDZvxhVt9OR+XiKwW8RAA)