# Some type operations confuse me

Tags: typescript

I have the following two types

```js
interface ChangeAction{
    type: 'CHANGE'
    payload: string
}

interface DeleteAction {
    type: 'DELETE'
    payload: number
}
```

Then i need prefix each Type of `type` key with something like `ON`, I do following

```js
type MakePrefix<T extends {type: string}, P extends string> = Omit<T, 'type'> & {
    type: `${P}${T['type']}`
}
```

Most of the time it works fine

Bug when use union type, looks like some types are missing

```js
var changeAction: MakePrefix<ChangeAction, 'ON_'> = {
    type: 'ON_CHANGE', 
    payload: '12'
}

type OperateAction = MakePrefix<ChangeAction | DeleteAction, 'ON_'>

var operateAction: OperateAction = {
    type: 'ON_DELETE',
    payload: "123" // string | number ???
}
```

I don't know if this is a bug or my Type-Operator is written incorrectly

Comment: You mean "union" (`|`) instead of "intersection" (`&`); could you [edit] to use the proper terms?

Comment: Your type operator is written incorrectly.  You are expecting `MakePrefix<T>` to distribute across unions in `T`, but this does not happen automatically; `Omit<T, K>` is non-distributive in `T` (see [ms/TS#46361](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/46361)).  If you want to distribute across unions you can use a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WG5ZJN). Does that meet your needs? If so I can write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Furthermore, I would think you should write `MakePrefix<T, P>`  as a single [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) instead of playing with `Omit` and intersections.  A homomorphic mapped type (using `in keyof`) automatically distributes across unions, so you get the desired behavior with simpler code, shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/wgXbbN).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a mapped type that you can reuse for prefixing the `type` prop (and other props):

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=3&ssc=1&pln=5&pc=3#code/C4TwDgpgBACgThAZgSwB4B57Qq4EB2AJgM5THBzL4DmANFAMoVQ55GnmU0B8UAvFAAGAEgDeWAL5imcCYIDcAWABQK0JFgIUqGVWrwA9mEwIWuAiTIU99Q2DNtLnG1AAqDi6QBKEAMYG4QhMjemceXgFRFSgoAG0AaSgqKABrCBADRDcAXQAuKETWT00jKAB+TSQ0Ewh6VwTs3nz6+OylZQl2lSo8OEQAQ19oAGEAC36aCABBX2BkA3woKOUY9Qh8gHJhgAkpgDkAcQBRDfaYsH6QABsDfsJ8sOp2iRVu-F6BoagAEQgriDwMzmCyW0Sga023yOABkjq4TmcoBdrrd7lB8ABXAC2ACMIHBnq9lP58OQoL5xpMgfN8PksNpdDQ7OgNgB5PYAfQ29A2a25UDGE2o01mNIioJW4PA6ygbM5O32x35YORNzumwAjAAmbkqTpQAD0BqgBhSRLWUFZkDg-UBopBAnpaEZ+jgRhZ7K5PL59EFVPtiwAPj8-gCRcD8Nwif9gCbrbbwzT8lb8QnqQsusojKm7RH+EtDQAqFQAPzL5Yr5ZUrmlstEUsg+QARJ6obD4U35EjLmq0Y8uxINklSPgDLH+sRiMhqPh+jj-uCDA3oGz47maRsAHRgmuQUiZJFu62gWWq1FD-qmKj+LEXObziDbyUxXcrx5D5AjsdQCdTmdzhdgCXC0NkxXF8S3AAKLUAGYtS1ABKKBCwNMEIVlVsYThE5aBVHtUU1WDdQ6TNsxtdcHQlVZpU2TD2xwvCUXVKBtRg3CSMNY1TRUIA)

```ts
type Prefix<Pre extends string, Str extends string> = `${Pre}${Str}`;

type PrefixStringProp<Pre extends string, Prop extends string, T extends Record<Prop, string>> = {
  [K in keyof T]: K extends Prop ? Prefix<Pre, T[K]> : T[K];
};

interface ChangeAction {
  type: 'CHANGE';
  payload: string;
}

interface DeleteAction {
  type: 'DELETE';
  payload: number;
}

const changeAction: PrefixStringProp<'ON_', 'type', ChangeAction> = {
  type: 'ON_CHANGE', 
  payload: '12',
}; // ok

type OperateAction = PrefixStringProp<'ON_', 'type', ChangeAction | DeleteAction>

let operateAction: OperateAction;

operateAction = { /*
~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Type '{ type: "ON_DELETE"; payload: string; }' is not assignable to type 'OperateAction'.
  Types of property 'payload' are incompatible.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.(2322) */
  type: 'ON_DELETE',
  payload: '123',
};

operateAction = {
  type: 'ON_DELETE',
  payload: 123,
}; // ok
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having with

```
type MakePrefix<T extends { type: string }, P extends string> =
  Omit<T, 'type'> & { type: `${P}${T['type']}` }
```

is you expect it to [*distribute*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property) over [unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) in `T`, but it doesn't.  What I mean is that you want `MakePrefix<A | B | C, P>` to be equivalent to `MakePrefix<A, P> | MakePrefix<B, P> | MakePrefix<C, P>`.   That's a reasonable thing to want, and some type operations in TypeScript *do* distribute this way.  But not all of them do.  [The `Omit<T, K>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) does *not* distribute across unions (this is working as intended as per [microsoft/TypeScript#46361](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/46361), although it tends to surprise people).  Even if it were, an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of the form `F<T> & G<T>` will not be distributive over unions in `T` even if `F<T>` and `G<T>` are (`F<A | B> & G<A | B>` will contain unexpected "cross-terms" like `F<A> & G<B>`).  So `MakePrefix<T, P>` just doesn't distribute the way you want.  Your `OperateAction` is equivalent to:

```
type OperateAction = MakePrefix<ChangeAction | DeleteAction, 'ON_'>
/* type OperateAction = {
    payload: string | number;
    type: "ON_CHANGE" | "ON_DELETE";
   } */
```

And it allows those "cross-terms" you don't like:

```
var operateAction: OperateAction;
operateAction = { type: 'ON_DELETE', payload: 123 }; // okay
operateAction = { type: 'ON_CHANGE', payload: "abc" }; // okay
operateAction = { type: 'ON_DELETE', payload: "xyz" }; // okay?!
```

---

Luckily, there is an easy fix for turning non-distributive type functions into distributive ones.  A type function of the form `type F<T> = T extends U ? G<T> :  H<T>` is a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types), and will automatically distribute over unions in `T`.  So if you have a non-distributive type `type NonDistrib<T> = X<T>` you can make a distribute version by wrapping the definition in `T extends any ? ... : never` (or `unknown` or `T` instead of `any`), like `type Distrib<T> = T extends any ? X<T> : never`. Let's try it:

```
type MakePrefix<T extends { type: string }, P extends string> =
  T extends unknown ? (
    Omit<T, 'type'> & { type: `${P}${T['type']}` }
  ) : never;

type OperateAction = MakePrefix<ChangeAction | DeleteAction, 'ON_'>;
/* type OperateAction = {
    payload: string;
    type: "ON_CHANGE";
} | {
    payload: number;
    type: "ON_DELETE";
} */

var operateAction: OperateAction;
operateAction = { type: 'ON_DELETE', payload: 123 }; // okay
operateAction = { type: 'ON_CHANGE', payload: "abc" }; // okay
operateAction = { type: 'ON_DELETE', payload: "xyz" }; // error, as desired
```

Looks good. The new `OperateAction` type is equivalent to `MakePrefix<ChangeAction, 'ON_'> | MakePrefix<DeleteAction, 'ON_'>` as desired.

---

That's the answer to the question as asked, although in the particular example here I'd be inclined to refactor to a simpler form which is naturally distributive in unions: the *homomorphic [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html)* (The docs for *homomorphic* mapped types seem to be deprecated now, unfortunately, but you can look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59790508/2887218) and its answer for more details.  Roughly, a type of the form `{[K in keyof XXX]: YYY}` with `in keyof` is a homomorphic mapped type):

```
type MakePrefix<T extends { type: string }, P extends string> = {
  [K in keyof T]: K extends "type" ? `${P}${T['type']}` : T[K]
}
```

Instead of `Omit`ting the `type` property and then intersecting another `type` property back in, you just map over all of the properties in `T`, and only modify the value type of the `type` property.  This produces an equivalent `OperateAction` and is arguably easier to understand.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUEkgJbAAuEATgGYLIDCAFiMAOYQCC8ZxA9sHkJEkZAJ4wIALiQByegAkOAOQDiAURlCicURl4gAJtKhlKpVkIC++IaQo06SACIQMEClx79BwkeKmyTmoAMmoAKhpaSDp6htLAAK5gAEZUVjZEoJCwjgDyZqyCUWISSACyIADWEAAKlBDUxAAeADxhSBBNFMAGUHh+Esam5kiWADRINR1dED19JmZsAHxIALxRRLlgxGRtEzIlEDIrAGT9h9IABgAkuDWWt2EA2gf+MgC6lpejGcKHSLkJJQQB5uHwBKtylVavVGq0mCx2J5wUgAD7OVzuThg-j7XJKAD6xyiAHoAFQDZCAqgg7FeCE+XzCGL6IxIBYjdGJFJUADcGz+-mkACJ8QSFMp1MK0UhRYSgqEIsL+UyiJYkGSSVEAG4gShIXhA2nI-jSanA0H0lXCQ00y0oyG4SnSGRihXhDQTFlxJAARgATABmUa8pAkkkGyogURRW0WukO85C2RiiWqT3RaOxNnCkDJeDSyyh8OR6Oxo327yO50p+UhD0yL1Z1kipqiLCF4sR3hR0QAfgAhOlflloHBEM5iBzklsdkVfP8KtU6g1mm1pt1eknBuzhmxRhMpp1N-M96wVutVe1j7MtwlgJVgLwAO4CPtIAAUAs2212YX2hzHEgZxOhcSA3HcDy4M8rwSB8Xw-KqACUSDxBA2p8sU-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-NY+CWEAA)

Comment: Does the last-viewable version of the mapped types docs (which use _homomorphic_ as part of the  description) still exist as a commit in the GitHub repo?

Comment: I think it’s still there in the handbook at https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types