# Creating a readonly array from another readonly array

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have an array like this:

```
const arr = [{id: 1, color: "blue"}, {id: 4, color: "red"}] as const
```

and I want to create a type from it that looks like this:

```
type Colors = ["blue", "red"]
```

I've tried something like this:

```
type ArrTransform<T extends Readonly<{id: number, color: string}[]>> = {
  [K in Exclude<keyof T, (symbol | string)>]: T[K]["color"]
}
```

But it never seems to get the order of the elements or the length of the outputted array type correctly.

Is this something that can be done in Typescript?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WYkl3N) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Yeah, if you want to write it up i'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Mapped types on tuples are also tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) automatically. But there are a number of "gotchas" with this support, and it looks like you might have gotten caught in several of them.

---

Tuple-to-tuple mapping only works for [*homomorphic* mapped types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59790508/what-does-homomorphic-mapped-type-mean) over a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type.  So `type ArrTransform<T> = {[I in keyof T]: ...}` will work correctly, since `in keyof T` makes the transform *homomorphic*, and since `T` is a generic type parameter.

As soon as you change it to `{[I in Exclude<keyof T, symbol | string>]: ...}`, presumably in an attempt to filter for numeric indices, you make the mapping no longer homomorphic, and things break.  Even worse, for [tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types), the relevant "numeric" indices are actually *string* [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) like `"0"`, `"1"`, `"2"`, etc., and not *number* literal types; so your filter would throw away the indices you care about.

We will therefore leave it like `{[I in keyof T]: ...}`.

---

If `{[I in keyof T]: ...}` turns tuples into tuples without having to try to explicitly mess with `keyof T` on the left hand side, surely that means `I` will only be observed to iterate over the numeric-like indices of `T`, right?  And so `T[I]` will definitely be assignable to `{ id: number, color: string }`, right?  Wrong.

Frustratingly, the compiler seems to take the view inside the body of the mapped type that `I` might be `"push"` or `"pop"` or `"length"`, and therefore even though `T` is constrained to `{ id: number, color: string}`, `T[I]` could end up being all kinds of things, most of which are function types.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#27995](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27995) for more information.

So we can't just write this:

```
type SadArrTransform<T extends Readonly<{ id: number, color: string }[]>> = {
  [I in keyof T]: T[I]['color'] // error
}
```

as the compiler assumes that maybe `T[I]` will not have a known `"color"` property.   Instead you need to write something that means "*if* `T[I]` has a `"color"` property, then the type of that property, otherwise... oh, I don't care... how about `never`"?  That looks like this:

```
type ArrTransform<T extends Readonly<{ id: number, color: string }[]>> = {
  [I in keyof T]: T[I] extends { color: infer V } ? V : never
}
```

---

And this version now works how you want:

```
type X = ArrTransform<typeof arr>;
// type X = readonly ["blue", "red"]
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwTAvDA2gbxgSwCYBcMAjADQygA2ICRARAEaUCuApnTAL7nb5EAs5KjXoJWeDpwC68CBXDQAsACgVUAJ4AHVjADKcPAEEkAFQRxIAMxoBbADwmYrAB5RWYPHIBKrA+ErqdryEMGDMNgysCEIg1LQw0Ag4YADmXOhSAHyZqDCYKjAYAJK4YDAA1qzqIJYwJlJEJuhFUugA5MIIbTIA9D1OSDQqnCpqWjrGCGYWENYI9o4ubh7evnj+gcFEYRFRMXFEiclpnBnZufnKhc2lFVU1dQ11zTJL7p558gelllEwAGpcGAAfgBMG2rAAblFhqNlBptDAABq5SbTKy2OwI1gPRAITIAbhUfRg2ORuTEfjAAQwjBY7HIdDEEikQA)

Comment: I appreciate this in-depth explanation. It's crazy though how much more complicated it is to map a tuple to a tuple, relative to mapping a tuple to an object.