# Pick only two properties from a type in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I need to pick only two properties whose names are not yet defined from a type, and create a new type from there with one of these properties required and another one optional.

I am aware that it is possible to pick a single property with

```js
<T extends Record<string,any>> {
    [K in keyof T]: (Record<K, T[K]> & 
    Partial<Record<Exclude<keyof T, K>, never>>) extends infer U ? { [P in keyof U]: U[P] } : never
}[keyof T]
```

But didn't figure out how (and if) it is possible to pick two properties using this method.

Follows an example of how i would like to use it

```js
class Article {
    name: string
    id: number
    content?: string
}

const article: TwoKeys<Article> = { id: 23 } // no error
const article: TwoKeys<Article> = { name: "my article", id: 122 } // no error
const article: TwoKeys<Article> = { name: "my article" , id: 23, content: "my content" } // error! we passed more than two props.
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/wXK5oW) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wOPnMN) meet your needs?  If so, I could write up an answer explaining it; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes @jcalz, it does meet my needs. Please, provide an answer explaining it!

Comment: I will do so when I get a chance; might be some hours from now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, let's make a helper type called `PickOnly<T, K>` where you take an object-like type `T` and a key type `K` (or [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of such keys) and produce a new object-like type where the properties of `T` with keys in `K` are known to be present (just like [the `Pick<T, K>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys)), and where the keys *not* in `T` are known to be absent (which is not required in `Pick<T, K>`):

```
type PickOnly<T, K extends keyof T> =
    Pick<T, K> & { [P in Exclude<keyof T, K>]?: never };
```

The implementation [intersects](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) `Pick<T, K>` with a type that prohibits keys in `T` other than those in `K`.  The type `{[P in Exclude<keyof T, K>]?: never}` uses [the `Exclude<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetype-excludedunion) to get the non-`K` keys of `T`, and says that they must all be [optional properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties) whose value type is [the impossible `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type).  An optional property may be missing (or `undefined` depending on compiler options), but a `never` property cannot be present... that means these properties must always be missing (or `undefined`).

An example:

```
let x: PickOnly<{a: string, b: number, c: boolean}, "a" | "c">;
x = {a: "", c: true} // okay
x = {a: "", b: 123, c: true} // error!
// -------> ~
//Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'never'.
x = {a: ""}; // error! Property 'c' is missing
```

A value of type `X` must be an `{a: number, c: boolean}`, and furthermore cannot contain a `b` property at all.

---

So, your desired `AtMostTwoKeys<T>` is presumably a union of `PickOnly<T, K>` for every `K` consisting of every possible set of keys in `T` which at most two elements.  For `Article` that looks like

```
| PickOnly<Article, never> // no keys
| PickOnly<Article, "name"> // only name
| PickOnly<Article, "id"> // only id
| PickOnly<Article, "content"> // only content
| PickOnly<Article, "name" | "id"> // name and id
| PickOnly<Article, "name" | "content"> // name and content
| PickOnly<Article, "id" | "content"> // id and content
```

So let's build `AtMostTwoKeys<T>`.  The part with no keys is easy:

```
type AtMostTwoKeys<T> = (
    PickOnly<T, never> |    
)'
```

Now for one key... the easiest way to do this is via a *distributive object type* of the form coined in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).  A type of the form `{[K in KK]: F<K>}[KK]`, where you immediately [index into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) produces a union of `F<K>` for all `K` in the `KK` union.

So for one key, that looks like:

```
type AtMostTwoKeys<T> = (
    PickOnly<T, never> |
    { [K in keyof T]: PickOnly<T, K> }[keyof T]
);
```

Oh, but `in keyof T` makes the mapped type [homomorphic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59791889/2887218), which will possibly introduce unwanted `undefined` values in the output for optional input properties, I will preemptively [use the `-?` mapped type modifier](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#mapping-modifiers) to remove the optionality modifier from the mapping:

```
type AtMostTwoKeys<T> = (
    PickOnly<T, never> |
    { [K in keyof T]-?: PickOnly<T, K> }[keyof T]
);
```

For two keys, things are a bit trickier.  We want to do *two* layers of distributive objects here.  The first one iterates over every key `K` in `keyof T`, and the second one should introduce a new type parameter (say, `L`) to do the same.  Then `K | L` will be every possible pair of keys from `keyof T`, as well as every single key (when `K` and `L` are the same).  This double-counts distinct pairs, but that doesn't hurt anything:

```
type AtMostTwoKeys<T> = (
    PickOnly<T, never> |
    { [K in keyof T]-?: PickOnly<T, K> |
        { [L in keyof T]-?:
            PickOnly<T, K | L> }[keyof T]
    }[keyof T]
)
```

That's basically it, but the resulting type will be expressed in terms of `PickOnly`:

```
type AMTKA = AtMostTwoKeys<Article>;
/* type AMTKA = PickOnly<Article, never> | PickOnly<Article, "name"> | 
  PickOnly<Article, "name" | "id"> | PickOnly<Article, "name" | "content"> | 
  PickOnly<Article, "id"> | PickOnly<Article, "id" | "content"> | \
  PickOnly<Article, "content"> */
```

Maybe that's fine.  But usually I like to introduce a little helper to [expand out such types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57683303/2887218) into their actual properties:

```
type AtMostTwoKeys<T> = (
    PickOnly<T, never> |
    { [K in keyof T]-?: PickOnly<T, K> |
        { [L in keyof T]-?:
            PickOnly<T, K | L> }[keyof T]
    }[keyof T]
) extends infer O ? { [P in keyof O]: O[P] } : never
```

Let's try it again:

```
type AMTKA = AtMostTwoKeys<Article>;
/* type AMTKA = 
| {  name?: never;  id?: never;  content?: never; } // no keys
| {  name: string;  id?: never;  content?: never; } // only name
| {  name: string;  id: number;  content?: never; } // name and id
| {  name: string;  content?: string;  id?: never; } // name and content
| {  id: number;  name?: never;  content?: never; }  // only id
| {  id: number;  content?: string;  name?: never; } // id and content
| {  content?: string;  name?: never;  id?: never; } // only content
*/
```

Looks good!

---

And just to be sure, let's check your example use cases:

```
let article: AtMostTwoKeys<Article>;
article = { id: 23 } // okay
article = { name: "my article", id: 122 } // okay
article = { name: "my article", id: 23, content: "my content" } // error!
```

Success!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7&noErrorTruncation=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ts=4.6.2#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEkoGdnwIIwC4EtIIG8BYAKHnPgDsoBbEALnmSxh0oHNSL4dhHKArjQBGIGFwpgA9pSwhZAfkbNWHUgF9SWklgCeABwQAFPAGsA8pQi6APABUANPADS8EAA85lYGlMhdUgBm8HYAfPAAvBLkJmCm9k7O4QBk8ATwANpGPJTwAKLukAKgNn4BwY4uoQC6SlQgAG5i8OoA3NoQIFjw7oyxFla26VDKLGzsTsL8QqIwTmCMwlJSnVC56k4ARFCb8AA+8Jtgm6HtJO6RafAjh5vzjCwCCOrwAPSv8FKmULqkFxFXG6bO7wKbwACMACYAMz3eCPZ5vD5iGBSGAAQlI73gAFo8ficeEAH5Y152AwIADkghEYkpPDQlCk3RQyBw7Gowk68Kk8Ip8GpjTpADo-pdhoxgS1Wki3DBURj4EZUYZsLoBWB6Tg0DRtWy1CRtKQ9IYMFgALJSZh2ADuUmc-mQ9nCAIAFNElWZLNYEvUmjBwnsPekMq42PAykEQtUcXV+t7bJUkvsPdwQwAZHIR-xRuwxpSp7gUeODX2uA7p8LqDKRirVD3V2vR0gASjcnnkPhygWa5ngCiuWSzTfM1UY5iy1Ra8H4QvEhp0-PQ5rsznQl3QFqtWFt9sdNkwuHwpyxACo+abl6v1wCSz7D3hOk5KHPA564gmD9hHyAttQ6Cc+zwBId62A++B-rQIC7Acmy8IBBygV+R5Poc-7QUBRwyF4WAIcBZDvgM97fhBhzwW+SHgahcHADBhzSLI8i4W+AA6IFeqWVG-vR2FMYBp6vEaJCvOeJoIFea6XKQBzpFQUF1C+-oyjwwAKXOykMThalKdO2JMtmujINJVxyXQoyqOwym8NpYgabxiizjpLzYjI1imSAxmyeh5njFZfBUDMtnkJpTE2TAMrOR86HXN4KmeeQ3lMGMHB2YxDlJRZflhRFsrRWswCIPZWDxSp0y0uFCXyY5QWFWlWDZdOsqueqvAlbwZWzKlWk+SllV0A1kUqTFBUhbIJWjfVPWWX1IANSpA1NYMtU4aQAkdF01wkZ0jCbpa1p2g6hnIT+J4kLAKEIAC6TtfAMK6VFvIomipDnT+4ruZKNDqq9+AgjdUKQvdVCPfKz1nVtl1XIlmxfZtF1-f5MLzEVn3qhNuyDU9io2gg+isiABU0GiCBYAAFms8J2vA+gqsgwpAA)

Comment: That's a wondeful explaination and a brillant execution. Thank you.