# Mapped type for string doesn't work as expected. Misunderstanding or bug?

Tags: typescript

Why `S` is `string` in following code?

```
type T<X> = {[K in keyof X]: never};
type S = T<string>;
```

Here is TypeScript playground.
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgPADQHxQLxQN4G0DSUCWAdlANYQgD2AZlAgLoBcUhEAbhAE4C+A3AFChIUAMppYcAM7AORAOZIeQA

It becomes the same type (`string`) even if I replace `never` by other types.

Adding context, following type works as I expect.

```
type T<X> = {[K in (keyof X) & string]: never};
type S = T<string>;
```

Comment: You can find an explanation here: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40012

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially what you are doing is mapping the keys of the type `string` which are `number | typeof Symbol.iterator | "toString" | "charAt" | "charCodeAt" | "concat" | "indexOf" | "lastIndexOf" ...` etc. set their types to `never`. You can do that with a simple Union.

```
type X = keyof string; // type X = number | typeof Symbol.iterator | "toString" ...
```

But not with key mapping the way you tried. What you created is a so called [**homomorphic mapped type**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59790508/what-does-homomorphic-mapped-type-mean). That means the compiler regognizes you are trying to map the keys of an already existing object type. When that is the case the compiler simple returns a type with the exact same property modifiers as the one on your input type.

In short, when mapping the properties of a primitive type typescript will just return that very primitive type.

> This mapped type returns a primitive type, not an object type. Mapped
> types declared as `{ [ K in keyof T ]: U }` where `T` is a type parameter
> are known as homomorphic mapped types, which means that the mapped
> type is a structure preserving function of `T`. When type parameter `T` is
> instantiated with a primitive type the mapped type evaluates to the
> same primitive. - [TypeScript FAQ Bugs that aren't Bugs](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#common-bugs-that-arent-bugs)

Comment: Thank you so much, this should be the answer, though I have not fully understantood yet.

Comment: This is a topic with only very little documentation. So I think from a certain point we just have to accept that this is how the compiler works :/

Comment: (To explain further for future readers) Homomorphic means "structure preserving". When a type is mapped with index signature and `keyof`, the Typescript compiler prefers "to not change things" in the source object when mapping and creating the result object. So e.g., if some keys are readonly, they'll remain readonly, or if optional (`key?: value`), they'll remain optional. Another example of this behavior is, when the source is a primitive, the result remains the exact primitive. In contrast, an example of "non-homo" mapping would be `[Key in "exampleMethodA" | "exampleMethodB"]: Obj[Key]`.