# How to get accurate return type inference from a Record type parameter value when `keyof` another parameter is used to constrain the key?

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAIgUQGIEECqAZAKgZRgXhgG8BYAKBhgEMAuGABgBpzKAjOgZiZZmDoBYAHMzIBfANzlyAMwCuYYFACW4GNJAgAPACUAfAAoAblQA2sgKYQ6ABSoAnZaZ3nQdgCaaA1uYCeIaTBQPgAO5v7wyOjYOIx6ugCUdNqSZHIKyqrqWjzaIpRYMOYAHlDmYG4QMNouIO6a0HZKYADmjDBgsgC2rOZ2uuQGPMZmljb2jibOrh7efgFYbXF5vODSSs10C+SJVSlpiipgahpGphYQbaBga80A-PHEPHbmULJ2RymiUmRX0McgAEYCP99EQYAB6cH-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)

I have a function that takes two objects as the parameters. The first object's keys must be a subset of the second objects keys. However the second parameter may be excluded and a default set used. The return type of the function is one of the values from the first parameter. I have function overloads to add constraints to the parameters as well as provide the return type. See below:

```js
const DEFAULTS = {
  a: 0,
  b: 30,
  c: 48,
};

function foo<R>(values: Partial<Record<keyof typeof DEFAULTS,R>>): R;
function foo<
  R,
  T extends Record<string, number>
>(
  values: Partial<Record<keyof T, R>>,
  config: T,
): R;
function foo(values, config?) {
  return ;
}

const foo1 = foo({ // foo1 has a type of string
  a: "a",
  b: "b",
  c: "c",
  // asdf: "43", // <-- correctly causes error
});

const foo2 = foo( // foo2 has a type of unknown
  {
    x: "x",
    y: "y",
    z: "z",
    // asdf: "43", // <-- correctly causes error
  },
  {
    x: 0,
    y: 260,
    z: 800,
  }
);
```

The first overload's return type works, however the second overload return type always returns `unknown`. I'm trying to understand why and how I might change the second overload to provide the correct return type while still maintaining the constraints.

I have tried putting the definition of the first param into a generic itself, which gets the correct return type however the constraints are no longer applied:

```js
function bar<R>(values: Partial<Record<keyof typeof DEFAULTS,R>>): R;
function bar<
  V extends Partial<Record<keyof T, any>>,
  T extends Record<string, number>
>(
  values: V,
  config: T,
): V[keyof V];
function bar(values, config?) {
  return ;
}

const bar1 = bar({ // bar1 has type of string
  a: "a",
  b: "b",
  c: "c",
  // asdf: "43", // <-- correctly causes error
});

const bar2 = bar( // bar2 has type of string
  {
    x: "x",
    y: "y",
    z: "z",
    asdf: "43", // <-- should cause error but doesn't
  },
  {
    x: 0,
    y: 260,
    z: 800,
  }
);
```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WPzZqN) meet your needs?  If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: That gets me most of the way there. I changed my overload to your suggestion and the results are working great. I'd love to understand why this works! Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: I will write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your requirements, I would write your function's call signature as follows:

```
declare function foo<V, C = typeof DEFAULTS>(
  v: { [K in keyof V]: K extends keyof C ? V[K] : never },
  c?: C
): V[keyof V];
```

Note that this is a single call signature instead of two.  If the caller passes in a `c` argument, then the compiler will use it to infer the [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type argument `C`.  Otherwise, the compiler will be unable to infer `C` and it will fall back to the [default](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) type `typeof DEFAULTS`, as you desired.  There may be a use case for keeping two separate call signatures but in the absence of evidence to the contrary I'd say this is sufficient.

Also note that the type of `v` is a [homomorphic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59791889/2887218) [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over the keys of `V`.  That means whatever value you pass in for `v` will be used to infer `V`.  The particular type, `{ [K in keyof V]: K extends keyof C ? V[K] : never }`, looks like `V` but every key `K` in `V` is checked via [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) to see if it's also a key in `C`.  If so, it is left alone. If not, its value type is replaced with [the impossible `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type) .  This conditional type is what prevents someone from passing in extra keys to `v`.

Let's test it out:

```
const okay = foo(
  { a: "a", b: "b", c: "c" }
);
/* function foo<
  { a: string; b: string; c: string; }, 
  { a: number; b: number; c: number; }> */

const okay2 = foo(
  { x: "x", y: "y", z: "z" },
  { x: 0, y: 1, z: 2 }
);
/* function foo<
  { x: string; y: string; z: string; }, 
  { x: number; y: number; z: number; }> */
```

This are valid calls to `foo()`, and `V` and `C` are inferred as desired.  In the first case, `C` falls back to the default `{a: number, b: number, c: number}`, and `V` is inferred as `{a: string, b: string, c: string}`.  The mapped type `{ [ K in keyof V]: K extends keyof C ? V[K] : never }` evaluates to just `V`, because all of the keys in `V` are also keys in `C`.  So `v` is assignable to the mapped type, and everything compiles with no error.

In the second case, `C` is inferred as `{x: number, y: number, z: number}`, and `V` is inferred as `{x: string, y: string, z: string}`, and again, the mapped type is the same as `V`.  Again, everything is happy, because all the keys of `V` are also in `C`.

Now for the errors:

```
const bad = foo(
  { a: "a", b: "b", c: "c", asdf: "43" } // error!
  // ---------------------> ~~~~
  // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.
);
/* function foo<
   { a: string; b: string; c: string; asdf: string; }, 
   { a: number; b: number; c: number; }> */

const bad2 = foo(
  { x: "x", y: "y", z: "z", asdf: "43" }, // error!
  // ---------------------> ~~~~
  // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.
  { x: 0, y: 260, z: 800 }
);
/* function foo<
  { x: string; y: string; z: string; asdf: string; }, 
  { x: number; y: number; z: number; }> */
```

In both cases, the `V` type is inferred to have an extra `asdf` property of type `string`, which does not correspond to any key in `C`.  And so the mapped type `{ [ K in keyof V]: K extends keyof C ? V[K] : never }` is no longer the same as `V`.  In the case of `bad`, it's `{ a: string, b: string, c: string, asdf: never }`, and in the case of `bad2`, it's `{ x: string, y: string, z: string, asdf: never }`.  And so the actual value passed in for `v` does not correspond to this type.  That is, the `asdf` property is of type `string` instead of the expected (impossible) `never`.  And so the `asdf` property produces an error in each case.

This is what you wanted to see; any property key that appears in `V` but not in `C` will be forbidden.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAIgUQGIEECqAZAKgZRgXhgG8BYAKBhgEMAuGABgBpzKAjOgZiZZmDoBYAHMzIBfANzlyAEwCmwADZUATrJgAzAK5hgUAJbgNIEAB4AaoxgBhAjCgBPAA6yQ6+MnTYcAPgAUPADc6IhgAbQBpGD0wGABrWXtXGDMAXTpI2QAPKFkwaQg4hKSbAH5kiJSYOjBZANllGFERSmASuityAEo6M1D4xLdUyTJyUEhYEFiqe1t1Y38KYmo6ACIqFct2GBXWDd5V4BXGruGAegAqDW1dAxi50x4Q2hhoZWiAc3EYLdePr74XlA3mBPo1LI9ljAwJoALasepfLbQuEI-ZQ2Hw5RfUTeGDnU5SMhjaAwSbTABMs3mEMyq0ye3sq3sewAXqsWUcmjS6EwYIyYABGSxsmCU0QncgXK46fSGe4mbmA4Gg-m-EFfEVq0FNGCK5GYr78-WokXGrGNXH4wmjcAk1hUaRUkALShPVbrTarXaWAErQ6WKgQaTqVb8DicmCnU4werKEDKACEPCjMAAtOmM5ms9ncQA-fO55PRrBONQAci1ZaiBTAIFggYgeneYCorAUaigIDspZgZZqdWUZYAdBKyFKtDLbkYHosls8tYi6Au0cvA8Gl0C-mDdbO3eiUeakRjUQCzdjLQSRkTbbB7dJKYR7i6lrTtvTLPyVszhey9muQ9sYacpYKaxvGSaLCm2bQTBeYFkWMAls4vaVtWUJ1tQECNs2rbtnYXYOMhfa1PUw6Kry-LkgAbLyIqCPQ9DHGQnRnJcE43HKxgKosISvsuqqbuqMCaoJoL-huyrYuCPEwK+Z58tUx7mqaSnnnil7kEAA)