# Is there a way to define a typescript type which recursively narrows the type of all descendents

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings

I have a bunch of typescript types which use a shared `Inaccessible` interface in place of objects that the user doesn't have access to.

However, oftentimes the types I'm working with are more complicated than the above (nested data from a GQL endpoint) and the components I'm writing only work if the entire object is defined. Since this is fairly common I'd love to be able to write a typeguard which I could use in any component and would recursively "remove" all `Inaccessible` types from all descendants of the base type.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do. But crucially the `AllPropertiesAccessible<T>` type would be generic so it would work with other types with Inaccessible descendants.

```
interface Inaccessible {
  invalidId: string;
}

interface Person {
  id: string;
  name: string;
}

interface Node {
  children: Array<Node | Inaccessible>;
  user: Person | Inaccessible;
  spouse: Person | Inaccessible;
}

interface FamilyTree {
  rootNode: Node | Inaccessible;
}

function isFamilyTreeAccessible(familyTree: FamilyTree) familyTree is AllPropertiesAccessible<FamilyTree> {
  // logic which recursively validates that all elements in the tree are accessible
}

function FamilyTreeOrInaccessibleDisplay({familyTree}: {familyTree: FamilyTree}): JSX.Element {
  if (isFamilyTreeAccessible(familyTree)) {
    return <FamilyTreeDisplay familyTree={familyTree} />
  } else {
    return <NotAccessibleMessage />
  }
}

function FamilyTreeDisplay({familyTree}: {familyTree: AllPropertiesAccessible<FamilyTree>}) {}

function NotAccessibleMessage() {
  return <div>Inaccessible</div>
```

In this example we have a `FamilyTree` type which has a bunch of descendants that could be inaccessible. The `AllPropertiesAccessible<FamilyTree>` type would be equivalent to:

```
interface AccessibleNode {
  children: Array<AccessibleNode>;
  user: Person;
  spouse: Person;
}

interface AccessibleFamilyTree {
  rootNode: AccessibleNode;
}
```

Is there a way to write such a `AllPropertiesAccessible` type in typescript?

Comment: Please [edit] to make your code a self-contained [mre] that demonstrates the issue when pasted as-is into a standalone IDE.  Right now I'm faced with undeclared `UserEmail`, `Inaccessible`, `useGrapQL`, `QUERY`, `QueryResult`, etc. To proceed I'd have to define them myself and hope that my choices are close enough to what you're doing.  Could you make this a [mre] including what you expect `AllPropertiesAccessible<T>` to do to various choices for `T` that range over the use cases you care about?  Thanks!

Comment: @jcalz - updated the summary with a fairy robust example of what I expect.

Comment: So does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mZQlaN) meet your needs?  If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Looks mostly like what I need. Though unless I'm missing something it doesn't seem to be reducing the `Array<Node | Inaccessible>` to `Array<Node>` for the `children` prop of `FamilyTree`?

Comment: No, it's definitely reducing it; the fact that `x` and `y` are mutually assignable indicates that your manually defined type and the generated type are structurally equivalent. Maybe [this](https://tsplay.dev/mqe4qm) makes it more obvious when you drill down into `children` and look at its type?  Maybe what you're missing is that the type in question is an anonymous recursive type so the type display will eventually write `...` somewhere.  When you did it manually you did it in two steps with an intermediate named type, but the type function I wrote doesn't have the luxury of doing that.

Comment: Do you agree that it's what your need or am I still missing something?

Comment: Yup this looks like what I need then!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your example code, my inclination would be to define `AllPropertiesAccessible` as the following [recursive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#recursive-conditional-types):

```
type AllPropertiesAccessible<T> =
    T extends Inaccessible ? never :
    { [K in keyof T]: AllPropertiesAccessible<T[K]> }
```

It's a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types), so it splits `T` up into its [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) members; any of them which are `Inaccessible` will be removed (since they evaluate to [the impossible `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type)), and those which are not removed are [mapped](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) so any properties are themselves transformed with `AllPropertiesAccessible<>`.

This definition is deceptively simple, since you may wonder what happens if `T` is a [primitive type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#the-primitives-string-number-and-boolean) like `string` (do all its apparent properties like `length` get mapped?) or if `T` is an array (do all its array methods and properties like `length` get mapped?).  Luckily, since `{[K in keyof T]: AllPropertiesAccessible<T[K]>}` is a *homomorphic mapped type* (see [What does "homomorphic mapped type" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59790508/2887218) ) it automatically leaves primitives alone (so `AllPropertiesAccessible<string>` will be `string`) and automatically [maps arrays/tuples to arrays/tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays)) (so `AllPropertiesAccessible<T[]>` will be the same as `AllPropertiesAccessible<T>[]`).

---

Let's test it out:

```
type AccessibleFamilyTree = AllPropertiesAccessible<FamilyTree>;
/* type AccessibleFamilyTree = {
rootNode: {
    children: ...[];
    user: {
        id: string;
        name: string;
    };
    spouse: {
        id: string;
        name: string;
    };
};
} */
```

That looks good, although the type display for the `children` property of `rootNode` is a bit confusing.  What does `...[]` mean?

Well, the issue is that because `FamilyTree` is a recursive type, `AccessibleFamilyTree` is also recursive.  But the `AllPropertiesAccessible<T>` type doesn't give new names to intermediate types generated by the transformation.  Indeed, if you were to write out the intended type yourself, you'd find yourself reaching for a new named type:

```
interface AccessibleFamilyTreeManual {
    rootNode: AccessibleNode;
}

// need to name this
interface AccessibleNode {
    children: Array<AccessibleNode>;
    user: Person;
    spouse: Person;
}
```

If you try to keep `AccessibleNode` anonymous, you end up with infinite regress.  The compiler handles this by just giving up when displaying the type.  It still knows what it is though:

```
declare let aft: AccessibleFamilyTree;
const foo = aft.rootNode.children.map(x => x.user.name)
// ---------------------------------> ^
// (parameter) x: {  
//   children: ...[]; 
//   user: { id: string; name: string; }; 
//   spouse: { id: string; name: string; }; 
// }
// const foo: string[]
```

The type of each element of `aft.rootNode.children` is known to itself have a `children` of some recursive array type, as well as `user` and `spouse` properties of the right shape.

And just to be sure that `AccessibleFamilyTree` and `AccessibleFamilyTreeManual` are seen to be equivalent, let's do a little assignment between them:

```
declare let aftm: AccessibleFamilyTreeManual;
aft = aftm; // okay
aftm = aft; // okay
```

The face that those assignments succeed is evidence that the compiler thinks that their types are mutually assignable, as desired.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=22&ssc=6&pln=21&pc=39#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AocgOxRCQGcx0k4ANOAb0rh7mCphIomZnACSNNGgb1gAIwA2LLr1V8qANxQLgAEzG6AXHHowo-AOYVVAX269+g4aIAKQ+hCqdyah0ZNmlta+cDR0xqbmVFY+vHaxPI5CItJwAHIQusoJamgAFsAKukRUxgCCUFAoAJ4APBlZcAA+4pLS9LKKSAB8wb4ArvRCxm5QHl4tEujtnUp9aowQg0gj7p7NrdMy8nM58apJzqkAYrSF1QAqRNkhcDgQMA0r6Zksk23bXfP7vDDVYCwygoFC4cADYMAGGUpJ8lLULt04ABeHKqC5wJAAD0EVF09E2MI6OxYAH5QkgNEI4IZUbwOHAANoAaXUcAA1khqhBMHALgBdcrA0EQcEwSH0aEzYnw5l8xE-Hh-AFwSWwpCnEDnK5IFhIlVCsFCMVQwmzJC1DVa669HIAegAVHAlYDTcTLQpLtdkd5VPdHq9jCoQvlCsUkKU4AA6aMMvnzVTLKCB2m+PQRQLReMhMLPSJBFNwGxZniLZbJ24Hfx5zMF1Q59NRGK3It7b5we22+yJATJUSqoldJ4+4MFIolcqVGq1ftmp4226J1ZjTzFkyQMtwUbjb5d9ROFIuqVdd2enUAWRQVH62mHvj9T3KrsHrx3OSyaAUKCIcCU8BQmBgR8jyUE9tSQeY0E8Uw4EwCAIG9f8YEje9XkjEMx3DSMQBQMAAApMWRRFMUjRNIxzABKO1bTgABaOj6IYximOYxjEQAPSouBcKYKo6Ccci4ExQMeE4nh0LDCNo0jWNSDgUS4EXTg+CrDMrFCWhc1U2Sizk1RbWokt1yGYS0wCRtZPrMygkLWTOLsPTqMgqhoNgiAG0sWNd3fT9v1-OBEJAIC1VA64LyvbR5kQhCAJAWT9LgCA2RqHIAuimA4uoxLkrfJAPy-FhMH6KgMGAdZgHoEKdRnYlcJETUPTA4xKqQcjjDqq0dT4fEgRBQ0IRNYDzWam0ckK4qxXWZqAHkoCmJ8lAAEXKsBP2qXD6XahqvRsYTNtPZ5msLVq4AAKQAZVYSMAFElDoARbzUYAeVw8rmuqrparOLadXIgSgwrO4kBgfooC8C0vv2pbGFWmCIbApEOD2sCbDgW1ugLFGkAUIYHtuIhgdBuB6ged6lDPGQUAsFg0YxvZdzGkrJrh64oZWmp1th+r9sLXbmZ1QVepFI1xVJoa+Z6I6lPxkGwd0YANG6WpbTlhXC3porGa8DIYFF8mOkppBcL+gtpcJ2oVe6ObBqVi26fIGwgA)