# Typescript generic function where parameters compose into the return type

Tags: typescript, validation, generics, types

I have a set of type guard functions with the signature:

```
type Validator<T> = (doc: any) => doc is T;
```

I want to be able to compose these validators. For example:

```
export const union = <T>(validators: Validator<>[]): ValidatorFn<T> => {
  return (doc: any): doc is T => {
     for (const validator of validators) {
       if (validator(doc)) return true;
     }
     return false;
  }
}

export const intersection = <T>(validators: Validator<>[]): ValidatorFn<T> => {
  return (doc: any): doc is T => {
     for (const validator of validators) {
       if (!validator(doc)) return false;
     }
     return true;
  }
}
```

However, i don't really know how to type the `validators` param such that whatever is in there is either 'in' T or 'sums up' to T. For example, the following should hopefully work:

```
interface FooOne {
  a: string;
}

interface FooTwo {
  b: string;
}

interface FooThree {
  c: string
}

type Bar = FooOne | FooTwo
type Baz = FooOne & FooTwo

const oneValidator = validator<FooOne>()
const twoValidator = validator<FooTwo>()
const threeValidator = validator<FooThree>()


const barValidator = union<Bar>([oneValidator, twoValidator])  // should succeed
const barValidator = union<Bar>([oneValidator])  // should succeed because FooOne is sufficient to validate Bar
const barValidator = union<Bar>([oneValidator, twoValidator, threeValidator])  // should fail because FooThree is not in Bar

const bazValidator = intersection<Baz>([oneValidator, twoValidator]) // should succeed
const bazValidator = intersection<Baz>([oneValidator]) // should fail because validating FooOne is insufficient to validate Baz
const bazValidator = intersection<Baz>([oneValidator, twoValidator, threeValidator]) // should fail because FooThree is not in Baz
```

How can I set up the types so that the typescript compiler is smart enough to evaluate these compositions?

Comment: I wish this weren't pseudocode; some of this is fairly obvious what it's supposed to mean (e.g., `type Validator<T> = (doc: any): doc is T;` should be `type Validator<T> = (doc: any) => doc is T;`) but some of it I don't get (e.g., `const barValidator = union([oneValidator, twoValidator, threeValidator])  // should fail because FooThree is not in Bar`, what do you mean it should "fail" here?  How does this have anything to do with `Bar`?  Is it because the name of the variable starts with `"bar"`? ).  Could you [edit] the code so it's a [mre]?

Comment: Like, maybe [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WkD59w) demonstrates what you're trying to do, but I had to make a bunch of guesses.  Did I guess correctly?  If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: I edited the code a little bit, but I apologize that it's not real code -- I don't really know how to express this. By `fail` I mean, TS should throw a type error -- it should know that even if we successfully validate the `threeValidator` if we fail on the `oneValidator` and `twoValidator` the entire function is not a valid Bar type guard.

Similarly, for Baz, if we successfully validate on `oneValidator` but don't pass in the others, TS should throw a type error because a doc that only passes `oneValidator` may not be type Baz

Comment: Did you look at the above playground link or [this one](https://tsplay.dev/Nr8GaW)?  As far as I know I'm implementing what you want, except: • you're assuming that the function will have a type argument corresponding to the validated type, which I doubt is your actual requirement; is it not sufficient to just see if the value coming out of the function is assignable to the type you want? (see next comment)

Comment: (see prev comment) • you seem to want a `Validator<Baz & Foo3>` *not* to be a `Validator<Baz>`, which is inconsistent... for the same reason a `Validator<X>` is also a `Validator<X|Y>`, a `Validator<X&Y>` is also a `Validator<X>`); I can't imagine a way of getting the pass/fail behavior you specify without seriously abusing the type system.   Can I post my approach as an answer or is there some good reason it doesn't meet your needs?

Comment: I think the second playground is correct, thank you! Can you explain why the union is returning T[number]?

Comment: I will explain when I write up the answer, which should be sometime today

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My inclination here would be to make `union` and `intersection` [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) `T` corresponding to the type each `validators` is [guarding](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates).  For example, if you have validators `vx` of type `Validator<X>`, `vy` of type `Validator<Y>`, and `vz` of type `Validator<Z>`, then when you call `union([vx, vy, vz])` we want `T` to be `[X, Y, Z]`.

Then we can represent the `validators` input as a straightforward [mapped type on the tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays), like `{[I in keyof T]: Validator<T[I]>}`.  And in order to give a hint that we want `T` to be a tuple and not an unordered [array type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#the-array-type), we can write it as a [variadic tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types), `[...{ I in keyof T]: Validator<T[I]> }]`.  Because the mapped type is *homomorphic* (see [What does "homomorphic mapped type" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59790508/2887218) ), the compiler is able to infer `T` from a value of that mapped type.

That means all we need to worry about is the return types of `union` and `intersection`.

---

For `union`, the question is: "given a tuple type `T`, how do we write a type which is the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of all its element types"?  That is relatively easy to write; all we need to do is [index into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) the type with `number`, since tuple types already have a `number` [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) with the union of element types.  (Hopefully that makes sense; if you have a value `a` of type `[string, number, boolean]` and index into it with a `number` `i` that isn't out of bounds, then the type of `a[i]` will be `string | number | boolean`):

```
const union = <T extends any[]>(
    validators: [...{ [I in keyof T]: Validator<T[I]> }]
): Validator<T[number]> => {
    return (doc: any): doc is T[number] => {
        for (const validator of validators) {
            if (validator(doc)) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

And let's test it:

```
declare const oneValidator: Validator<FooOne>;
declare const twoValidator: Validator<FooTwo>;
declare const threeValidator: Validator<FooThree>;

const uv1 = union([oneValidator]);
// const uv1: Validator<FooOne>
const uv12 = union([oneValidator, twoValidator]);
// const uv12: Validator<FooOne | FooTwo>
const uv123 = union([oneValidator, twoValidator, threeValidator]);
// const uv123: Validator<FooOne | FooTwo | FooThree>
```

Looks good.

---

For `intersection`, the question is: "given a tuple type `T`, how do we write a type which is the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types) of all its element types"?  That is more involved.  There is no simple way to get this... the indexed access types correspond to what you get when you read properties, not write them.

In order to turn a tuple into the intersection of all its element types, we need to write our own utility type that maps the tuple to a version with the elements in a *contravariant* type position (see [Difference between Variance, Covariance, Contravariance and Bivariance in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66410115/2887218)) and then use [conditional type inference via `infer`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types) to infer a single type for those, which will become the intersection, as documented.

It looks like this:

```
type TupleToIntersection<T extends any[]> = {
    [I in keyof T]: (x: T[I]) => void
}[number] extends (x: infer R) => void ? R : never;
```

which you can verify works as intended:

```
type Test = TupleToIntersection<[{ a: string }, { b: number }, { c: boolean }]>
// type Test = { a: string; } & { b: number; } & { c: boolean; }
```

And thus `intersection` looks like

```
const intersection = <T extends any[]>(
    validators: [...{ [I in keyof T]: Validator<T[I]> }]
): Validator<TupleToIntersection<T>> => {
    return ((doc: any): doc is TupleToIntersection<T> => {
        for (const validator of validators) {
            if (!validator(doc)) return false;
        }
        return true;
    });
}
```

And let's test it:

```
const iv1 = intersection([oneValidator]);
// const iv1: Validator<FooOne>
const iv12 = intersection([oneValidator, twoValidator]);
// const iv12: Validator<FooOne & FooTwo>
const iv123 = intersection([oneValidator, twoValidator, threeValidator]);
// const iv123: Validator<FooOne & FooTwo & FooThree>
```

Also looks good.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwJYBM7APYCcA8AVAPigF4oAKFDAYwC4o4A7EAShKMqqiQGco8BuAFCCqGBt2BQArgyRiSUfFAgAPYBAYpejEAG0AugTKCopqADdEqdNm51dAOicBvKLoCSXBlADWEEBgAZnz6dPDIaJi4eB6GUAC++oLMYVaR2Pi6DFIAtgBGEFhxxETOJmZYEMBSWN4U1HQ6KVAcXLwx2fmF+mxQZWYDUIHY5KLikpYRNlhQQRZp09ys-YOrSMFkk9ZR9VTMrJXVtVDAWFIQQqum8eWrhzXegYjcF7cJgjeCoJB8UmAIEDwGHcDHUWBeVGAcgYSlU6k02iYBiIpBWpg8Xl8-jmeFC5BUdBi7n0rBKFgwqA+WVyBSKyjUGi0+LoSAYgUKUAASqSiOYKSgoAB+LlQOgMCDmQpCL7gaB4CASBR4P4AoEgsEQqFiHC6VxwOgSLCsgDmCQANH0oHkxTSOfELa5aFaMBgAYwEoZBAB6L0nWV8BWSVH0A2nE38BJQABklutUE6tIj8WjlqdeRdboYSeEY0VrI1EEh0IUsIZCPoSMMxgGW3S4PsTgcrgxrKxAWCuNSUyimWJRESyS72wyyv+gOBoMKmuh+AIKNKb3uxzIu0aTGarR4vzHasn4MLWphhF6aMGwxmZFzEwWUVmwVri2WbyuXA2AEIHzsOPsoEvHs9XhfG4Xz-E4zkAsx4mYIRPkEfNCieKhoAAMRdAB5cU+jefUoENcMPmEeCsEQlCXTwAB3DAsIGOM8IYY0YMIvcSKgVCMDwAALSpoFPJ06ONAiZR+AAhOAZlINiMOgAAfViyMooToFEgAvBRJMwmM2IojBhBQQsEDE6Ar1mcVwmHLAhzrHB1IgAghD0qgDMqKBjOASizLrSzpms+SMDswQHKcoyxEVYAuIgCAPOmLyey08LbOlYypHMABGBQZGhMhdDESKb2wEkhB9FyQskZKUpijIbIIEQSukVKACZ0tkMQspyqKogtNyMHa-LoO9X0koaircBsqBZK0yjqsGlL6oAZiazLstMvKsE69yVs6+KeqKPqiumubhp8jApLGuT2Mo064u46qc1qpBUoUIjpxapbcu7XrCoGu7UsOqqavGLgGsevdnoYVrlve1aTnWyGCv64qAfumbfvQjSzu0qbvpm+bSCeg9Frajboe6omwu47a4b2rGDtgFajpOzTfJTK6IuqoA)