# Extract type for each field of an object

Tags: typescript, typed

In typescript, given an object represented as a record of derived class, how do I extract the proper underlying class ?

Let me give you an exemple of my problem:

```js
abstract class factory {
    abstract deploy(...[]): any;
}

class a_factory extends factory {
    deploy = (a: number, b: string) => {};
}

class b_factory extends factory {
    deploy = (a: {}, b: number) => {};
}

const obj = {
    a: a_factory,
    b: b_factory
};

export type Object<F extends factory> = ReturnType<F['deploy']>;
export interface ContractBuilder<F extends factory> {
    deploy(...args: Parameters<F['deploy']>): Object<F>;
}
export type FactoryConstructor<F extends factory> = {
    new (): F;
};

const doSome = (any: any) => {};

const build = <K extends factory, F extends Record<string, FactoryConstructor<K>>>(contracts: F) => {
    const a: { [contractName: string]: any } = {};

    for (const x in contracts) {
        a[x] = doSome(contracts[x] as any);
    }

    type MySuperType<T extends F> = {
        [P in keyof T]: ContractBuilder<K>;
    };

    return a as MySuperType<F>;
};

const MyTestObj = build(obj);

MyTestObj.a.deploy() //  This is not typed to a_factory
MyTestObj.b.deploy() //  This is not typed to b_factory
```

As you can see, the final object doesn't infer the correct type for each of his member.

How could I achieve that ?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wOLAMN) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Could you, if you don't mind, please modify the tsplay and use my types, such as FactoryContructor and ContractBuilder. I did super simply my code here and it's hard to do the parallel from your code to mine

Comment: My issue reside in the fact that in the build function, <K extends factory> should be somehow inside the <F extends Records ...> part. It's really hard to explain, sorry

Comment: Like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w1E7lw)?  It's a bit weird to be beholden to types that aren't motivated in the example code, but if it helps you evaluate it, there you go.

Comment: Ok, this is the way to go. Can you write an answer please ? I'll validate it. Just make sure to keep all my variables, functions and everything in my code above and make sure it's compilable/working on the get go because I cannot make it work with your declare const stuff and cannot wrap my around it to make it work. Thank you so much !

Comment: Like [this](https://tsplay.dev/we6BeN)?  I hope I don't have to bring back the unconventional kebab case names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say the main problem here is that your `build()` function has no *inference site* for the [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter `K`. You might think that `<K extends Factory, F extends Record<string, FactoryConstructor<K>>>` means that `K` could be inferred from  [the constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) on `F`, but that's not how it works. There is an old closed suggestion to support this at [microsoft/TypeScript#7234](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7234), but it was never implemented.  Currently, the rule you should follow is: **each type parameter in a generic function should appear in the function parameter types, as directly as possible**.  For a type parameter `T`, the best inference site is where there's a function parameter of type `T` (e.g., `<T,>(x: T) => ...`).  Another good inference site is from a *homomorphic* [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) (see [What does "homomorphic mapped type" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59790508/2887218) ) (e.g., `<T,>(x: {[K in keyof T]: ...T[K]...}) => ...`).

So here's a different way to write `build()`:

```
const build = <T extends Record<keyof T, Factory>>(
  contracts: { [K in keyof T]: FactoryConstructor<T[K]> }
) => {
  const a: { [contractName: string]: any } = {};

  for (const x in contracts) {
    a[x] = doSome(contracts[x] as any);
  }
  type MySuperType<T extends Record<keyof T, Factory>> = {
    [K in keyof T]: ContractBuilder<T[K]>;
  };

  return a as MySuperType<T>;
};
```

Here, there is only one type parameter, `T`, whose type is that of an object whose property values are all assignable to `Factory`.  Then `contracts` is a homomorphic mapped type on `T`, where each property is a `FactoryConstructor` for the analogous property of `T`.  So if `contracts` is of type `{foo: FactoryConstructor<Foo>, bar: FactoryConstructor<Bar>}`, then `T` will be inferred as `{foo: Foo, bar: Bar}`.

The return type is `MySuperType<T>`, which also maps over `T`, this time turning each property into a `ContractBuilder` for the analogous property of `T`.  So if `T` is `{foo: Foo, bar: Bar}`, then `MySuperType<T>` is `{foo: ContractBuilder<Foo>, bar: ContractBuilder<Bar>}`.

---

Let's test it out:

```
const MyTestObj = build(obj);

MyTestObj.a;
//(property) a: ContractBuilder<AFactory>
MyTestObj.a.deploy(123, "456"); // okay
MyTestObj.a.deploy({}, 789); // error!

MyTestObj.b;
//(property) b: ContractBuilder<BFactory>
MyTestObj.b.deploy({}, 789); // okay
MyTestObj.b.deploy(123, "456"); // error!
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgYnCB7KAnggN4BQCCokM8CAJgKYAOyuBAFAHTcDaAugEoAXJQB2BANykAvqVIo0GAILZ4+IgwAeEBqLoZVeQiXL1mrIgF4E7YCNEBXALYgGUADQIQI6gEtRAOYCCJYAfCQI0lKy8qjoCABChuoIWjp6BjgpZBSMLGwhNnYk0p7eCI4ubsFhEVEycrC4opAIuCAAVoU5lCIqWYTupuVJAwQyUqRaTPiIEARMDAgA8p0M8AA8mKnauvpYY+HWAEoMEA5QogAqCwxbPADkeRYPfKFS07MI-jpQAGZwJYAYWa0BwCQcvmQjCgWx26X2yUI4R6zzYXG4wCgATAIgACljgE4zm4wPcnuY2K9QsIVmtNph3g1PlA5rcDmpCCCWtAHJy4Wk9plOQQjiYKKIGAB3di0zDRSZNHn0XAAZVwxMKtnEImA4hqKMiiuarRAkOhhQ2V3hQoQpyaUDoGwA1gwCLg-ggrp4kaLQuxTEqwfBcREeABpb6iBCu92eq58ES+7nUPlGK0Rt6RUgG8VIE2IYrEBA8IM0CAAOSJDB80H8AUTYiI0m69VMf3wNiVrU0UfzomDEDAwR6FGAPE0fEKdDVGoY7DLODAE6naCbAikFFkFHmiwQAFkCKqHIsoDdFlabRk7et8E7Yx6vT7DmLRyXI-4Y27HwmRNzBxCUIwhm4ZvJuRpyBQUBnBc0bAJQGCHsep7nncVxMm28gFgeBBXAwkCrF01hmkB7DtB0G5yIeeEEZ0nDAFIAD0jHsEwUC4Ke8zBMU-7loB0JuBs-QiqEpDUfhECEfRnBohwACMABMADMngAEQACwAKwAGyqRuCDMW0zrAOM4m0R00myewxClAgADsAAcACc+mGW47FQAAhFRuESVJIBMSxbEcW4XFeH+oJ8eawGjCJYm+eZnAgDJlIcDZniOS5EgGYxRkmfFNGSXRyVWYpKkIBpOl6dlblQB53lAA)