# Typescript function that should accept an array of specific types with a certain condition

Tags: typescript

Consider the following types:

```
type objectExtensionFunction<TBaseObject extends object, TExtendWith extends object> = (base: TBaseObject) => TExtendWith & TBaseObject;

declare function myEndpoint<TObjects extends objectExtensionFunction<any, any>>(objects: TObjects): any;
```

The above function accepts any array of `objectExtensionFunction` types. These are functions, that will receive a base object, and should add an additional property to that object, and create a new object type, based on the property added.

What I would want to achieve, is somehow tell `myEndpoint` function, that the minimal input array, should contain functions, that will at least add some specific properties to the first base object supplied, if all of the functions are called on a base object.

In other words:

```
/** 
 * how could I declare `myEndPoint` function, that it will only accept an array of  
 * `objectExtensionFunction` types, if the merging of all the function results of those 
 * `objectExtensionFunction` types extends my supplied base type
 */
declare function myEndPoint(): any;
```

A concrete example to illustrate the problem I am trying to solve:

```
type requiredEndType = {
   a: boolean,
   b: boolean
}

type objectExtensionFunction<TBaseObject extends object, TExtendWith extends object> = (base: TBaseObject) => TExtendWith & TBaseObject;

const addToBaseA: objectExtensionFunction<{}, {
   a: boolean
}> = (base) => {
    return {
        ...base,
        a: true
    };
}

const addToBaseB: objectExtensionFunction<{}, {
   b: boolean
}> = (base) => {
    return {
        ...base,
        b: true
    };
}

const addToBaseC: objectExtensionFunction<{}, {
   c: boolean
}> = (base) => {
    return {
        ...base,
        c: true
    };
}


/** I am looking to type this function, so that it will accept an array of `objectExtensionFunction` types
 *  that when called in succession, chained, providing an empty object as the first object parameter, will resolve 
 *  in an object, that satisfies the `requiredEndType` constraint
 */
declare function myEndpoint<TObjects extends objectExtensionFunction<any, any>[]>(objects: TObjects): void;

myEndpoint([addToBaseA, addToBaseB]); // this should be accepted
myEndpoint([addToBaseA, addToBaseB, addToBaseC]); // this also should be accepted
myEndpoint([addToBaseB, addToBaseA]); // this also should be accepted, the order does not matter
myEndpoint([addToBaseA, addToBaseC]); // this should raise an error, after running all the functions, the `b` property would be missing
```

Here's a typescript playground [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAThCOBXAlnAJgUQHZoCrmgF4oBvAWACgpqBDALigCMB7ZgGwhqwBpLqmGLdpyyUAvpUqhIUZowBWEAMbAMAD2AQsAZ2TMsAMURYVerAB5cAIRraIAeQXLgUCBq1ptspyu5Rc6po4AOrIwAAWru44XnKKKgB8UMQAFIy2EAzWGY7xwACUyUkB0WihEVAAZP42drnOANySFEr62i40aHjMtRAAggxxzoFauvpGJsBm5iRifuRUtIKsHFziSanpdoWESQv8sBDAiDBYpHwH-AB0N1sQvIuXUPRQwDCIEBfUYk0UEhSUVo6DpdXA9DJWQY%20VTRMaGYymfQzObnR6MZbCNZ-DZQNIZHZ7L6HY6nVFPag3K53B7kgSvd6fR5QH7iZpA9rPUHguwAYSheRGOjME0RFlm8y%20Sgxq1E2OSuLuBLJ-DgJLO%203JlOpRIOUvpHyJLL%20zUoAHoAFTmqAASWeAFsoGxWABrZBYADmr2YrwIr3CyC8ADMEVN9H5tN6IjQXGEoAB3ZBsNjPJRKCBgDpnGgwGA0ECyQNQAAGQxUgrhItDWCLPsg2j4Vr90fj4S0UCUNCTEDQUDdUG0iFTEG0cL8SnCNDd3b8YBgzAAbsg0G7PVxXHaM-nSx0vBFoIHUBzt1AwNmaHajhAYH4E0nDhG2PPoA3qH219u-FGXNpowGD8O-WgIs4CQVBu2wPACBrdk3knLBgAbU1KDQZQ2GzfcQzMKA7RACCwGYN1gEseoVC8Nwgk8bwBVhYVMKRLgQD8BiEgAbQAXQSFJt20LISOAbR8gYecCLQX5KBwvCCPglIWM6bpej6JiuV6Kw2PyBooFNU0-QDftwmYRA2B7RhoBoIcM27cTcJwfDCJkuSwQUpT5IhZzHIyHk1I0rSdK8TsIz0gyjKYUzzM0NArMkuzZOU1zORcuw%20i8zTtIiXT-O9bR9MM4zQrTCy0E-VtZBgFCYCgNBmAArBmBcO1o00GBIpsqTgHs2LErc7kIE89SUt8wKctgSc7GeM4rzna9nkDRrYGMLAV2eO89ygYNJjMbQiqAxga1nZhIBgUB4yC3LsIDXQPSAA) of the above code.

Comment: Your example seems to be pseudocode?  There's no `define` keyword.  Your functions are parenthesized so they are inaccessible to `myEndpoint`, and there are unrelated implicit `any` errors in there.  Could you please check the example code in an IDE and clear up any errors unrelated to the question you're asking, and then [edit] this so that when others look at your code it is a [mre] they can immediately start working on?  Thanks!

Comment: @jcalz made the edits and added a playground link as well - as my original problem is a bit harder to explain, I've just wrote a quick example here, without an ide, and it seems that I know much fewer of typescript form my mind, than I tought:P

Comment: • I still see `define` in the code above. Could you make sure all code in your question has at least briefly passed through a TypeScript IDE? •  Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w846Ew) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Yes, that is exactly what I was looking for - but a bit of explaining would also be needed, cause I would like to understand how is the magic happening:)

Comment: I'd be happy to write up an answer with an explanation; could you please fix `define` and any other pseudocode?  Maybe the title should say "accept" instead of "except" also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
declare function myEndPoint<T extends any[]>(
    objects: readonly [...{ [I in keyof T]: ObjectExtensionFunction<{},
        T[I] &
        Partial<RequiredEndType> &
        { [K in keyof RequiredEndType as Exclude<K, TupleToKeys<T>>]: RequiredEndType[K] }
    > }]): any;

type TupleToKeys<T extends readonly any[]> = { [I in keyof T]: keyof T[I] }[number];
```

The idea is that `myEndPoint()` is [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in `T`, the [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) of second type arguments to `ObjectExtensionFunction<{}, ?>` for the corresponding elements of the `objects` parameter.  So if you call `myEndPoint([x, y, z])` where `x` is of type `ObjectExtensionFunction<{}, X>`, `y` is of type `ObjectExtensionFunction<{}, Y>`, and `z` is of type `ObjectExtensionFunction<{}, Z>`, then `T` should be the tuple type `[X, Y, Z]`.  That much could be accomplished by

```
declare function myEndPoint<T extends any[]>(
    objects: readonly [...{ [I in keyof T]: ObjectExtensionFunction<{},
        T[I]> }]): any;
```

in which `objects` is a [variadic tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) (the `[...`+`]` part) to give the compiler a hint that it should infer a tuple type for `T`, and a [mapped array/tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) so that a `T` like `[X, Y, Z]` would be mapped to `[ObjectExtensionFunction<{}, X>, ObjectExtensionFunction<{}, Y>, ObjectExtensionFunction<{}, Z>]`.  It is a *homomorphic mapped type* (as described in [What does "homomorphic mapped type" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59790508/2887218) ) which is why the compiler could infer `T` from the mapped type

But that doesn't care what the elements of `T` are.  We want to analyze `T` to make sure that: no element has properties incompatible with `RequiredEndType`; and each property of `RequiredEndType` is present in some element.

The part where no properties are incompatible is represented by [intersecting](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) `T[I]` with `Partial<RequiredEndType>`.  If `T[I]` has any incompatible property, then that intersection will produce the [impossible `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type) for that property, and you'll get an error.

The part where each property is present is represented by intersecting by  `{ [K in keyof RequiredEndType as Exclude<K, TupleToKeys<T>>]: RequiredEndType[K] }`.  The construct `{[K in keyof U as Exclude<K, P>]: U[K]}` acts like `Omit<U, P>` using [the `Omit` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys).  It uses [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) to implement it, but it's the same operation; so what are we omitting?  We are taking `RequiredEndType`, and omitting all the properties in `TupleToKeys<T>`.  What's `TupleToKeys<T>`?  That definition grabs the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of all the keys of all the elements of `T`.  So that whole term is essentially an object containing properties of `RequiredEndType` which are not mentioned in *any* of the elements of `T`.  If that is empty, everything is fine.  Otherwise all the members of `T` will fail to type check because we are requiring properties not present in any member.

---

Okay, let's test it out:

```
declare const addToBaseA: ObjectExtensionFunction<{}, { a: boolean }>;
declare const addToBaseB: ObjectExtensionFunction<{}, { b: boolean }>;
declare const addToBaseC: ObjectExtensionFunction<{}, { c: boolean }>;   
 
myEndPoint([addToBaseA, addToBaseB]);
myEndPoint([addToBaseA, addToBaseB, addToBaseC]);
myEndPoint([addToBaseB, addToBaseA]);
myEndPoint([addToBaseA, addToBaseC]); // error!
// -------> ~~~~~~~~~~  ~~~~~~~~~~
// not assignable to type '{ a: boolean; } & Partial<RequiredEndType> & { b: boolean; }'
// not assignable to type '{ c: boolean; } & Partial<RequiredEndType> & { b: boolean; }'

declare const addToBaseBBad: ObjectExtensionFunction<{}, { b: number }>;
myEndPoint([addToBaseA, addToBaseBBad]); // error!
// -------------------> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
//   Type '{ b: number; }' is not assignable to type 'never'.
```

Looks good.  The first three calls succeed as desired.  The fourth call fails because `b` was forgotten and neither of the elements' return types extends `{b: boolean}`.  And the fifth call fails because `addToBaseBBad` because `b` was mistyped.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShCOBXAlgJwgEwKIDsMBVxoBeKAbwCgpqoBDALigCMB7FgGwlpwBoqamjVhy44KAXwoVQkKAHkmAKwgBjYFgAewCDgDOyFjgBiiHGoM4APPigQtOjLqgslq4DygANW-bxOXymoAfFCkABRMtLoQjPgAlKEh3gBkUPgA3FIy0PiIYJz4LADSECC61j7aflDotBiG7CB0OCAA2gC6IaRkUK0AklDIOFAA1qUsAGZp7YxjIJNp-e1Q4q04iAC2TBCo7ZkUGKrstOhQE6bmhlAbILgYAAosQ8AVdlWOzW2dYfzUAW66Ri1eo4Rq9AB0kJ6-UGwzmC3wM3krjUmiq+kMJjMwAsljI4j4NCJiz6y2Sv2J9xOONo7EscCQaEwd0IkBC5OJNGhRVho3GUwZKHQ2DwrOgUSgmhU7EQh0sRQ8uXyEEKJTK1iCQSRgqZIoIRFaRWWkiJIXE7TijG4IH2h2lJ2gKkMumAdAwBBYACEohAAIKMBSBdS+DHGC44wx4gnkOhCNicbgrIKZO3HU5OvSuuoe73RT0BlHB9EWLGXKz4jw9QTMeOiJMpo4OqAZl1unM+gDCBaDaJ0odLEfL0Z6KjjIkT4mTUhud0ezzCrWzhVzfo8S69Ps9FsyM7wc5wwAX65XvrX7uXm7P7eiHe3FF3DyeB6P543eavF+ivrvD-3h8Xr4nh+b4QLecTpFAAD0kG2KgqAsKgACEFDQVAAC0GGYWhIQAH54fhBHUARxE4ShME4CwWa6PoADmOC0EwnBQMALDMUQUAAOQ9AwNbjjgEHiFAqRUqgNJ0jqwoskQ7IxtWwgJvxKwcWRUAUVRtH0Yx0AsWxshcc2Y4KQJQlQCJYn0ggQrMqK0kmVWhmiAJykHI26bOlmgGbt6GDdm4vZ6CW4a4hWsmMOsWw7PW963HuT7-sePqnm2n4QJ63nblBME7PBSEqVh+UFVhuEkSRKnUGKnH2apmzbKgTmDE4al0NRyB0QxTE6dknE4BAABuOwceCFBAA)

Comment: Hmm - I am trying to play around with this a bit, just to understand it a bit more, but for the life of me can't figure out, why does it suddenly stop working, if I change the declaration of the `ObjectExtensionFunction` to `type ObjectExtensionFunction<T extends object, X extends object> = (base: T, next: X) => void;` (basically, removing the need of that function to return a value) - you are not checking the return type of the functions anywhere, so why does that break it?

Comment: You've changed the `X` type parameter from a covariant to a contravariant position, so type relationships change in direction (e.g., if `X1 extends X2` then now `ObjectExtensionFunction<{}, X2> extends ObjectExtensionFunction<{}, X1>`), so the check doesn't do what it did originally.  This seems like a followup question and out of scope for the question as asked, so I don't think I'm going to engage much here, if that's okay.