# TypeScript: Generic type of rest parameters to use in the return type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have a function for a ZIP Composition in TypeScript which any number of Arrays as parameters and should return a new array with an element of each input array. The problem is the type of the returned array.

The function should have the same return type as the zip function in python or in lodash.

```js
function zipComp<T>(...arrs: T[][]) { ... }
zipComp([1, 2], [false, true]) // expected: [number, boolean][], actual: unknown[]
zipComp(["a", "b", "c"], [1, 2, 3], [{}, {}, {}]) // expected: [string, number, object][], actual: unknown[]
```

I looked at the types from lodash to see how they did it.

```js
// from lodash (array.d.ts)
zip<T1, T2>(arrays1: List<T1>, arrays2: List<T2>): Array<[T1, T2]>;
zip<T1, T2, T3>(arrays1: List<T1>, arrays2: List<T2>, arrays3: List<T3>): Array<[T1, T2, T3]>;
zip<T1, T2, T3, T4>(arrays1: List<T1>, arrays2: List<T2>, arrays3: List<T3>, arrays4: List<T4>): Array<[T1, T2, T3, T4]>;
zip<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5>(arrays1: List<T1>, arrays2: List<T2>, arrays3: List<T3>, arrays4: List<T4>, arrays5: List<T5>): Array<[T1, T2, T3, T4, T5]>;
zip<T>(...arrays: Array<List<T>>): Array<Array<T>>; // => here is the problem
```

This implementation sort of works, but has the same problem if there are more than 5 input arrays.

Is there any way to write this arguments type in general, without having a case for any number of arguments?

Comment: You could use mapped tuple types like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WG2bVm) shows.  Does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make the function [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in `T`, the element type of the output array (so if the array produces a `[X, Y, Z][]` then `T` is `[X, Y, Z]`) and then give the function a [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) whose of a [mapped tuple/array type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) over `T`:

```
declare function zipComp<T extends any[]>(
    ...args: { [I in keyof T]: T[I][] }
): T[]
```

In the mapped type `{ [I in keyof T]: T[I][] }`, for each numeric-like index `I` in the `T` array, the element type `T[I]` at that index is mapped to an array of those elements `T[I][]`.  So if `T` is `[X, Y, Z]`, then the mapped type is `[X[], Y[], Z[]]`.

Note that because the mapped type in question is *homomorphic* (as described in [What does "homomorphic mapped type" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59790508/2887218) ) the compiler is able to infer `T` from the value passed in for `args`.  (If this weren't true, then inference might fail and we'd  need to rewrite the call signature.)

Also note that rest argument types tend to be inferred as [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) types by the compiler instead of just unordered array types, which is what we want.

All of this means that, if args is of type `[X[], Y[], Z[]]` then the output will be of type `[X, Y, Z][]`.

---

Or at least it should be; let's try it out:

```
const nb = zipComp([1, 2], [false, true]);
// const nb: [number, boolean][];

const sno = zipComp(["a", "b", "c"], [1, 2, 3], [{}, {}, {}]);
// const sno: [string, number, {}][];

const hmm = zipComp([""], [1], [true], [new Date()], [null], 
   [undefined], [Symbol()], [() => 2]);
// const hmm: [string, number, boolean, Date, null, 
//   undefined, symbol, () => 2][]
```

Looks good!  The compiler happily produces the output type from the input type even with relatively long inputs.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.5#code/LAKAJgpgxgNghgJwgAgGYFcB2UAuBLAe02QC88AHAYQIFtyAeAFWQgA8cJMwBnZOTAJ4BtALoA+ABShkM5ADoFiAObcAXMgDeyIQElkeYgGsIAgqmSMR6xrpGjkAX1ABKa6NCgoRbjmSYARsgAvKQU1HQSQgCMADTIAEwicUKocDDcEHE4COgQIs4A3KAA9MXIXpg+fv7qQpjoNP4QCHH+BAQwEPx2Ip7evtyYBMGhVLTkkQBEcJNxk-6zyJNQk0nasQlxAMxrQhoOcfuHDvlFIKXl-ciDBLU+CAZKcfWNzcc9fZW+ABY0NCNkMYRISTVbJKK7bK5XaYCAAd2QABE4BwJM4YegYDBdlhIKgDBAwLsAMoCRodNG7NHBMQJU4lMoVKq-Gh3bKPZ4NJotZBtDpdTBxZEcTlYuK4iD42FgOLcMltGBxalBWmJURAA)

Answer (score 0):

This is quite peculiar and shouldn't actually error.

`<T extends any[]>` means that `T` should be of an array type.

A workaround would be to set the following in your tsconfig.json compilerOptions object.

```
"skipLibCheck": true
```