# TypeScript: accept an array of different generics and return a merged type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, entity-component-system

I'm trying to figure out Entity Component System and for usability I need to be able to pass an array of different Component definitions and get a merged type as a result.

I'm trying to do this:

```js
const Position = defineComponent({ x: 0, y: 0 });
const Container = defineComponent({ capacity: 0, contents: new Array<{ item: number; amount: number }>() });

world.withComponents(Position, Container).forEach(([id, entity]) => {
  console.log(entity.x);
  consone.log(entity.capacity);
});
```

Full code:

```js
interface ISchema {}

type SimpleType = number | string | boolean;

type Type<V> = V extends SimpleType
  ? V
  : V extends Array<infer RT>
  ? Array<Type<RT>>
  : V extends ISchema
  ? ComponentType<V>
  : never;

type ComponentType<T extends ISchema> = {
  [key in keyof T]: Type<T[key]>;
};

type ComponentDefinition<T extends ISchema> = {
  id: Symbol;
  type: ComponentType<T>;
};

function defineComponent<T extends ISchema>(schema: T): ComponentDefinition<T> {
  return {
    id: Symbol(),
    type: schema as ComponentType<T>,
  };
}

type TupleToIntersection<T extends any[]> = {
  [I in keyof T]: (x: T[I]) => void;
}[number] extends (x: infer I) => void
  ? I
  : never;

class World
{
  protected readonly entities = new Map<number, { data: ISchema; components: Set<Symbol> }>();

  withComponents<T extends ComponentType<ISchema>>(
    definitions: ComponentDefinition<T>[]
  ): Array<[number, TupleToIntersection<T[]>]> {
    const result: Array<[number, TupleToIntersection<T[]>]> = [];
    for (const [id, entity] of this.entities) {
      let isMatch = true;

      for (const def of definitions) {
        if (!entity.components.has(def.id)) {
          isMatch = false;
          break;
        }
      }

      if (isMatch) {
        result.push([id, entity.data as TupleToIntersection<T[]>]);
      }
    }

    return result;
  }
}
```

Currently I getting the following error on this line:

```
world.withComponents([Position, Container])
```

```
Argument of type 'ComponentDefinition<{ capacity: number; contents: { item: number; amount: number; }[]; }>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentDefinition<{ x: number; y: number; }>'.
  Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
    Type 'ComponentType<{ capacity: number; contents: { item: number; amount: number; }[]; }>' is missing the following properties from type 'ComponentType<{ x: number; y: number; }>': x, yts(2345)
```

So my problem is that I'm not able to figure out how to accept an array of different generics.

Comment: Is [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/W4jKON) what you're looking for? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: By any chance could you explain why changing `...definitions` to `definitions` breaks everything? I would think it's the same array

Comment: I'd need to see a [mre] of what you mean by "breaking everything".  Do you want me to write up an answer to this question as asked or do you want to [edit] so it's an array and not a rest parameter?

Comment: Of course, sorry. This is what I mean by breaking https://tsplay.dev/NdER6m. `Position.type & Container.type` turns into `Position.type | Container.type`. Edit so it's an array and not a rest parameter please. I just didn't expect the behaviour to change.

Comment: Okay do you want me to edit your question for you or do you want to do it?

Comment: The solution is to replace `definitions: [I in keyof T]: ComponentDefinition<T[I]>; }` with `definitions: [] | { [I in keyof T]: ComponentDefinition<T[I]>; }`, right? https://tsplay.dev/w6x7Rm

Comment: I would use a variadic tuple wrapper but that should also work. You’re just trying to give a hint to the compiler that arrays should be inferred as tuples.

Comment: When I get off mobile and to a real computer I’ll follow up

Comment: [This](https://tsplay.dev/WP1yLw) is what I mean; a [variadic tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) gives that tuple hint.  Shall I write this version up?

Comment: I will do so when I get a chance, probably after I wake up in the morning 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make `withComponents()` [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) `T` of arguments to `ComponentDefinition<>` for each element of the `definitions` input.  That is, if `definitions` is of type `[ComponentDefinition<X>, ComponentDefinition<Y>, ComponentDefinition<Z>]`, then `T` would be `[X, Y, Z]`.  Then you can make the type of `definitions` be a [mapped type over the tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) `T`, and the compiler can infer `T` from `definitions` because it's a *homomorphic* mapped type (see [What does "homomorphic mapped type" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59790508/2887218)).  Like this:

```
withComponents<T extends ComponentType<ISchema>[]>(
        definitions: [...{ [I in keyof T]: ComponentDefinition<T[I]> }] 
): Array<[number, TupleToIntersection<T>]>
```

So `{ [I in keyof T]: ComponentDefinition<T[I]> }` is the relevant mapped type.  And I've wrapped it in a [variadic tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) `[...`+`]`, which, as the implementing pull request [microsoft/TypeScript#39094](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/39094) mentions, "can conveniently be used to indicate a preference for inference of tuple types".

And everywhere else in your code that uses `T` will need to be updated to account for the fact that it's `[X, Y, Z]` and not `X | Y | Z`... that is, every `TupleToIntersection<T[]>` should be replaced with `TupleToIntersection<T>`.

---

Let's try it out:

```
const Position = defineComponent({ x: 0, y: 0 });
const Container = defineComponent({ capacity: 0, contents: new Array<{ item: number; amount: number }>() });
const world = new World();
world.withComponents([Position, Container]).forEach(([id, entity]) => {
    console.log(entity.x);
    console.log(entity.capacity);
});
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIGUEAsIFs7IDeyAvgFBlgCeADiusLjQDYQAqtKAvMiAK64ARtGQAfZAGcwUUAHMxyQQHslrOCADcFanWQc6AHgBqAPmQ8jyCAA9IIACYTkDJq30QyyL8gD8yI57eAFz+VrYQDk4AglBQcFQGoDAiAEpsJoFefjFxCe4GaSYZ3sghljZ2jmiYOPiZvsgAwkpMSiARYPmm9SHtAG7QWpScTS00bR35bGGVThjYeHBmPIT1ANoA1hBUyKDIW1RKMHoAuiFTm9snJlokQzooza3t4AAiEDCgwGDAbQbTFQiVXmtSW5iI9WA9hC6CoQlUWhKDxCT3GL06nH+NzIdwoMD4IAQPzayHsH1AEFRE3A-xmQLmNUWJgAFBIFvhzgBKFFjalgd6fEDfX4gLEQkpQCBgPhQEDikreKEwuHKZjMzkAGnqSM4ITZoOQcCcVPRUxMWpKuPIw10bD4LHYSlQ4GgEggRJFtMBkUNICoa2u4NWJTWqF2coOR1OIWZ1nOoZOnPMZj6SihtzW-CE0BOdJ9sZCSREqCTXBTafs9T8qB6vAgAygQwQzCNTgA6kooMx7PKvDQoEpIESID3JXB7G1mDsOsKIE4eO0AO7IACycBoBizwigGqIpLgYDgIRBiw0yAQvPREhhUoMsPhzDMJBZnKGJUX3ywJo6Ei94R937gPkJ74CYAYstq3hkoKwptNeyBrAAdMhxChuG+zbFGbBnKMzwdAKXzEqKbAJk+uYAPTkcgBgALQ0cgfRwDI47AAgyDSg67EjDgkr1NyyA5PEBiZgI267naDpsE6LpQG6Hp-OkgbBgqXgXiAUjIJKEh8MwYAhIJCQidmO56PabjSZAsnukR-zgYGPABoiKnIDAnbIMyakaWsUK7jO1C5lGYBYMAEiIX5wBzkmynOd4rBgLsEhrmA2DgtIfAQG+MXeK5UDuZ58XQcgUbQYRIoSFFkFZbsxzMgAhH5VCIReeHgKFWBGsy0GIVCnIVVVVUhUlKU8PAzBuk5-XOYIY4bBNk2kJVCrWpNwA1YNB7YH181eFpOlgIhNB8BIWDMt59i+eA3yNfYB4EEapmSRZrrWZ6JHXImc0xeQX0UDFkrSrKmlznthpOOoVBzeQ1r5cgAAKSgSLBco8CV7SAWAzLEHGyAAAy7lQIQ46Qr5kDDzTgHAFK5Sj5Jo5eHSY+e66IFdhO7mpdhgPBS4CbEQnEN8eC9KJgyGrgSgEnpvAi7lz7qsTWgw4unbduCPMdl29jqloyua4hH5BejEinfDiNEbu5OHlTiaITlACiiAnadPlWJd-mlmY0XnnBqgQIhzBKLIzINYh1gkyUnm+-7gfB27jUIMzCBXSTJCvkAA)