# How to get the corresponding type for the following variables

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

```
interface Model {
  bar: number
  foo: string
}

async function getSth(a: number, b: string): Promise<Model> {
  return await Promise.resolve({
    bar: a,
    foo: b,
  })
}

function createA(m: Model): number {
  return m.bar
}

function createB(m: Model): string {
  return m.foo
}
```

GetSth is an asynchronous function. Both createA and createB need to rely on its return value as a parameter to run. So I want to build an asynchronous function with memory function for easy use, as follows:

```
function memorifyFuncs<T extends any[]>(asyncFunc: (...args: T) => Promise<any>) {
  return <Fs extends ((...args: any[]) => any)[]>(...createFuncs: Fs) => {
    const cache: Record<string, any> = {}

    return createFuncs.map(
      <F extends (...args: any[]) => any>(func: F) =>
        async (...args: T): Promise<ReturnType<F>> => {
          const key = args.map((arg) => JSON.stringify(arg)).join('&')
          if (!cache[key]) {
            cache[key] = await asyncFunc(...args)
          }
          return func(cache[key])
        }
    )
  }
}
```

MemoryFuncs receives asynchronous functions similar to getSth, sets the cache internally, and then receives and builds functions similar to createA and createB. It caches the implementation process and maps it out through the map. However, I try to find that the corresponding function returned cannot get its return value type:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dvBd.png)

get the corresponding type for the variables below

Comment: Please, provider a playground link

Comment: [typescript_playground](https://s.r.sn.cn/LJNDcE)

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WKpAGw) meet your needs? If so I can write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the call signature to `memorityFuncs` be more [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html), perhaps as follows:

```
declare function memorifyFuncs<T extends any[], R>(
  asyncFunc: (...args: T) => Promise<R>
): <O extends any[]>(...createFuncs: {
  [I in keyof O]: (arg: R) => O[I]; }
) => { [I in keyof O]: (...args: T) => Promise<O[I]>; }
```

Here we want `memorifyFuncs` to be generic not only in `T` corresponding to the argument list of the `asyncFunc` callback, but also in `R` corresponding to the awaited return type of that callback.  You also need the returned function to be generic in `O`, the [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) of awaited output types for each function in `createFuncs`.  So if `createFuncs` is of type `[(x: string) => number, (x: string) => boolean, (x: string) => Date]`, then `O` will be `[number, boolean, Date]`.

We can then write the type of `createFuncs` and the return type as [mapped tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays).  The type of `createFuncs` is `{[I in keyof O]: (arg: R) => O[I]}`, meaning that it's an array of functions: each one takes `R` as an input, and outputs the corresponding element type of `O`.  And the type of the output is `{[I in keyof O]: (...args: T) => Promise<O[I]>}`, meaning that it's an array of functions: each one takes the same input as `asyncFunc`, and outputs a `Promise` for the corresponding element type of `O`.  Note that because the type of `createFuncs` is a *homomorphic* mapped type on `O` (see [What does "homomorphic mapped type" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59790508/2887218)), the compiler is able to *infer* `O` from `createFuncs` (otherwise it would have been more complicated to express).

---

I'm not going to worry about getting the compiler to be happy with the implementation of `memorifyFuncs`.  There's no way it can follow that your algorithm obeys the rules of the mapped tuple types.  You should just [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) your way through that, or use [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) to loosen checking there:

```
function memorifyFuncs<T extends any[], R>(asyncFunc: (...args: T) => Promise<R>) {
  return <O extends any[]>(...createFuncs: { [I in keyof O]: (arg: R) => O[I] }):
    { [I in keyof O]: (...args: T) => Promise<O[I]> } => {
    const cache: Record<string, any> = {}
    return createFuncs.map(
      (func: any) =>
        async (...args: any) => {
          const key = args.map((arg: any) => JSON.stringify(arg)).join('&')
          if (!cache[key]) {
            cache[key] = await asyncFunc(...args)
          }
          return func(cache[key])
        }
    ) as any
  }
}
```

---

Okay, let's try it out:

```
const [funcA, funcB] = memorifyFuncs(getSth)(createA, createB)
// const funcA: (a: number, b: string) => Promise<number>
// const funcB: (a: number, b: string) => Promise<string>

async function foo() {
  const n = await funcA(1, "two");
  console.log(n.toFixed(2)) // "1.00"
  const s = await funcB(2, "three");
  console.log(s.toUpperCase()) // "THREE"
}
foo();
```

Looks good.  The compiler infers that `funcA` is of type `(a: number, b: string) => Promise<number>`, because `createA` returns a `number`... and it infers that `funcB` is of type `(a: number, b: string) => Promise<string>`, because `createB` returns a `string`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIHsAmEA2yDeAUMsgEZxQBcyIArgLanTHIzrrUDOYUoA5oQC+hQnE4BPEAla0pYYOhDI+EMAGUwACwAUcanUbQANGS49+ASmoAFKOnrBOEADwZsOAHwEWUVbShKcADucMBgyLb2jhAAdL6c6DgAbhDaRCQk5FTIcEYsJGwcZHkkghZCIjCyCPKKyAi+cJAAgtr01G64VjQMTFDeJL5g-kr0MVkVhFVyCkoNEE0QAEJtHVhdZrwgfAPIQyPIY4WTAPQAVITYCDgUKNM1s4cQ9Oi8MOIAYtWczgAqyBAAB6QECYTg5EDiADaAF0TAAlDzaFhiSQIL5SajaGI4ih8TjUX4WZAAXi8kQcTmciMI3WcAHkAcCIKDwXBIbCkTiYvNFhiEATdlCAJLIUDIADWEHE6BgyHpMKxeOo8OJZPlIphAG5kMI1V58MgRWKlFKZXKFVjuXjBUTSeS7JSXPTNR4dcIzidKtVaqNnq9gO9+T9-kCQWCIdC4chEboJFJ+VbcVB8YT9RFHdFqR5iek9n4AsgGUzw2yOTCuTjeZBg9RDcbxWbZfLFchdCmVemXcKYbqrPkCEbRY3pc3LW3rSnbemKVnuxXdfbdiQEIpuPVEJoICqIKuoJhnNwtnwTOzxF4SQRhBl88NC9WIMGYvQ4AAHZE3kjae7UM-6gc3qiUgTsmqaRumeafhkq4gOuZqkjkU7Pm+2jtnwv6QumABSaj0gAcjER78IG4hoRYFgxAAVugoDaAA5AAZHR5RQTegZtgAhAgm4QFCZowrmAGsdxCBbnx0q9pewShOEQHotU2KgZwLGsaUQk3vshb3NoIlifxKlQdeGTEmIkYsMIwgiDB65QvczQmPcSySU8LxvJ83zaCo6haBYOmNC0JgPks5QnCc9RruEdlKvovTGKYyBEdsM6ZlSBh9B4hCheFsGRdUSzRT0hhQCYpCbJYS6zlSiV8BlojxtI9y+qw7DaIJK4RTQCHSWEMhSK0ACMJgAERgEE6BDRYWosNZiSxDg6B8NoIAxGA6AfMAgIQJg2gAEzkcgWVDf1MQAAwnUN00deCUkhD1jm7cNWi+BAE1Te1sGzTE82LZwK3oAAqq+r7QAAwmIqT7YdvwABLwgAonDF3CIUrVakAA)

Comment: so the most important is that the array type in typescript means that all the elements  in it has the same type, if i want to know the particular type of each,  just consider that array is a object, truly in javascript, array is object,  is it ?

Comment: In JavaScript and TypeScript, arrays are objects.  You might be asking about [tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types), which are heterogeneous arrays, usually of known length and order.