# Why sometimes typescript cannot intelligently infer the type of return value

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

This may be a simple question, but it also confuses me a bit.
for example:

```js
function test(val: { bar: string, foo: number }):string {
  if (true) {
    return val.bar
  } else {
    return val.foo
  }
}
```

In my opinion, if typescript can intelligently analyze the execution process of this function, the type of the return value should be 'string'. However, in fact, typescript only focuses on the return of the function, so the final inferred result is' string | number '.

But we know that 'string | number' is not the result we want. If we label the return type as' string ', a compilation error will occur. To address this compilation error, we have to use type assertions.

I think sometimes typescript has the ability to analyze the process of function execution, but why didn't it choose to do this?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that demonstrates what you're talking about.  If I paste that into an IDE [like this](https://tsplay.dev/Wz7R3w) I see an error that `return val.foo` is unreachable, and nothing about `string` being the wrong return type. That error needs to be fixed before you can rely on any return type inferred by the compiler.   I'm sure there is some explanation for how the compiler infers return types independently of reachability analysis, but it's hard to say anything about this particular example since the problem it has is not the one you seem to be describing.

Comment: (see prev comment) Assuming the example is updated to demonstrate the issue directly, it looks like the canonical answer is at [ms/TS#51800](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/51800): unreachable code errors are transitory since you need to fix them, and once you fix them the types will work out.  If you've written a return statement that's unreachable, presumably the fix will be to make it reachable (in which case the union type is what you want) or to remove it (in which case the union type will go away), and in either case TS isn't doing something "wrong" by inferring the union.

Comment: (see prev comments).  Does that fully address the question?  If so I'll write it up as an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: so in this case, TS has sufficient ability to infer types, provided that I need to fix some errors. But what I want to express is that sometimes TS is not so intelligent，such as this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75729515/how-to-get-the-corresponding-type-for-the-following-variables) you have solved, here is the [case](http://c.nxw.so/bBVxt). in this case , we need to use 'as any' to loosen type checking , i mean that TS cannot intelligently infer what happened to this function during execution, but this is obvious to human, why can't TS ?

Comment: Any specific example you choose will presumably have some specific reason why the compiler can't figure something out that is "obvious to a human".  If you want to [edit] the question to use a different example, that's your prerogative, but it should be done in the question and not as a comment.

Comment: (see prev comment) But if you're really asking the *general* question "why can't the compiler figure out everything that is obvious to a human", then that's probably too broad for SO since it's not a specific programming problem. Regardless, it has an obvious-to-a-human answer: the compiler is not a human being and lacks the cognition to see things based on how "obvious" they are.  Furthermore, some "obvious" things are not true, and the compiler might be warning about something that can actually happen but the human being missed.