# TypeScript generic wrapper around union function

Tags: typescript, generics, union

I can't figure out a way how to type a wrapper function. I'm creating a utility that will add a `console.log` to an `onChange` callback of a form control. What am I missing here?

```
interface TextInput {
    type: 'TextInput';
    onChange: (value: string) => void;
}

interface NumberInput {
    type: 'NumberInput';
    onChange: (value: number) => void;
}

type FormControl = TextInput | NumberInput;

export const withLogger = <TFormControl extends FormControl>(formControl: TFormControl): TFormControl => ({
    ...formControl,
    onChange: (...args: Parameters<TFormControl['onChange']>) => {
        console.log(formControl.type, 'onChange', args);
        // Error: A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter.(2556)
        return formControl.onChange(...args);
    },
});
```

I tried multiple ways of typing the args of the onChange wrapper including:

```
onChange: (value: any) => formControl.onChange(value)
onChange: <TValue>(value: TValue) => formControl.onChange(value)
onChange: (value: number | string) => formControl.onChange(value)
```

These would fail with `Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.(2345)`

Edit: [TypeScript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoQB5gJIgA4CuYyA3gFDKXJgCeeEAXMgOTpa6FjMDcFVA9iADCACzggA5o2QAKAG5wANgWkBnMFFASAlMgC8APmRz%20wACa8AvmTKhIsRCgByBALYAjaByKk%20lWvRMzC4eXvhEPH7IgqLiUkzySipMIG6eULqGxqYWZNZkASgAYvxQrkKCGvyK%20miYOOHEAD7IIeneYLxkmHilxAiC6sgA7sBgIgAy-BJSULUAPKglZRXgUNXI9RAgZqrIy%20WV64oGMjClh2vVTEsXq1WK2jcH98f6RjLkVMgAdH-nKyO1QANFEYmJJNJEso1BotMgWqlQhl3r5vt8BiBVNUID9FNMzncgYofoVgSxwXEIMxyQoYdpeOiqFAIGACFAQMgAZcHj9KZDoSoGVFLKDLMKgA)

Comment: This is essentially a limitation with generic conditional types, and the recommended approach is to refactor to use generic mapped types and indexed accesses, as described in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) and shown for your example [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/we6gVN). Does that fully address your question?  If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Wow I didn’t know of this limitation. This answers it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TypeScript compiler is not able to do much analysis on [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) that depend on [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameters.  Since [the `Parameters<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype) is implemented as a conditional type, and since `TFormControl` is an as-yet-unspecified generic type parameter, the compiler really has no idea what `Parameters<TFormControl['onChange']>` might be, and whether it might be allowed as the parameter list to a function of type `TFormControl['onChange']`.  The compiler doesn't give any significance to the identifier `Parameters`, and it can't "see into" the definition of `Parameters<T>` in an abstract way.  If `T` is some specific function type, then `Parameters<T>` can be evaluated and checked against `T`.

So in the compiler's attempt to analyze `formControl.onChange(...args)`, it ends up widening `formControl` from the generic `TFormControl` to the nongeneric `FormControl`, which is of the [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `((value: string) => void) | ((value: number) => void)`, and a union of functions is essentially uncallable.

---

The recommended approach to something like this is to refactor so that your generic operations are represented by [indexed accesses](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) into homomorphic [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) (see [What does "homomorphic mapped type" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59790508/2887218) if that term needs explaining) instead of conditional types.  This technique is described in detail in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).

First you write a simple mapping object type which connects the [literal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) `"TextInput"` and `"NumberInput"` types to their corresponding parameter list types:

```
interface InputArgs {
    TextInput: [value: string];
    NumberInput: [value: number];
}
```

Then we can define `Input<K>` as a *distributive object type* over `K` (where we index into a mapped type over `K` to get a union):

```
type Input<K extends keyof InputArgs = keyof InputArgs> =
    { [P in K]: { type: P, onChange: (...args: InputArgs[P]) => void } }[K];
```

The above `Input` type subsumes your `TextInput`, `NumberInput`, and `FormControl` types, as shown:

```
type TextInput = Input<"TextInput">;
type NumberInput = Input<"NumberInput">;
type FormControl = Input;
```

And now you can write `withLogger()` this way:

```
export const withLogger = <K extends keyof InputArgs>(formControl: Input<K>): Input<K> => ({
    ...formControl,
    onChange: (...args: InputArgs[K]) => {
        console.log(formControl.type, 'onChange', args);
        return formControl.onChange(...args); // okay
    },
});
```

This works because `onChange` for an `Input<K>` is explicitly represented as being of type `(...args: InputArgs[K]) => void`, and you can therefore pass it an argument list of type `InputArgs[K]`.  The function and its arguments stay generic and nothing is widened to an unusable union.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQEkwAcCuECCMA5gM6oDewq1qAKlAB4Sa4QBcqA2gG4IA2OKBxIQY4IgF0A3FRoA5HAFsARrBZ4OPfoI5glqmNOABfYMAgBPLGnUQAPAGlUjaGAAmZANZQLAezgY2HiEpKgAvKjefgG2ISQAfOGy1ORcAAqo4KgOEhypltYcaQA0qL5gAMIAFghgREKoABQAdK0IxCQcsR2caRIAlOGJ3L4gbqjGE5w5MuZWaPRMtuGBrHYARIvMQRDr8TIFaAoqajsrthvHBrZ7B-OoAGK+MIoV5aK+fOc7s4xYzxBUEhyiJUAB3EAQKoAGV8RHqMBWjmcTCg7i8Pn8q2CHXijTgz1e7xgny6O0c8X6ZLWDkSYUSjUoNFQrWaBJeb0gJL4xWSZUqNTqDRabQ61JxpGmAyGFD5zOBYBInygzT4cPxhM5Hz4zUOpQA5OVqrV6vrSu1SP0ZMzmTAoBAcDAwKh2USuZ9mkbBfURc0LSQrXzjLzjIGgA)