# Typescript keyof operator for object type

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics

I want to get keys of type A and write them to type B.
I expect type B to be "x", but I receive "x | undefined".
Why does keyof operator also includes undefined to result type?
I understand that I can tentatively wrap type in Required util, but I just want to understand the way how keyof works because in doc I couldn't find anything.

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeAPA-ALigZ2AJwEsA7AcygB8oiBXAG1oF8BuAKFEigCEFkBtAaQggoxKAGshAewBmsALpZBIBrwkgZ8pkA)

```js
type A = {x?: string | null};
type B = {[Key in keyof A]: Key}[keyof A];
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with `keyof`; your type `A` is `{x?: string | null | undefined}`, as you could see [in the same playground you posted](https://tsplay.dev/w25D9W). [Optional properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties) automatically allow `undefined`. Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: `type B = {[Key in keyof A]-?: Exclude<Key, null>}[keyof A];`

Comment: @jcalz sorry, I left the wrong link for the playground, I updated it, and now I get type "x" | undefined.

Comment: If you just want the keys why are you mapping it? just `type B = keyof A; // "x"`? [playground](https://tsplay.dev/mpjezw)

Comment: Okay, but still, it's not `keyof` that's adding `undefined`.  When you map over an existing type, optional properties stay optional, and therefore still have `undefined` in it.  So `{[K in keyof A]: K}` is `{x?: "x"}` which is equivalent to `{x?: "x" | undefined}`, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/m3x0qW).  Does that explain things or am I still missing something?

Answer (score 1):

A *homomorphic* mapped type (described in [What does "homomorphic mapped type" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59790508/2887218) ) of the form `{[K in keyof T]: ⋯T[K]⋯}` preserves the [optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties) and/or [`readonly`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#readonly-properties) nature of the mapped properties.  Optional property in, optional property out:

```
type A = { x?: string | null };
//   ^? { x?: string | null | undefined }

type B0 = { [Key in keyof A]: Key };
//   ^? { x?: "x" | undefined }
```

And optional properties automatically include `undefined` in their domain, and indeed when you use IntelliSense to hover over the type, you'll generally see `| undefined` in there, as shown above. (This assumes you're using [`--strictNullChecks`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictNullChecks) but not [the `--exactOptionalPropertyTypes` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#exact-optional-property-types---exactoptionalpropertytypes).)

And therefore, when you [index into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) it to get the values as a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types), any optional property will contribute an `undefined` to the resulting union:

```
type B = B0[keyof A];
//   ^? "x" | undefined
```

So the `| undefined` isn't coming from `keyof` per se, it's coming from the `| undefined` in the type you're mapping over.

---

As you mentioned, you can use `Required` or [the `-?` mapping modifier](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#mapping-modifiers) to fix that:

```
type B = { [K in keyof A]-?: K }[keyof A];
// type B = "x"
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeUAeB+AXFAzsATgJYB2A5lAD5TECuANnVAL4DcAUAPQdQ8B66bUJCgAhAAwJkUANoBpCCCgkoAawUB7AGawAutnmLWnbnwFDoIyeOlqQW3ey48o-NoPAWATJJRylxVQ1tGB0AWiwoWWYbIIdjKHNRb0QAIlQUoA)