# How to maintain optional property mode while type remapping in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I am using `TypeScript 4.9.5` and I need to utilize type remapping. During the remapping process, I want to maintain the `optional property mode`. Specifically, I need to `add a "child" prefix` to each property of an interface and convert the original literal types of properties to uppercase. Here is my interface definition:

```js
interface ChildrenProps {
    children: ReactNode;
    className?: string;
    style?: CSSProperties;
}
```

I expect to transform it into the following form:

```js
interface ChildrenPropsWithPrefix {
    childChildren: ReactNode;
    childClassName?: string;
    childStyle?: CSSProperties;
}
```

To achieve this, I have written the following type utility:

```js
/** Make all properties with a prefix and convert the first character of properties to uppercase */
type PrefixAll<T, P extends string> = {
    [K in keyof T & string as `${P}${Capitalize<K>}`]: T[K];
}
```

However, the result I obtained is as follows:

```js
interface ChildrenPropsWithPrefix {
    childChildren: ReactNode;
    childClassName: string;
    childStyle: CSSProperties;
}
```

As you may notice, there is a difference between this result and my expected outcome. All the properties have become `required`, [TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.5#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQNwCwAUIwPQJICyyA1ligDZ84YYmCyxgWdAHdgMABYohlAsAAeKAHYATOAGEIGgG5jCwKKni45yKHhhi4EAkoijxkuDAhwArmDe4aLwIzIwwAJ6icAAKymoAggIAPAAqADQxcFiq9troFlDAGgDmAHxwALxwAN6McPVwANoA0nBFcDzhTnApcABkcAVFxSjoAAYAJNXRAL5Tushgssh8wABeWEnNpTNjALoAXD0te-QMM4yMRfZQBHi8unLAfFqUGrGu6LUMDXBWz68sBojtg7AA6UH4AByEC0WDOv1wfDQqChyBAWAA-EchiUEQ0LOE+FiQVQYGDdABlSkfNwwCSoM4XJgMa5iO64XjRGxAmC09DZXJadCxLAqVSJPhJR4At78jJkf4vMjlb6Ip4vN6k8GQmAwuH4+pIlFojHYwYwQp4uoEiLE826inU2kmBlMy4MZjMODxfA+FZ8cJwACScC03g0EHgGiwWB0YyVWhlmqBcA0fw1WkpdqwY0czmErldkkYuAMFjgAFFVKJ8Ny3jAjvXefzKjUbUbM1ryKH0TEeRoYGQ0h2-sjUKj0VgjmQwAOhyOfg0vRmAcnAcCeyhSOu3sPR4ndOPJxiZ4m94vfivE9midOajNF8zS+X4M3BwARCCSADq0B4WhNvOrZVGqDTnkCM69qQ74Lgex6mves7zvuS6dmuXaQVufa7kCqHqmuCFTmemEaPh4GZrexJHNUj6MMyQA), whereas I want them to `remain optional`.

Although I can address this issue by making `ParentProps extend Partial\<PrefixAll\<ChildrenProps, 'child'\>\>`, it alters the original structure of the interface, which might confuse other developer. I would like to avoid such a situation.

Can you suggest a solution or alternative approach that allows me to achieve the desired result while maintaining the optional property mode? I would greatly appreciate any code examples or insights you can provide.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Wv1ZQm) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @wonderflame you can get a homomorphic mapped type fairly easily, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76694437/2887218)

Comment: @jcalz I've actually tried to do so, but for some reason, it didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `PrefixAll<T, P>` to be a *homomorphic mapped type* over the properties of `T`, meaning that it preserves [optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties) and [`readonly`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#readonly-properties) property modifiers (see [What does "homomorphic mapped type" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59790508/2887218) for more information).  The standard way of doing that is to write `{[K in keyof T]: ⋯}` where the keys you are mapping over are `keyof` a generic type parameter.  This works for [remapped types via `as`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) also.

Your problem is that you wrote `{[K in keyof T & string]: ⋯}`, and the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) breaks the connection to `T`, since `(keyof T) & string` is not `keyof` anything directly.

If you change `keyof T & string` to `keyof T`, the resulting mapped type will be homomorphic, as desired.  But then you will not be allowed to use `Captialize<K>` because `K` might not be a `string`.  Luckily, you can just write `Captialize<K & string>` instead.  And when `K & string` evaluates to [`never`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type), it has the effect of suppressing the property entirely, just as if you had written `K in keyof T & string`.  So the solution is to move `& string` from the `in` clause to the `as` clause:

```
type PrefixAll<T, P extends string> = {
  [K in keyof T as `${P}${Capitalize<K & string>}`]: T[K];
}
```

Let's test it out:

```
interface ChildrenProps {
  children: ReactNode;
  className?: string;
  style?: CSSProperties;
}

type ChildrenPropsWithPrefix = PrefixAll<ChildrenProps, "child">;
/* type ChildrenPropsWithPrefix = {
    childChildren: ReactNode;
    childClassName?: string;
    childStyle?: CSSProperties;
} */
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoUWAcgewCYoDeywA6sAM4AWAKlZadBAIIgCiAHnALYAOANhHJgquAKohuOMMABucSHjrAoeAApwoYAJ4ARCLwggCIBMAgUAXMjBQArigC+AbgBQoSLEQoAwgGU-NSgcQy1zCmRiHCpGfn5rACJAPg3Adl3AWAJAITJAeD+E5BdXAp1DZCCIGGAOZjiAHhoAGhLkCA5IYwiKW1AAcwA+ZABeSNdkZABtAGkSEGQAawhtHBhkGmQ4CIADABJCNUdtnzheYDA4fmAALwhqyYAyZA6obp7HdYBdaxoJ17dHAo9oeBIZA+ej8PBQIxBEIRQjDZAIUHgozWdCYXAENwjBD8NYULA8CAAfmsD26mPuOkExOBAShoRkFh+hW0xRBwDBEJAdIowiopXKHAGJQhAqq-GqbI5kOCvAoDQSCPZeASPTcAHoAFQ2Fm+RGc7m8-kVIWwkZYxGSpEgFEYBDYfAQcnmpU+HEUPEE6mkkBdJ3wxF+SlE6z+QIy6AMig-ZAatVAA)