# Is there a way to match the type to the "key" change?

Tags: typescript, interface, type-inference

For example, I wrote the following code.

```
func({
  items: [
    {
      event: 'a',
      callback: (data) => {

      },
    },
    {
      event: 'b',
      callback: (data) => {

      },
    },
    {
      event: 'c',
      callback: (data) => {

      },
    },
  ],
});
```

I want is this.

- When the event is 'a', the data type of the callback factor is inferred to A interface.
- When the event is 'b', the data type of the callback factor is inferred to B interface.
- When the event is 'c', the data type of the callback factor is inferred to C interface.

Will it be possible?

The `addEventListener` seems to be already working, so I tried referring to this part, but it didn't work out.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wje1bW) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Yes! That's right! This is what I wanted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to define a mapping between the string [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) of the `event` property and the type of the intended `callback` parameter `data`.  Luckily TypeScript has an easy way to represent mappings from string literal types to arbitrary types: it's just an [object type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#object-types).  Like the following [`interface`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#interfaces):

```
interface EventMap {
    a: A;
    b: B;
    c: C;
}
```

One we have that, we can define `func()` as a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function like this:

```
declare function func<T extends (keyof EventMap)[]>(arg: {
    items: [...{ [I in keyof T]: {
        event: T[I],
        callback: (data: EventMap[T[I]]) => void
    } }]
}): void;
```

Here the type parameter `T` represents the [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) of `event` properties in the `items` array.  So if you call `func()` the way you show in your example, then we'd want `T` to be `["a", "b", "c"]`.

When you call `func()`, the compiler looks at the `items` property of the argument and tries to match it with the type `[...{[I in keyof T]: {event: T[I], callback: (data: EventMap[T[I]]) => void }]`.

That's a [mapped tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) which has been wrapped in the [variadic tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) `[...`+`]` to give the compiler a hint that you want `T` to be inferred as a tuple and not an unordered array (see [microsoft/TypeScript#39094](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/39094) where it says "the type `[...T]`, where `T` is an array-like type parameter, can conveniently be used to indicate a preference for inference of tuple types").

And because `{[I in keyof T]: {⋯T[I]⋯}}` is a *homomorphic* mapped type (see [What does "homomorphic mapped type" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59790508/2887218)), the compiler will be able to infer `T` from the elements of `items`.  For each element `T[I]` at numeric index `I` of the tuple type `T`, the corresponding element of `items` should have an `event` property of that type `T[I]`, and a `callback` property whose `data` callback parameter is of type `EventMap[T[I]]`, which means we [index into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) `EventMap` with the key `T[I]`.  The intent is that the compiler will infer `T[I]` from the `event` property, and then use that to [contextually type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) the `callback` `data` parameter.

Let's test it out:

```
func({
    items: [
        {
            event: 'a',
            callback: (data) => {
                //     ^?(parameter) data: A
            },
        },
        {
            event: 'b',
            callback: (data) => {
                //     ^?(parameter) data: B
            },
        },
        {
            event: 'c',
            callback: (data) => {
                //     ^?(parameter) data: C
            },
        },
    ],
});
// function func<["a", "b", "c"]>(⋯): void;
```

Looks good.  The compiler inferred `["a", "b", "c"]` for `T` as desired, and the `data` parameter of each `callback` is appropriately contextually typed.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&ts=5.1.6#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN7IB4C5kDOYUoA5sgL4BQoksiKAQpsgJ74gCuAtgEbSUa4aPCTIAwiwBe+XgHs5AGwhwQgoXVEoAogDcI4ALJwADpirJLyOPlQBuC1d75GDq8gT5xD6lQAmEAiKcFAoMJwgCGDAcmrhkQA8ACrIENiQIH4EyAAUANYQrHIwyHoGYMYmAJQA2gC6AHw5IaT4GI6WwJDcBPg1AHSDWDUAksigyAVFJUl1bR3uqfrg+EmjdQA0C+4IcIqKvIh5+Dl+cGA2pcsVpjVrI3V1VcgAvA3IunLAfgsUlHVUChVfCfb4OKjxBA5druLoQHp9bZWGGLVEQa74ADkcExW1RqN2+0OCGOuTOF2eb3M+JpyAA9HTFgA9AD8ORMITg3AgdGe5MuqCRqIoePxIqF1NplnR5SxvFxEp2ewORxO-Mp7xRUvcDOZbI5UC5POgfPOl0Yiqs4pp1vxWtpMpWyExCAV2o8yuJpNOZo1kvdll17lZ7M53N5yH5XktlltwtFlk2gKqDl1kOisWQkISNQARHBcxtkLneIXiwhc40coB7omBHy+fjsQA)