# How to enforce a property of an object, in an array of objects, to have a non empty string value?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, conditional-types

Consider the following code

```js
type EnforceNonEmptyValue<TValueArg extends string> = {
  value: TValueArg extends '' ? never : TValueArg
  type: 'substringMatch'
}

function identity<
  TValueArg extends string
>(
  object: EnforceNonEmptyValue<TValueArg>
) {
  return object
}

// rightfully complaints
identity({value: '', type: 'substringMatch'})
//---------^
//  `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2322)`

// works
identity({value: 'works', type: 'substringMatch'})
```

The function `identity` with the help of `EnforceNonEmptyValue` generic enforces that the object passed to the function has a non empty string value, i.e. the value of `value` property should not be an empty string `''`

I want to extend this check for an array of objects

```js
identityArray([
  {
    type: 'substringMatch',
    value: 'np-payment',
  },
  {
    type: 'substringMatch',
    value: '',
    //------^ should complain here
  },
])
```

i.e I want typescript to throw an error if any object in an array of objects has a `value` property's value as an empty string `''`

But I've been having a hard time to make it work. How could we enforce it for an array of objects? ( with or without an identity function )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [mapped array/tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) as shown here:

```
function identityArray<T extends string[]>(
  args: [...{ [I in keyof T]: EnforceNonEmptyValue<T[I]> }]
) { }
```

The compiler can infer the type `T` from the homomorphic mapped type (see [What does "homomorphic mapped type" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59790508/2887218)) `{[I in keyof T]: EnforceNonEmptyValue<T[I]>}`.  I wrapped it with a [variadic tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) (`[...`+`]`) to give the compiler a hint that we'd like `T` to be inferred as a [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) and not as an unordered array type, but you might not care either way.

Anyway, let's test it:

```
identityArray([
  {
    type: 'substringMatch',
    value: 'np-payment',
  },
  {
    type: 'substringMatch',
    value: '', // error!
  },
])
// function identityArray<["np-payment", ""]>(
//   args: [EnforceNonEmptyValue<"np-payment">, EnforceNonEmptyValue<"">]
// ): void
```

Looks good.  The compiler accepts `"np-payment"` and rejects `""`.  You can see that `T` is inferred as the tuple type `["np-payment", ""]` and the `args` argument is of the mapped tuple type `[EnforceNonEmptyValue<"np-payment">, EnforceNonEmptyValue<"">]`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKALgngDgpgBAUQHYDMD2AnAxjAcmpBAWykgDUBDAGwFcYAeAFUtpgEEMBzOGADzBhIAJgGc4IsBgCWSTgD44AXjgBvUHDgA3anQBccZjvZce-QaLgByS3AD8cJDE0wMcfYdYdO6uJFj7LERoAIwlpWQBZCjAsAAtLUABfUFAUGiQsMCkCOCkhQSzIeh8POi9TAWExMJlvEDkACh80YIArGEz9ZHRsPAJiUggWOiZh43lQAEpVHwwYMBoMJDgW9syklJAAei24aU5YsDSqKgg4LDQSKgoZMBFQPIKpSAaVLSMAywAaX2gYAKCoUktSiMXicESk1AOwAtHD4fCAHrQ3ZwAAGjD+VhqshsUjESDQYDgFBEIiknCQFGCVHgYDQv1gVkczgwlgAdHcGgAmADM3O5kzRmx2cAA7pgANb3ECPJCFCCvd6sAISjDS76M-7YkI4ziguI2SGbVLpTLZZZyhUcDAUCBMCrmarA2QAbQAuo0fBQuCJ9K72YG3q6AJK5ZaSmAQNAoAzurqoTA4fCEEjkIxMUOeiHuqaqCGbK3PCA2u0NV0+NQgDQaPzawK6l366KGr4+DTaFXMqAwqB2ogFb4+RJt6szMe1v4AxvhZtgocT5V6Kya0UuDCYACEw9H7qh212aQyWRyRcgpftroAREge32IAP5Vefler56mgeaz7OH64K7ukmfSpoMYz0Ded79gUV5yD8AG9CmAzpqwYHQbmn6TPomhoHkoBAA)

Comment: Thank you! Understood it completely.