# Recursive mapped type without conditional

Tags: typescript

This generic type is equivalent to just using its type parameter:

```js
// Equivalent to T
type NoOp<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: NoOp<T[P]>;
};

// usage:
type ObjType = { a: string, b: { c: number, d: boolean} };
type NoOpObj = NoOp<ObjType>; // equivalent to ObjType
type NoOpString = NoOp<string>; // string
```

Why does this work? It appears to be using unconditional recursion, which I'd naively expect to be result in some kind of error no matter what its type parameter is.

Also it's unintuitive that it can be used on a primitive type like `string`. I guess `keyof string` isn't meaningless; it has methods like `concat` and `slice`, etc. But how does TypeScript determine that `NoOp<string>` is literally just `string`?

I suspect the answer to the first question is something like "type checking is lazy", and the second is implemented as some kind of special case, but I'd like a deeper understanding of what's going on here.

Comment: "Homomorphic" mapped types over primitives are basically ignored.

Comment: [What is "homomorphic" and what does it mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59790508/what-does-homomorphic-mapped-type-mean)

Comment: Break the homomorphic mapped type: https://tsplay.dev/Wklb0w

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript supports recursive object types where the property values refer to the type being defined:

```
interface Foo { x: Foo } // <-- fine
```

Indeed, "type checking is lazy" when it comes to object property types.

---

*Homomorphic* [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) (see [What does "homomorphic mapped type" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59790508/2887218), usually involving `in keyof`), as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#12447](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/12447). As mentioned in the pull request, homomorphic mapped types automatically "skip" primitives:

> A mapped type of the form `{ [P in keyof T]: X }`, where `T` is some type parameter is said to be a [homo]morphic mapped type ... When a primitive type is substituted for `T` in an [homo]morphic mapped type, we simply produce that primitive type. For example, when `{ [P in keyof T]: X }` is instantiated with `A | undefined` for `T`, we produce `{ [P in keyof A]: X } | undefined`.

So `NoOp<string>` will be `string`.  This feature was introduced before [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html), so before you could make the type anything you wanted, "leave primitive types alone" was probably a better default behavior than "recursively map forever, even down into crazy things like the `length` of a string".

Comment: Cool! Do you know if this is mentioned anywhere in the main TypeScript docs? It seems important.

Comment: No, it's not at https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/ .  Maybe it should be added.  Unfortunately the language evolves at a rate faster than the TS team can keep up with documentation, and they've essentially completely given up the idea of having a language spec.  At this point when people ask they say that the GitHub issues are considered part of the documentation. ‍♂️