# Way to implement `Required` with `Exclude` instead of `-?`

Tags: typescript

We know that currently TypeScript's built-in `Required` utility type is implemented by "removing the optional tag" using `-?` like

```js
type Required<T> = { [K in keyof T]-?: T[K] }
```

My question is that since an optional property is actually (maybe) created like `| undefined` e.g.

```js
interface Foo {
  name?: string
}
```

where `typeof Foo['name']` is `string | undefined`, it's natural that we can `Exclude` the `undefined` to implement `Required` like

```js
type MyRequired<T> = { [K in keyof T]: Exclude<T[K], undefined> }
```

However, actually this idea doesn't work. The output type is the same as `T` without any modification. Why doesn't it work?

Comment: So, are you looking for OmitOptional , ExcludeValueUndefined, or exactOptionalPropertyTypes in tsconfig (which removes implied undefined from optional props)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a property is [optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#optional-properties) then the compiler automatically adds `undefined` to its domain (unless [`--exactOptionalPropertyTypes`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#exact-optional-property-types---exactoptionalpropertytypes) is enabled). That is, allowing `undefined` is one of the *effects* of making a property optional.

But the direction of causality doesn't go the other way.  Adding `undefined` to a property doesn't make it optional, and removing (or trying to remove) `undefined` from a property doesn't make it required.  So your approach doesn't work because you're trying to do it backwards.

A [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) of the form `{[K in keyof T]: ⋯}` is *homomorphic* (see [What does "homomorphic mapped type" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59790508/2887218)) and automatically copies the "optionality" and "[`readonly`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#readonly-properties)-ness" from the input type `T` to the output type.  So if a property of `T` is optional, then the corresponding property of `{[K in keyof T]: ⋯}` will also be optional.  And removing `undefined` from the output property will have no effect, because it will be added right back by the compiler.

If you want to prevent a homomorphic mapped type from preserving optionality, you can use the `-?` [mapping modifier](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#mapping-modifiers) to make all output properties required and it will also remove `undefined` from the domain of the output property.  You can also just prevent the mapped type from being recognized as homomorphic, if you want to make the property required but keep `undefined` (see [this comment on microsoft/TypeScript#31025](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31025#issuecomment-484734942)).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose `type A = {x?: undefined | 1}`
That includes all these instances

```
{}
{x:undefined}
{x:1}
```

Suppose `type B = {x: undefined | 1}`
That includes only these instances

```
{x:undefined}
{x:1}
```

Instances of `MyRequired(A)`:

```
{}
{x:1}
```

which can be written as

```
type MyReqA = {x?:1}
```

Instances of `MyRequired(B)`:

```
{x:1}
```

which can be written as

```
type MyReqB = {x:1}
```

So MyRequired doesn't work for A, but it does for B. As expected.

---

Background that may or may not be useful:
In real life JS, a property key can have a value of `undefined`.

```
a = {x: undefined}
```

or have the key not present

```
b = {}
```

and both return the same value trying to read the key:

```
a.x; // undefined
b.x; // undefined
```