# Why do similar-looking codes yield different errors in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

```
type Convert<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends string ? number : T[P]
}

function test<T>(target: T): Convert<T> {
  return target as any
}

interface Bar {
  a: number
  b: (_: any) => void
}

const bar: Bar = test({
  a: '', // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
  b: v => {}
})

const bar2 = test({
  a: '',
  b: v => {} // Parmeter 'v' implicitly has an 'any' type.
})

const bar3: Bar = test({
  a: '',
  b: (v: any) => {}
})
```

[image: screenshot of code and errors]

When I modify the `test` function as follows, the `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'` error disappears, leaving only `any` related errors. But why?

```
function test<T, R extends Convert<T>>(target: T): R {
  return target as any
}
```

Comment: @jcalz Thank you very much for your response! Your answer highlighted the differences in type inference between the two versions, which was very enlightening for me. I have a follow-up question regarding the first version. I'm curious about why bar and bar3 exhibit different behavior in the type system (the former throws an error, while the latter doesn't). I hope you can help clarify this for me. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given

```
type Convert<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends string ? number : T[P]
}

function test<T>(target: T): Convert<T> {
  return target as any
}

const bar: Bar = test({
  a: '', // error!
  b: v => { }
})
```

the type checker *cannot* use the argument to `test` to infer the [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter `T`.   That's because the `b` property is a *context-sensitive* function.  The `v` callback parameter is [not annotated](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#parameter-type-annotations) with a type, so the compiler needs to [contextually infer](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) it. But it *defers* such inference until after `T` is inferred, since it expects it needs to do that first.

Therefore the type checker falls back to a lower-priority inference site: the *return* type of the function.  The compiler *can* contextually infer `T` from the expected return type of `Bar`. This behavior, inferring generic function type parameters from the contextual type of its return, was implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#16072](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/16072) and [released in TypeScript 2.4](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-4.html#return-types-as-inference-targets).

Because `Convert<T>` is a *homomorphic mapped type* (see [What does "homomorphic mapped type" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59790508/2887218) ), the compiler infers `T` from `Bar` by essentially first guessing that `T` *is* `Bar`, and then checking it.  This check succeeds for the expected return type (since `Convert<Bar>` is equivalent to `Bar`), but *fails* for the argument passed in as `target`.  That's why you get an error.

---

On the other hand, given

```
function test<T, R extends Convert<T>>(target: T): R {
  return target as any
}

const bar: Bar = test({
  a: '', // okay
  b: v => { } // error depending on --noImplicitAny
})
```

the introduction of a second type parameter `R` breaks the inference connection between `R` and `T`.  Here `R` is still contextually typed from `Bar`, but `T` can now only be inferred from the value passed in as `target`.  The [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) `R extends Convert<T>` does not serve as an inference site for `T`.  There was an old feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#7234](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7234) that would have supported such inference, but this was never implemented.  So `T` doesn't influence the type inferred for `R`.  After `T` and `R` are inferred, then `R` is *checked* against the constraint `Convert<T>`, but that doesn't change the type being inferred.

This behavior is sometimes used intentionally to block inference; there is an open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#14829](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829) asking for a way to prevent the use of a type parameter from being used as a generic type argument inference site.  There's no native support for this, but one of the workarounds is to add an extra type parameter, as mentioned [in this comment on ms/TS#14829](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829#issuecomment-288902999).

Anyway, since `T` can now *only* be inferred from the function argument, it is... and `R` is inferred only from `Bar`, and since `Bar` is compatible with `Convert<T>`, the call succeeds; the error on `a` goes away because there is no sense in which the compiler expects `a` to be of type `number`.

You may or may not get an error on the callback parameter `v`, since now there is no context at all for `v`'s type, and the compiler will implicitly give it an `any` type.  If you have [the `--noImplicitAny` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#noImplicitAny) enabled, that will be an error.  Of course if you go and annotate `v` as `any`, now the original problem above does not surface, because `T` can be inferred from the argument without needing to defer anything.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.2.2#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUEkqJLAsgGoQBOUAlgPbACMehRSALgJ4zIDCTAG41OAHgAqAPiQBeNhw4BtAApI6wJAGsI3BgDMkEgLoAuI6uNIIAD04RgAEyhIonahoDmSAPzEArmAARjRI5hKW7EQAvvhRSPr+wPCcjJr2bpJSABScINSeEJzhAJTmgsAi1OLSCopI1EX+1On5hZxIIC4gwNzxsfEa9tT65EgAQvl1iiDmwIEh1PFEQebZAPrmPdwlcjJCDHSO-XGK8ExuSEH55pPUclzQnNkE9Z3mAOQfADTLV+ZCPZ4JCxRTREqnEGQkjQOCIJBUWhpABM0y4vAEwlEWQer3qqnUmh0ekMJnClmsdgczlc7i8vgCwVC5JUxhO8USyVSTEemQk3yQACVKfYnC4KlUalIcnkCkVSuZhXjFI1OM1WnKOl1Or0ToohjRRvC7miiLNGYs-qskBstr1drJ9odjmDIURzsBLtdqLcpvIMs9lRxzV8BQB6MNIBhaEB9N7WwGO4GgjjguLsAbRIA)