# How to properly type a table of tuples to array of objects utility function (like zip) avoiding merged union of all values in typescript 5.2.2

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, typing, keyof

I'm close to nailing it, but can't find a way around the final `TS2322: Type  TcolTuple[i]  is not assignable to type  string | number | symbol` compiler error.

So, here is a utility function `rowsToObjects()` that quite a few people probably defined in their projects once or twice, it's somewhat similar to [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) in concept:

```js
const objects = rowsToObjects(
    ['id', 'color' , 'shape'   , 'size'  , 'to' ] as const,  
    [  1n, 'red'   , 'circle'  , 'big'   , '0x0'] as const,
    [  2n, 'green' , 'square'  , 'small' , '0x0'] as const,
    [  3n, 'blue'  , 'triangle', 'small' , '0x0'] as const,
)
```

That outputs:

```js
[
    {id: 1n, color: 'red', shape: 'circle', size: 'big', to: '0x0'},
    {id: 2n, color: 'green', shape: 'square', size: 'small', to: '0x0'},
    {id: 3n, color: 'blue', shape: 'triangle', size: 'small', to: '0x0'},
]
```

The actual implementation is obviously trivial, but typing it gives me some hard time:

```js
export function rowsToObjects<
    Tobj extends { [i in keyof TcolTuple as TcolTuple[i]]: TvalTuple[i] },
    TcolTuple extends readonly string[],
    TvalTuple extends { [j in keyof TcolTuple]: unknown }
>(cols: TcolTuple, ...rows: TvalTuple[]): Tobj[];
```

Current code seems logical to me, but the compiler complains about the `as TcolTuple[i]` part:

```
TS2322: Type  TcolTuple[i]  is not assignable to type  string | number | symbol 
  Type  TcolTuple[keyof TcolTuple]  is not assignable to type  string | number | symbol 
    Type
    TcolTuple[string] | TcolTuple[number] | TcolTuple[symbol]
    is not assignable to type  string | number | symbol 
      Type  TcolTuple[string]  is not assignable to type  string | number | symbol
```

Am I missing something obvious here? The typing is close to satisfactory, but without that `as TcolTuple[i]` it does not recognize which value belongs to which key and just unions them all.

[image]

Comment: I would approach it [this way](https://tsplay.dev/wEYrVw). Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Please do! It does seem to do the trick <3

Comment: Though I would change `Record<keyof K, any>` to `Record<keyof K, unknown>` to make it clear that it's type safe.

Comment: Sure, if you change `i` and `j` to `I` and `J` and remove the default type arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main problem you're having with

```
{ [I in keyof TcolTuple as TcolTuple[I]]: TvalTuple[I] }
```

is that using [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) prevents the mapped type from being *homomorphic* (see [What does "homomorphic mapped type" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59790508/2887218)), so instead of [mapping over just the numeric-like indices of the tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) like `"0" | "1" | "2"`, you're mapping over *all* the indices, including `number`, a mixture of all the elements.  And that gives you the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) you're unhappy with.

The easiest change here is to explicitly map over only the numeric-like indices, by [intersecting](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) `keyof TcolTuple` with the *pattern* [template literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types) `` `${number}` `` (as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#40598](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40598). That removes anything that isn't a string version of a number.  For example, `"0" | "1" | "2" | number | "length" | "find"` when intersected with `` `${number}` ``, gives you just `"0" | "1" | "2"`.

That more or less fixes it:

```
declare function rowsToObjects<
  Tobj extends { [I in `${number}` & keyof TcolTuple as TcolTuple[I]]: TvalTuple[I] },
  TcolTuple extends readonly string[],
  TvalTuple extends { [J in keyof TcolTuple]: unknown }
>(cols: TcolTuple, ...rows: TvalTuple[]): Tobj[];

const objects = rowsToObjects(
  ['id', 'color', 'shape', 'size', 'to'] as const,
  [1n, 'red', 'circle', 'big', '0x0'] as const,
  [2n, 'green', 'square', 'small', '0x0'] as const,
  [3n, 'blue', 'triangle', 'small', '0x0'] as const,
)
/* const objects: {
    id: 1n | 2n | 3n;
    color: "red" | "green" | "blue";
    shape: "circle" | "square" | "triangle";
    size: "big" | "small";
    to: "0x0";
}[] */
```

---

Personally, if I were writing this for myself, I would:

- use [`const` type parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-5-0.html#const-type-parameters) instead of requiring callers use [`const` assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions);
- maintain the tuple-type of the inputs so that if the input array is strongly ordered then so is the output (e.g., `rowsToObjects(["a"],[0],[1])` should return `[{a: 0}, {a: 1}]` and not `{a: 0 | 1}[]`;
- remove the extra [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameters and just compute the output inline instead of relying on [default type arguments](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults);
- use uppercase letters for mapped type parameters like `I` and `J` instead of `i` and `j`, keeping to the naming convention to distinguish types from variables (in `{[P in K]: F<P>}` `P` is a type parameter, not a variable name, so `p` could be confusing).

None of these are of vital importance, but it gives the output

```
declare function rowsToObjects<
  const K extends readonly PropertyKey[],
  const V extends readonly Record<keyof K, unknown>[]
>(
  cols: K, ...rows: V
): { [I in keyof V]:
    { [J in `${number}` & keyof K as K[J]]:
      V[I][J]
    }
  };

const objects = rowsToObjects(
  ['id', 'color', 'shape', 'size', 'to'],
  [1n, 'red', 'circle', 'big', '0x0'],
  [2n, 'green', 'square', 'small', '0x0'],
  [3n, 'blue', 'triangle', 'small', '0x0'],
)
/* const objects: readonly [{
    id: 1n;
    color: "red";
    shape: "circle";
    size: "big";
    to: "0x0";
}, {
    id: 2n;
    color: "green";
    shape: "square";
    size: "small";
    to: "0x0";
}, {
    id: 3n;
    color: "blue";
    shape: "triangle";
    size: "small";
    to: "0x0";
}] */
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9#code/FAOwhgtgpgzgDmAxlABATQPYFcBOMUDewKKAJlIgDZg6oBmWIiALgJYYgo4YDuMAKhgDyAIwBWFZjAA8xEikHiUUAB7MoIUvgIoA2gEkUrTgAMAJARBYIIqDgC+JlADIUAaygBPDHQWIMlPxYcJSoYPj8-oHBoQYAunEAXAoAbmDRIVDxKPYANHIkkQFBmcpqGlpcUGCkHJSeKDDMOMYA5rpx+fKp6SWhZeqa2noAUkacHt6+RRmhSSiMbiC8nPZyAHwAFFEwyTN9ULkoAHSn3Hx7abNZcQCUexjiHQDcwHL+IE0ojxIs+AC8XF4AmE4kkME2BT0AHJWKRoUdoVEMDgEShoTAABZgOBQNEY1gALzxiOYGGhcRQ4RQHyaXXkugAjCBEbR4YjEKwcFQSeiRKxWviAAwqIUUqn4WnMekkXQAJhZ6NatA0+JgAEcsDReRiIOlKMLReLqVKZXoAMyK6EiShYHXNVhgECtUJqvWUA2IkViykmjh0uS3OQAegAVDT-cxvmC-skiN0SHDksyUAAfFAKtMoS2vBMRygo5IAIjZRazReVUA0ZfTRZtdqLuYTWJxUGLnO5oRrKCLGq1tG7RYdTpdUEbUJIMCJbZ7-Nag5g7so47zZOL3pXOQ6KFDwbea1AkFgCGQKAAssZUPGyBRqLQUAwmGwOEC+IJRL8pLJulKUABpAYKnwWgajqBoAAVuFxHBmE8P8vA6M1fwANUAoYqlAkB6hQAAlCgUVIaRJh8f8jkWZYeBAdYOg2SEfwCXZSJOM5gWSZDAzjPRDGMdwvBI5CkgnQhRnGFBzEsaxbAcJxXGI3wAOpP9dBGBJEiEkhkPiZS4iEtZunsV43hIX8fnBFBAXOEEP3BOiGVhdl0WRVFERbXE1WnfEyQpM0mStNl8Q7Hl8TnQ0fR8hVEUrVUXM1bU3X1ULvKhXRLURet7RaEdXRcpdEs6QMQ3DEyYykZIQNqLCGl0a9uiTFBmSbeiCxwYtS0a+RXJnItAq7drJ2nYs503bo1x7DcmzyQghLqhU+vzQseyikBho67FcWLPttRW-riQ2pdtpQUai3GuRJpq+Q6pzISnMG20xzmzri2HZ1eqEqddp7Rd9QOo6TpIexKV3N5gHsIA)