# Variadic zip over iterables in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, types, generator, variadic

I'm trying to write a variadic zip over iterables while also preserving type. For example,

```js
function* naturals(max=10) { for (let i=0; i<max; i++) yield i }
const x = [1, 2, 3]
const y = ["a", "b", "c"]

const zipped = zip(naturals(), x, y)
console.log([...zipped]) // => [[0, 1, "a"], [1, 2, "b"], [2, 3, "c"]]

function* zip<?>(...iterables:?[]) {
   const iterators = iterables.map(iter => iter[Symbol.iterator]())
   ...
}
```

Is there a type signature which helps preserve my types?

Comment: ① `naturals` isn't iterable, it's a function that produces an iterable.  Do you mean `zip(naturals(), x, y)` or something? ② Exactly what *type* do you expect out of your example?  Is [the code in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mZyLEN) sufficient?  If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: This is exactly it! Brilliant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could give `zip()` the following call signature:

```
declare function zip<T extends any[]>(
  ...iterables: { [I in keyof T]: Iterable<T[I]> }
): Iterable<T>;
```

It is [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the type parameter `T` representing the type of the arrays in each element of the output (i.e., the function returns `Iterable<T>`).  This is expected to be a [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types).

The input type is a [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) of a mapped type over the array/tuple type `T`, where each element of `T` is wrapped in `Iterable`.  This mapped type is *homomorphic* (featuring `in keyof T`, see [What does "homomorphic mapped type" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59790508/2887218) for more info) and so TypeScript can infer `T` from it.

Let's try it on your example:

```
const zipped = zip(naturals(), x, y)
// const zipped: Iterable<[number, number, string]>
```

Here `iterables` is of a tuple type assignable to `[Iterable<number>, Iterable<number>, Iterable<string>]`, and so the compiler infers `T` as `[number, number, string]`.  So the output type is `Iterable<[number, number, string]>` as expected.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.3.2#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mAVAAjAQyiATmgNgZwAoBbNAD2QF5kBGABgEpkBvZYOLZQ3AUymRhVkdANwDkAHmSkyYmAGp5TAJ4weuACbiAvgFgAUBAT5+FagG0aAGmQAmGwGYAugaNgTyZUPMAiND5sfACMA5B8IHxd9DR4IXDQsHjZwaHgwZAAvGAAHCQAVZB4yKB4wDXxkNDBlcycAPkIAOmaYEpwg3nwALhZkcwBJAXSAax5lOGBkPKce-ra0Dp58gfrkbQZZ+cX8upFXY34s7OyeLWojwnRMHAJCBhsyG2UGAwB6V+RP5AA9AH4DIA)