# Typescript: extract and process keys of specific type from object

Tags: typescript

I have an object type with keys whose corresponding values are either of number type, string  type, optional number type or optional string type :

```
interface MyObject {
  mandatoryNumber: number;
  optionalNumber?: number;
  mandatoryString: string;
  optionalString?: string;
}
```

How can I write a function that takes an instance of this object as parameter as well as a key, restricting only keys of type number or optional number, and that returns either twice the value if the value is defined or 0 otherwise ?

I tried the following:

```
type NumberKeys<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends number ? K : never
}[keyof T];

function process<K extends NumberKeys<MyObject>>(obj: MyObject, key: K): number {
    const value = obj[key]; // -> Typescript error: Type 'K' cannot be used to index type 'MyObject'
    return value !== undefined ? value * 2 : 0;
}
```

But I am getting an Typescript error: Type 'K' cannot be used to index type 'MyObject'.

Comment: I think it's just that your `NumberKeys<T>` type is preserving the optionality in a way you don't want; you can use `-?` [as shown here](https://tsplay.dev/N5j7Vm) and it fixes it.  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: I guess that should work!

Comment: Okay I'll write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that your definition of `NumberKeys<T>` uses a *homomorphic* [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) (see [What does "homomorphic mapped type" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59790508/2887218)) which, among other things, preserves whether a property is [optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#optional-properties) or not.  So if `T` has even one optional property, then the mapped type will include `undefined` in its properties, and this `undefined` will make it all the way into the result:

```
type Ex = NumberKeys<{ a: number, b?: string }>;
// type Ex = "a" | undefined
```

That `undefined` messes things up and the compiler complains that `K` can't index `MyObject` because `K` can be `undefined`.  So the big fix we need to make is to suppress `undefined`. One way to do this is to use [the mapping modifier](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#mapping-modifiers) `-?` to make all properties in the result required:

```
type NumberKeys<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]-?: T[K] extends number ? K : never
}[keyof T];

type Ex = NumberKeys<{ a: number, b?: string }>;
// type Ex = "a"
```

That's good, and it resolves the error you had:

```
function process<K extends NumberKeys<MyObject>>(obj: MyObject, key: K): number {
  const value = obj[key]; // okay
  return value !== undefined ? value * 2 : 0;
}
```

---

Unfortunately you're still not quite getting the behavior you want:

```
type NKMO = NumberKeys<MyObject>;
// type NKMO = "mandatoryNumber"
```

The `undefined` is gone, but `optionalNumber` isn't present. That's because the mapping modifier `-?` seems to remove `undefined` only from the result of the mapping, not from the original property.  This is considered a bug in TypeScript, as reported in [microsoft/TypeScript#31025](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31025), but it's such a longstanding bug that I expect it will never be fixed. I imagine lots of real world code would break if they fixed it.

Anyway that means `optionalNumber`'s property is still treated like `number | undefined` even with `-?`, and since `number | undefined` does not extend `number`, the key is not selected with your code.  The easiest way to fix that is to just check for `number | undefined` instead of `number`:

```
type NumberKeys<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]-?: T[K] extends number | undefined ? K : never
}[keyof T];

type NKMO = NumberKeys<MyObject>;
// type NKMO = "mandatoryNumber" | "optionalNumber"
```

Which works.

---

Or, you could just sidestep the issue by operating on `Required<MyObject>` instead of `MyObject`, using [the `Required` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#requiredtype) (which is implemented via `-?`, of course):

```
type NKMO = NumberKeys<Required<MyObject>>;
// type NKMO = "mandatoryNumber" | "optionalNumber"

function process<K extends NumberKeys<Required<MyObject>>>(
  obj: MyObject, key: K): number {
  const value = obj[key]; // okay
  return value !== undefined ? value * 2 : 0;
}
```

This is quite similar to the other approach; both deal with optional properties introducing `undefined`, it's just doing it in slightly different ways.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8DyAjAVhBMZAbwChlkBbOEAEzjAHsp0A5AV0u2gC5kRO3KAG5yyRgAcwwRiDgAbDl2gB+PgOUix1Og2boAymCigA5nwDOxs6IqTpshUZMhTa5FZenRAX1L-SOUoICwlEFEwTUxIxMHQJFCUhAGkIdAsAHgAVAD5kAF4YigoAbWTkUGQAazTGGGQsgF0+LLLG5AgAD0g6C35BaGQVZHL1CAA3aDEfEpr0OobG0Vj4lABRToLkJOhU9IziZDh1AagAGmRsd08zZB8c22QAeifkOITkDa2AIjhv5AAPsh2HQIDBQBBaP4KO9EslUJgtjsoHtMhgcPhCA8xC83qttvDEYVvjp6EwWMj-kCQbQwRCoWIYCDCDIQMgJFBGEgLJlyl0erQ+sjURl0XgCGAcjkABSMPB8MWYsAXOZ8ZIAShOmiKxQQsisyHGCnYKEKctwszSS2er2gnKgYgoUAgYHYUDZRvkJuQAEJ8oUaXSQJChobjSgAFTIABMyD4AAZHn4-IE4MFQuFkAAFOBQaQKABiwE2ZBh+OFaUyuS2peKZQqbLmCyaAFp3K1ku1+RBev1tcNRvwJlMKDMm-Umssyx8voUK-tDsc+0ILldLNZXHdsRRcbDPptiX9oXiPqxCUjTiLFRLtzaT3CET9SXoKadvgEKEyQCzZOzOdzeQ6boe0FbZL0rUUsHFLEZXNBUoKVFU0jVTVl0GWsKD1EADU9b0zTwS10GtXFGCqOB0EdZBnVdd0wy9FA-QDUFwWDWhQ1wyMYzjZBE2mUgUyCEIwiQZAC3YeR5CLEsVlPcD9mrQoMOQetKnHRY2xaNogIFPoNCEQFgWY+lQ0HYNJgdUdCObJZjz3M9HznOS0QQm9Hl3ctz2JZ9yTYN8DO+exWQUSlGWZBw2Q5LkQkA7te3nZyMRvWD5TQFzCCQ9AUK1fSlKwnDwy2c1COI15SPIyjqLdD0CsYwzaRYkNhg45Ao1jBMk34-xBIzETIgAEUYLIAAtgD6Ws7Kc7I8kUyiVMbWoJ2aBotNi0C9MGAduLMkc7isxblhkh8iTAzQRQAJQgABHdhgGdWhIMSmC3NeOzPOQEkaDJfRKX8wLHEUN9jy-H8Iv-aKMj5YC4smi7rtuyEHugyUpWlSi4NSx7lWqZCRlQ9aoB1TD9SIZr8ItOYSvEMiKOKKiXSqujvVqwMGrYpqCta7jeNHfigA)