# Guard function call so that deeply nested objects have a key that must match the type of a sibling property function cargument

Tags: typescript

Given the function and example arguments when calling createParser, I want defaultValue to be the value type argument in the parse function and only for that key in the configuration object.

I've tried various methods, inferring, etc, but I can't seem to pin the type to the exact key in the config.

```js
type Parser<T> = (value: T) => any;

interface ParserOptions<TParser extends Parser<unknown>> {
  parse: TParser;
  defaultValue?: Parameters<TParser>[0];
}

function createParser<
  TValue,
  TParser extends Parser<TValue>,
  TParserOptions extends ParserOptions<TParser>,
  TParsers extends Record<string, TParserOptions>,
  TConfig extends {
    [K in keyof TParsers]: TParsers[K];
  },
>(fields: TConfig) {
  return fields;
}

createParser({
  right_string: {
    defaultValue: 'adf',
    parse(value: string) {
      return value;
    },
  },
  right_number: {
    defaultValue: 1,
    parse(value: number) {
      return value;
    },
  },
  wrong: {
    defaultValue: new Date(),
    parse(value: string) {
      return value;
    },
  },
});
```

How can I guard this function call to not allow the "wrong" key as an example.

Comment: There are too many generic type parameters in your function. Does [this version](https://tsplay.dev/mb1D8N) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz no, I’ve tried many different variations and can only get close but can’t pin it down. So this was a copy paste of my last state.

Comment: I'm sorry, did you look at [the link in that comment](https://tsplay.dev/mb1D8N)?  I'm trying to show you a TypeScript Playground link that shows my efforts in solving the problem.

Comment: @jcalz oh sorry just saw the link. I’ll check it out in a few and get back.  If that’s the solution then I got lost in the sauce for a while.  Granted my implementation is this but nested deeper into other factories and logic.

Comment: @jcalz That 100% solves it.  I have no clue how I ended up here then in the first place as this solution seems like one I'd do naturally.

I'll plug this into the library I'm working on.  Thanks so much.

I added a NotEmpty type around the argument to not allow {}.

Comment: Okay I'll write up an answer when I get a chance.

Comment: @jcalz I think the spot that was tripping me up is that I simplified my question to the barebones.  I want to infer a few more things.

```typescript
interface ParserOptions<In, Out> {
  parse(value: In): Out;
  defaultValue?: In;
}
```

So I want to also be able to infer the output of the parse function and this I think is what was tripping me up.

Comment: Wait, are you expanding the scope of the question now or just giving some more context about why you were having a problem? I hope it's not the former (since that was why I asked if my approach met your needs and I would have waited to start writing an answer if I thought the answer was no)

Comment: @jcalz unfortunately it's a slight scope change, but I can leave the question untouched as your answer did solve this issue directly.

Comment: So I'll write up an answer and if you can't figure out the next step you'll open a new one, I guess?

Comment: @jcalz yes, sounds good.  As I think both versions may be useful to searchers.

I think it may get a little more weird with my original intention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the example as written, I would approach it this way, with only a single type parameter:

```
interface ParserOptions<T> {
  parse: Parser<T>;
  defaultValue?: T;
}

function createParser<T extends object>(fields: {
  [K in keyof T]: ParserOptions<T[K]>
}) {
  return fields;
}
```

Now `T` in `createParser()` corresponds to an object whose property types are the type argument to `Parser`.  So when you call:

```
createParser({
  right_string: {
    defaultValue: 'adf',
    parse(value: string) {
      return value;
    },
  },
  right_number: {
    defaultValue: 1,
    parse(value: number) {
      return value;
    },
  },
  wrong: {
    defaultValue: new Date(),
    parse(value: string) { // error
      // Type 'Date' is not assignable to type 'string'.
      return value;
    },
  },
});
```

the compiler infers `T` as `{ right_string: string; right_number: number; wrong: Date; }` and complains that the `parse()` method on the `wrong` property is in error, as desired.

This works because `fields`'s type is a homomorphic [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) (see [What does "homomorphic mapped type" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59790508/2887218)) over the keys of `T`, and TypeScript can often infer from such mapped types.

But beware, it is more of an art than a science to write [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) functions so that inference does what you want it to do.  Sometimes a slight change in the stated goals will require a large change in the generic call signature. Even worse, sometimes a slight change will make the problem unsolvable and then you have to either give up or refactor to use some other data structure. Given that the version in your question had lots of extra type parameters that presumably had some purpose, it's not clear that adding them back in will work to achieve that purpose.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.3.2#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgJwM4QQHgCoD4oF4oAUAbnADYCuEAXFBgJR45wB2IA3AFAcCWzwqAMzgBjaPGSoA8mGDcA9sySYcAbw5QoYRChriU6bJw0ATCEPKlgANTKUA-DQycAvlwHlmw2QqjCEEOH49VEwoCAAPfmZjJCg5ACMAKwgvLAIBbghSGJo1DQBtAGkoXigAawgQOQFaAF1dbSkZeUVMItqsDmcGPKh-YHIEZigMrJiXLj8AoMaEAl6EbgBzAAtgAH0kYEXmJdz1DShTc0sbCmooAHI4YwFLgBoDjS0JYlsLrZ2lnqfD-sHhiRzkZDs5HhowQdFqsNsxyABbeKofaHI5mOAWazvGgARnBhxeKDe5xocMRqB+qI0-yGUCBlBBEPxkI0AHcEAo9lBeiZ0ZizpRSRBWVAACKBCAEOj456NYmCqCfXjfbm-akQAa0+kQRlQFl6x7dNhQIA)

Comment: Thanks for this and the explanation.  I can't believe I was over-thinking this exact problem so much, lol.

Comment: As mentioned prior, I have a slight different criteria now and think I need to get more into complex generics:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77776886/configuration-object-type-inference-based-on-property-function-arguments-and-ret