# Configuration object type inference based on property function arguments and return values

Tags: typescript

I recently asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) (thanks [jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887218/jcalz)) but criteria changed and things get a bit more complicating I think.

I've attempted various methods at achieving this, so I'll just post a snippet of my cleanest attempt.

```js
type ParserFunction<In, Out> = (value: In) => Out;

interface Parser<In, Out> {
  parse: ParserFunction<In, Out>;
  defaultValue?: In;
  defaultValueOut?: Out;
}

function createParser<
  TParser extends Parser<any, any>,
  TFields extends Record<string, TParser>
>(options: {
  [K in keyof TFields]: TFields[K] extends Parser<infer I, infer O> ? Parser<I, O> : never
}) {
  return void 0;
}

createParser({
  pass: {
    defaultValue: '100',
    defaultValueOut: 100,
    parse(value: string) {
      return Number(value)
    }
  },
  fail: {
    defaultValue: '100', // this should be a number
    defaultValueOut: 100, // this should be a string
    parse(value: number) {
      return String(value)
    }
  }
})
```

How can I protect this function call (return value doesn't matter right now) so that defaultValue is the parse argument value type and defaultValueOut has the same type as the ReturnType?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wQLnGW) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yep!  That is it.  I feel like I was close but pulled some of it out into other generics and you can't do that, but i've also done this and it doesn't work:
```
type InterfaceOptions<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Parser<infer I, infer O> ? Parser<I, O> : never
}
```

Anyway your solution definitely works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [the answer to the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77775154/2887218), it is more of an art than a science to write [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) functions so that inference does what you want it to do.

My approach is to minimize the number of generic type parameters and to try to express the intended restriction inside the [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) where possible.  It's not always possible to do that; some self-referencing constraints are accepted, but other quite similar ones are rejected.  When they are accepted you tend to get nicer error messages.

Anyway here that looks like

```
function createParser<
  T extends {
    [K in keyof T]: 
      T[K] extends { parse: ParserFunction<infer I, infer O> } ? Parser<I, O> : never
  }>(options: T) {
  return options; // to help testing below
}
```

And we can test out with your example:

```
const bad = createParser({
  pass: {
    defaultValue: '100',
    defaultValueOut: 100,
    parse(value: string) {
      return Number(value)
    }
  },
  fail: {
    defaultValue: '100', // error 
    // 'string' is not assignable to 'number'.
    defaultValueOut: 100, // error
    // 'number' is not assignable to 'string'.
    parse(value: number) {
      return String(value)
    }
  }
})
// const bad: {}, which is ‍♂️ until you fix it as shown below

const good = createParser({
  pass: {
    defaultValue: '100',
    defaultValueOut: 100,
    parse(value: string) {
      return Number(value)
    }
  },
  fail: {
    defaultValue: 100,
    defaultValueOut: "100",
    parse(value: number) {
      return String(value)
    }
  }
}) // okay
/* const good: {
    pass: {
        defaultValue: string;
        defaultValueOut: number;
        parse(value: string): number;
    };
    fail: {
        defaultValue: number;
        defaultValueOut: string;
        parse(value: number): string;
    };
} */
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.3.3#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-UV05ns6hQ-hw5Ho7H44nkyCwaBIBng0i84WS2XBaY5ca+GdOwg1TKNRAPl8oABlYDKpHyk1m65JU2N3FYfEown2y1QDHg-A4cFhqCAPg3AOy7gFgCQBCZIA8H9QNgBDcFA3QYNa+BlK0UYxlASDgpi3xotwmI4niUaIoQhBEqwWQ5Hk8xUoUNJ0g6QpOqKHKSvygqViKNb0BKvJWsYC4oMey4IQeKrrhumo7rqBqoFxEDlvU5pQJahQ2na9IVsK1YunWrH0UpzpisxUAAESSjpbGypxS6zFmIlrgpAlblqe68UeJkSRaZ6JBeABUmSYVA2G4fa84xuR6r1AxyncZOiKhBulFVppMTaWZhoRRuHEQGJip2aqK7mYliSJXJvmRY60XUZlCWBYVjHRLWYWJTKyWpVA8WoMIaWHuFZoyLsrkAtIQA)

Comment: This works!  It's just interesting that you have to narrow down the generic and you can't use: "extends Parser<infer I, infer O>..."