# Reference inferred literal type from generic type

Tags: typescript

I want to define a type `NodeDef` which defines a node in a graph execution framework. Each `NodeDef` has a `name`, a list `deps` of the nods it depends on (its inputs) and a function `compute` to compute its output based on the inputs.

I want to restrict the parameter of the `compute` function to be an object with the string literals specified under `deps` as properties:

```
type Nodes = {
    a: number;
    b: number;
    c: string;
};

type Node = keyof Nodes;

type NodeDef<N extends Node, D extends Node> = {
    name: N;
    deps: D[];
    compute: (deps: { [K in D]: Nodes[K] }) => Nodes[N];
};

type Graph = {
    [K in Node]?: NodeDef<K, Node>;
};
```

However, when I create a graph, config the type of the compute function is not properly offered:

```
const config: Graph = {
    a: {
        name: 'a',
        deps: ['b'],
        compute: ({ b, c }) => { // <-- 'c' shouldn't exist here
            return 2 * b + c.length; 
        },
    },
};
```

I would expect the inferred type to be:

```
(property) compute: (deps: {
    b: number;
}) => number
```

However, it is:

```
(property) compute: (deps: {
    a: number;
    b: number;
    c: string;
}) => number
```

How can I make TypeScript infer the type the way I want it?

Comment: You would need `Graph` to be generic to keep track of such things, meaning you'd need to either write `const config: Graph<{a: "b"}> = {⋯}` manually, or write a helper function to infer things, like `const config = graph({⋯})`, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/m3Kgqm).  Does that meet your needs?  If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz It does! I did notice that TypeScript reports false-positive errors or misses errors when unexpected content appears, e.g. when adding another node with `deps: ["a", "x"]` or a compute function that returns a wrong type. I guess, it's best to create this kind of helper function on the node level then?

Comment: I'm confused, where do you notice this? Without a [mre] as code I'm not sure how to respond.  Should I write up this answer as-is or are you reporting some problem with it I should address?

Comment: @jcalz See [this playground](https://shorturl.at/kFOU6), here `b` is not reported until `x` is removed. Ideally, `b` should still be reported, though your solution is already providing what I've asked.

Comment: Why would `b` be reported? Do you mean `c`?

Comment: Oh, sorry! You're right, I meant `c`.

Comment: Yeah that’s pretty much a limitation of the type checker; sometimes it just stops at the first error it finds and doesn’t keep probing afterward, so you have to fix the first error before you are warned about the second.  I’ll write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Graph` type uses `Node` as the `D` type argument in its `NodeDef<N, D>` properties, so every property of a `Graph` is apparently dependent on all the nodes.  If that's not what you want, then you'll need to come up with a way to plug in something more specific for the `D` type argument.  Well, it's possible to write `Graph` so that each property is a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of `NodeDef<K, D>` for *every possible* `D`, but that union would scale exponentially with the number of members of `Node`, which gets unusable fairly quickly.  So let's not try that.

So, you will want `Graph` to itself be [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) and take a type argument which represents the `D` types for each property.  So it should be `Graph<D>` and for each `K` in `keyof D`, the type of the property would be `NodeDef<K, D[K]>`.  Like this, maybe:

```
type Graph<D extends Record<keyof D, Node>> = {
  [K in Node & keyof D]: NodeDef<K, D[K]>
};
```

Here it is technically possible that `D` has keys that are not in `Node`, but these will be excluded from the result due to the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of `keyof D` with `Node`.

---

Now you can give your type a name, but it requires manual [annotation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables), which causes you to repeat yourself both with a value and with a type:

```
const config: Graph<{ a: "b" }> = {
  a: {
    name: 'a',
    deps: ['b'],
    compute: ({ b, c }) => { // error
      // --------> ~
      // Property 'c' does not exist on type '{ b: number; }'.
      return 2 * b + c.length;
    },
  },
};
```

That works exactly as you'd like, but you're forced to write `{a: "b"}` yourself.  It would be nice if TypeScript could just infer type arguments in generic types, but it can't.  It *can* infer type arguments when you call generic *functions*, though.  So you can provide a helper function called `graph()` which infers `D` for you, and replace annotation with a function call:

```
const config = graph({
  a: {
    name: 'a',
    deps: ['b'],
    compute: ({ b, c }) => { // error
      // --------> ~
      // Property 'c' does not exist on type '{ b: number; }'
      return 2 * b + c.length;
    },
  },
});
config;
// ^? const config: Graph<{ a: "b" }>
```

So now `config` is inferred to be of type `Graph<{a: "b"}` just by virtue of the argument to `graph()`.  All we have to do now is define `graph()`.

---

Here's one approach:

```
const graph = <const D extends Record<keyof D, Node>>(
  g: { [K in keyof D]: K extends Node ? NodeDef<K, D[K]> : never }
): Graph<D> => g;
```

TypeScript generic inference is a little tricky; it is possible to infer `D` from a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over the keys of `D` (i.e., if it's a *homomorphic* mapped type, see [What does "homomorphic mapped type" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59790508/2887218) for more info).  So it has to be `in keyof D` and not `in Node & keyof D`.  So I moved the "and `Node`" restriction to the property type, making it the [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) `K extends Node? NodeDef<K, D[K]> : never`.  Any key in `keyof D` that does not appear in `Node` will be mapped to `never`, and you'll get an error.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEANJBvAUEpAXAnjMgHID2AJtEgLwbY5IgBcSwArmAEYQBOA3PRycW7LrwEMk8FlFw8AlsADmEpAF8B9AkSRlKNJAGsI+UgDNdFaJpzaSVgCIQzAHmJIIAD1wRg5KJaUADRIDh7evv6BEAB8BliSoJAsxKo4lDBQLA4A2gC6aVKkYDBsPiwAFBlZGEg5ANJIiqF5KVZQDXnqAJQ0cXrQOcQF9BqYWoTIAOI8IDAAFi5hXj5+AQBKEPCkPOQuxqYWDiEDMXG0CQwNTcDRSABkRibmLW2UTq71Ibn1eTGjNiKwFkSCUswWBhc22BuFC4VWUU2212+2eRxOVjOFUEoJY6DqjWaBxeDlaSEaK0iAQGSAA-NEPi4vqFOnERBAAG68dT0bosGZzRYOc5xFTjWyTJAALQMAoWLnxzCQACJOMr1P96NCQdCzPIlABBfngxaKliq9Vqc50SRKy6JcAQFgAchAzqCOPSEEyLByzs4zryHskOG2JTKTqQFXxnBC8B6fVqAHokx4eDwdp6GCmkABafMF-NxAB+WZwOYAChmiDwCEhnfBnUhyKQqMBSLCvPIQaRbnZ6zGRBxuPx1M6AHRlpA8CC4Ng8W4AJiQACokJwkABqKTjgA2viUuHmhRwamDDDPAPGWt7Ot7eqUBjBgujOLtWaSkdd7qz1V9-sDc9JDDUpyijGM4wTag4nxHNeAzHgpxzQtCxLJDUyrUgazrBsmxbNsO3CbtYV7PBJWdQdWGHcQxynGc5wXJBlzXDdt3gPcDyPE91CAnjRm6VRdX1VQcwAPXpbVYSEpRjUFBVGHNNUNUwNQgA)