# How can I infer types from a generic where 1 type can be passed down and another type is within its own fields?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Sorry for the confusing title, I'll try to explain it more in detail.

Code:

```
type PgTable = {
  [k: string]: any
}

type TableParams<TTable extends PgTable, TJoin extends {[k: string]: TJoinResult<TTable>}> = {
  table: TTable,
  join: TJoin
}

type TJoinResult<TParent extends PgTable, TChild extends PgTable = PgTable> = {
  table: TChild,
  type: "inner" | "left" | "right",
  on: (parent: TParent, child: TChild) => string;
}

function typeParams<TTable extends PgTable, TJoin extends {[k: string]: TJoinResult<TTable>}>(params: TableParams<TTable, TJoin>) {
  // do stuff
}

const userTable = {
  id: "12345",
  firstName: "Bob",
  age: 45
} satisfies PgTable
const petsTable = {
  id: "123456",
  name: "Charlie",
  owner: "12345" // FK
} satisfies PgTable

typeParams({
  table: userTable,
  join: {
    pets: {
      table: petsTable,
      type: "inner",
      on: (parent, child) => `${parent.id} = ${child.owner}` // child is typed as PgTable and doesn't have Intellisense
    }
  }
})
```

I have 2 types in the playground, `TableParams` and `TJoinResult`. `TJoinResult` is called by `TableParams` and has 2 generic parameters, `TParent` and `TChild`. `TParent` is passed down from `TableParams`, while `TChild` is within its own type (`table` key).

I can't pass down `TChild` from `TableParams` since the child isn't declared there, but adding a default type for `TChild` always typecasts it as the default type. How can I have it so that both `TParent` and `TChild` are inferred correctly?

Comment: @jcalz sorry about that, added the code in the question.

Comment: It doesn't depend on drizzle, it's purely a typing question. I've removed the dependencies.

Comment: Okay, I've added example and made sure there's no errors.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NdJe0W) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: The approach looks great! It's a good start for me as I'm looking for something that works recursively, I can see if I can make it work that way. If not I may have to bug you again!

Comment: Are you saying you'd bug me again here and I should wait to write up an answer? Or you'd open a new question for the recursive case?

Comment: Sorry, I'll write up a new question if I need help, feel free to write up your approach! Thank you so much for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be tricky to get TypeScript to both infer [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type arguments and [contextually infer](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) function parameter types at the same time. Getting it to work is more of an art than a science, and sometimes it turns out to be impossible. There is a general open issue at [microsoft/TypeScript#47599](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47599) about this, and while support for this sort of thing has been improving steadily, there will probably always be situations in which you can't get exactly the behavior you want without either manually specifying type arguments or manually annotating function parameter types.  The example in this question seems to be solvable by some "standard" techniques, which is good, but do note that sometimes seemingly minor changes can make a problem change from being straightforward to solve to being difficult or impossible.

---

To guide inference for the `join` property of `TableParams`, it would be best for the second generic type parameter would correspond to an object whose property types are just the second type parameter for `JoinResult`.  That is, if `join` is of type `{a: JoinResult<T, A>, b: JoinResult<T, B>}`, then the type argument would be `{a: A, b: B}`.  Then we can write `join` as a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over that type parameter.  Like this:

```
type TableParams<
  T extends PgTable,
  J extends Record<keyof J, PgTable>> = {
    table: T,
    join: { [K in keyof J]: JoinResult<T, J[K]> }
  }

function typeParams<
  T extends PgTable,
  J extends Record<keyof J, PgTable>
>(params: TableParams<T, J>) {
  // do stuff
}
```

TypeScript is pretty good at inferring from *homomorphic* mapped types (see [What does "homomorphic mapped type" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59790508/2887218)), such as inferring `J` from `{[K in keyof J]: ⋯J[K]⋯}`.  This inference hopefully will happen early enough so that when you're calling `typeParams()`, the type of `J` will be available to give your `on` methods the contextual typing you're looking for from the `child` parameter:

```
typeParams({
  table: userTable,
  join: {
    pets: {
      table: petsTable,
      type: "inner",
      on: (parent, child) => `${parent.id} = ${child.owner}`
      // parent: { id: string; firstName: string; age: number; }
      // child: { id: string; name: string; owner: string; }
    }
  }
});
```

Looks good! The type argument for `J` is inferred from the `join.pets.table` property to be `{pets: { id: string; name: string; owner: string} }`, and thus `child.owner` is seen as being of type `string` and not `any`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-cOhC8xygQ4mZzH3lDASC6bHGeuVLyDGAJTKFRqmDsAAMACQ4HLr4AAOgVXFlx9K5Q056zOa4+9HhCLp-y-YeivqjDgjRQPqhrACaPQ+H+TRQHaPgMFIPQoEEgEgsuHJcneFTfiGfINABUBxuBFCQXhT5BERtD-sho4oTwXBVEAA)

Comment: Why is `J` constrained to `Record<keyof J, PgTable>` and not just `Record<string, PgTable>`? Things still seem to work with `string`. Does`keyof J` aid in inference in some way, for example, as you say, allowing it to "happen early enough"?

Comment: Constraining to `Record<string, PgTable>` will end up prohibiting interfaces from working (see [ms/TS#15300](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300))... this might not matter for the use cases shown here but I generally use `T extends Record<keyof T, V>>` when trying to constrain values without constraining keys.

Answer (score 0):

```
type PgTable = {
  [k: string]: any;
};

type TableParams<TTable extends PgTable, TJoin extends { [k: string]: TJoinResult<TTable, any> }> = {
  table: TTable;
  join: TJoin;
};

type TJoinResult<TParent extends PgTable, TChild extends PgTable> = {
    table: TChild;
    type: "inner" | "left" | "right";
    on: (parent: TParent, child: TChild) => string;
};

// Helper type to get the table type from TJoinResult
type TableType<TJoin extends TJoinResult<any, any>> = TJoin extends TJoinResult<infer T, any> ? T : never;

function typeParams<TTable extends PgTable, TJoin extends { [k: string]: TJoinResult<TTable, any> }>(params: TableParams<TTable, TJoin>) {
  // do stuff
}

const userTable = {
  id: "12345",
  firstName: "Bob",
  age: 45
} as PgTable;
const petsTable = {
  id: "123456",
  name: "Charlie",
  owner: "12345" // FK
} as PgTable;

typeParams({
  table: userTable,
  join: {
    pets: {
      table: petsTable,
      type: "inner",
      on: (parent, child) => `${parent.id} = ${child.owner}`
    } as TJoinResult<typeof userTable, TableType<typeof userTable["id"]>>
  }
});
```

I created a helper type `TableType` to extract the table type from `TJoinResult`. Then, when calling `typeParams`, I used `typeof userTable` to infer the correct type for `TTable`, and `TableType<typeof userTable["id"]>` to infer the correct type for `TChild` within the `pets` join.