# Creating a generic type in TypeScript for dynamically appending property postfixes

Tags: typescript, types

in typescript i would like to create a generic, which i can use to add PropertyKeys with a specfic Postfix to an existing type. Each Postfix should hold also a type for a value. The following code illustrates, what the goal is:

```js
// Example how to use
type OriginalType = {
  name?: string;
  age?: number;
  // any other property
};

type ModifiedType = AddPostfixes<
  OriginalType,
  { Postfix1: number; Postfix2: string; Postfix3: boolean } // here the Postfixes with their related type should be defined
>;

// current implementation
type AddPostfixes<T, Postfixes extends Record<string, any>> = {
  [K in keyof T as `${K & string}${string &
    keyof Postfixes}`]: K extends `${string & infer Prefix}${string &
    keyof Postfixes}`
    ? Prefix extends keyof Postfixes
      ? Postfixes[keyof Postfixes]
      : never
    : K extends keyof T
    ? T[K]
    : Postfixes[string & keyof Postfixes];
} & T;


// expected/prefered type for ModifiedType in this case
type ModifiedTypeExpected = {
  namePostfix1?: number;
  namePostfix2?: string;
  namePostfix3?: boolean;
  agePostfix1?: number;
  agePostfix2?: string;
  agePostfix3?: boolean;
} & OriginalType;

// actual type i have now for ModifiedType in this case
type ModifiedTypeActual = {
  name?: string;
  age?: number;
  namePostfix1?: string;
  namePostfix2?: string;
  namePostfix3?: string;
  agePostfix1?: number;
  agePostfix2?: number;
  agePostfix3?: number;
};

const m: ModifiedType = {};
export {};
```

Additional note: The added prefixes must be optional whenever in the base key is optional.
So i.e.

```js
type MyOriginalType = {
name: string;
age?: age;
}

// agePostfix1, agePostfix2, agePostfix3 has to be optional too
type PostfixedType = AddPostfixes<MyOriginalType>;
```

The resulting postfixes key should be also optional.

Thanks for any help to fix the generic type `AddPostfixes`.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NB1pnw) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Nearly, currently the postfixed keys do not have the right type for the value. I updated my question with a link, where you can see the requirement at the bottom of the code and your current state of solution. Thanks for your help

Comment: Sorry, about that, does [this version](https://tsplay.dev/NB1Mkw) work for you?  (Also, please remove that [edit] from the question since it's just a comment reply, right? It's not really appropriate to modify the question to incorporate suggestions, especially unattributed ones. )

Comment: Thank you very much. This is the solution now. I apologize, i removed that edit. I do not know how to add readable links like you inside comment reply. I only have buttons in the edit question dialog or when i provide an answer to my own question, but no hyperlink button in the comment reply textarea. If you could provide an explaination for your coded solution this would be awesome, then i will mark it as the final answer.  Thanks again!

Comment: I will do so when I have a chance. ... oh, and I use https://tsplay.dev/ to give short TS playground links, if that helps

Comment: awesome thanks. I will use this next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
type AddPostfixes<T extends object, P extends object> = T & ({ [KP in keyof P]:
    (x: { [KT in keyof T as `${Exclude<KT, symbol>}${Exclude<KP, symbol>}`]: P[KP]
    }) => void } extends Record<string, (x: infer I) => void> ? I : never)
```

Your requirement that [optional properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#optional-properties) in the first type `T` argument map to optional suffixed properties in the output makes it a little more complicated.  In order to preserve optionality you want to write a *homomorphic* [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html), (see [What does "homomorphic mapped type" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59790508/2887218)) which means that somewhere in the answer you're going to see something like `{[KT in keyof T]: ⋯}` even though for the property value types themselves this wouldn't be necessary.  Anyway, here's how it works:

We make a mapped type over both the original `T` object type and the postfix `P` object type, so that we we iterate over every property key `KT` of `T` and every property key `KP`.  Then we basically want the output to have a key of type `` `${KT}${KP}` `` with a value of type `P[KP]`.  This is a little easier said than done.

First, we have to make sure the keys can be serialized into [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html), requiring things like `Exclude<KT, symbol>` or `KT & string` or maybe `KT & (string | number)`

Then, a nested mapped type would end up giving you things like `{Postfix1: {namePostfix1?: number, ⋯}, Postfix2: {namePostfix2?: number ⋯}, ⋯}` but you want just those inner properties combined into a single type.  That requires something like generating the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of all the properties of the mapped type.  To do that programmatically requires some type juggling; in the above I use an approach similar to that of [Transform union type to intersection type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50374908/2887218), where I put all the pieces in a *contravariant* type position, and then [`infer` from that](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types) to get the intersection.

That's mostly it.  Yes, we need to intersect the whole thing with `T`.  So, that gives this result:

```
type OriginalType = {
    name?: string;
    age?: number;
    otherProp: Date;
};

type ModifiedType = AddPostfixes<
    OriginalType,
    { Postfix1: number; Postfix2: string; Postfix3: boolean }
>;    

/* type ModifiedType = OriginalType & {
    namePostfix1?: number | undefined;
    agePostfix1?: number | undefined;
    otherPropPostfix1: number;
} & {
    namePostfix2?: string | undefined;
    agePostfix2?: string | undefined;
    otherPropPostfix2: string;
} & {
    namePostfix3?: boolean | undefined;
    agePostfix3?: boolean | undefined;
    otherPropPostfix3: boolean;
} */
```

This is what you want, mostly.  It is possible to collapse this into a single object type via another mapped type:

```
type APF<T extends object, P extends object> =
    { [K in keyof AddPostfixes<T, P>]: AddPostfixes<T, P>[K] };
type MT = APF<OriginalType, { Postfix1: number; Postfix2: string; Postfix3: boolean }>;
/* type MT = {
    name?: string | undefined;
    age?: number | undefined;
    otherProp: Date;
    namePostfix1?: number | undefined;
    agePostfix1?: number | undefined;
    otherPropPostfix1: number;
    namePostfix2?: string | undefined;
    agePostfix2?: string | undefined;
    otherPropPostfix2: string;
    namePostfix3?: boolean | undefined;
    agePostfix3?: boolean | undefined;
    otherPropPostfix3: boolean;
} */
```

but I don't know whether or not that really matters.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#code/FAFwngDgpgBAggEwQBQPYGcQDMCWAPKdAHgBUYo8QoA7BdGVAIwCsoBjEAGhmXMproMW7EAD4YAXhhkAZDAAUAbxgBtANK8c1GAGsoYVFh4BdAFzAYlhXlMxl6slt37D0mAEN6AAwAkigKJ4bAA2AK4IUERqJNzoYAC2jKjBogC+foEh4ZEasQlJKaleZjzqyMYWVqkAlJLiAG6oOAgwqXxUtPQASuyoAE4IRJh9WgDm3PI2MFpYUH0wAJK1Eg1NCOIA-IswttRQ9XPVwKCQsADyI6Na7sEkp5J2lZbU7vFQG7bDYwDcTx6j712oUSc1+VgYIAAFnNkH1UBBbAARdxUX6pX4naAwACyqAQOFwUAQdyxUkQKAw2HwhCIfwuOCuL1up04f2UaEwuDwAEYgSC+t8eJSuQAmT4gEbUUaCjlUvAAZlsSWSUHc2lSwFEGOAAHoAFQwcBY3H4wnE+5SemMm4k2ByRR-F5vWVc7kfGDUYGMOYwAA+MFCtCguD2CDBVncAJd+DdfO9839gYiIaJ4csqChMLhEGjPLjoOAbXtjteUFzIvdXylfoDQZTYb+kbLwvwFfFktGNaTwa0qb+GehfVh8PL7Z+hZgxfBTubnPw8vdyuCqu0ibrvYb4KbuYXStQKrVXfXobTEMHw5zLYVe4P1DRMD1OuORtgcGQADFSO0BPQmKwONwvAUB0gh-iI4gSGyqhqNM2h6AYRjkrmNIxDwoglEhV4oYBojqMYrS-C+OJkGSH5EFa1zMtA3DslevIel6oJCnOeBijAVbSsxcqKjAS4rq0Wq6gaRHYiRjzTqWlYSmMR7Jhup5Nu6nr8rJPYnv2mZDtmSIolAp4zrmsYMSpa5yepW5RnRSmMQmtZmX24IDlmI50fmAols6V5tux0nVqZakORGlksd5HGqfWp5OVpLkhWOUr6aWO6Lvuy6Hv5EWNsF3HJbe4XyRp57ZjuN6pXeE6PkAA)