# Why use `Exclude` implement Typescript utility types `Omit` can not keep readonly property?

Tags: typescript

Why are the results of `result1` and  `result` `result2` different?  `result1` will lose the `readonly` attribute.
My TypeScript vision is 5.3.2

Can someone explain it to me ?

```js
interface obj {
  readonly title: string;
  desc?: string;
  author: string;
}

type result = Omit<obj, "desc">;
// result = {
//   readonly title: string;
//   author: string;
// }

type result1 = {
  [K in Exclude<keyof obj, "desc">]: obj[K];
};
// result1 = {
//   title: string; // miss readonly property
//   author: string;
// }

type result2 = {
  [K in keyof obj as K extends "desc" ? never : K]: obj[K];
};
// type result2 = {
//   readonly title: string;
//   author: string;
// }
```

If we don't inline `Exclude<keyof obj, "desc">` there won't be a problem

Comment: This is discussed in [Design Meeting Notes, 3/8/2022
#53169](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/53169): Today, Omit is non-homomorphic. Will not preserve shape. Why? `keyof` on its own does not retain its source type. Also see [Break Pick and Omit #53188](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/53188/files)

Comment: @Lesiak That's weird, `Omit` is definitely "homomorphic" (otherwise the `result` above would look like `result1` and not `result2`).  The real answer here is that `resul1` is not using a homomorphic mapped type because it's not directly `in keyof` or `in K` where `K` is constrained to `keyof ...`.

Comment: @jcalz the meeting notes come from 2022, before the behaviour of Omit was changed by the pull request I linked

Comment: But you say "Today, Omit is non-homomorphic", but that's not true, right?  I mean, it now *is* "homomorphic" (which is a weird term for something that drops properties, but that's what we have.)

Comment: Anyway, @leon2wu, the answer to this is that `Omit` and `in keyof obj` are homomorphic mapped types, but `in Exclude` are not, as explained in the answer to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59790508/what-does-homomorphic-mapped-type-mean).  Does that fully address your question? If so we can point to that; if not, what's missing?

Comment: Sorry for misleading quote, "today" in my comment comes from the meeting notes refers to 2022. Now Omit keeps the shape of the input object.

Comment: @jcalz I think one more thing that adds to the confusion is that TS Playground shows old Omit definition `type Omit<T, K extends string | number | symbol> = { [P in Exclude<keyof T, K>]: T[P]; }` but resulting type seems to use the new one. [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&jsx=0&ts=5.3.3#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPYCMBWyDeAoZZKCOAE1RABsBPZMYMSiALmQGcwpQBzAbgOSkIbBAH5WHLiD4C4AVzAALVFAmce-AL548YagAcUxNnMphkAXmQB5ALYMAPBkwAaZACIhI9wD5+hAMCggHpggD1RIA)

Comment: The type display is inlining the definition of `Pick` but that isn't identical because when you inline things it can change things.  TS does that sometimes, and it's annoying (because you can't just copy and paste the displayed type and be sure you're preserving the behavior)