# TypeScript: Implement type constrain on parameter of functions inside a record passed as argument to another function

Tags: typescript, generic-type-parameters

I have a function that accepts a `Record` with event listener callbacks as values. I'd like to enforce that the first argument of an event callback within this record is typed as a `CustomEvent<PayloadThatConformsToABaseType>`. I've tried the following:

```js
type EventPayload = string | number;
interface CustomEvent<T> { payload: T }

function registerListeners<T extends EventPayload>(
  listeners: Record<string, (e: CustomEvent<T>) => void>
) {}
// Gets inferred as `registerListeners<"hello">(listeners: Record<string, (e: CustomEvent<"hello">) => void>): void`
// Type '"hello"' is not assignable to type '2'.
registerListeners({
    eventOne: (event: CustomEvent<'hello'>) => {},
    eventTwo: (event: CustomEvent<2>) => {}
})


function registerListeners(
  listeners: Record<string, <T extends EventPayload>(e: CustomEvent<T>) => void>
) {}
// Gets inferred as `registerListeners(listeners: Record<string, <T extends EventPayload>(e: CustomEvent<T>) => void>): void`
// Type 'EventPayload' is not assignable to type '"hello"'
registerListeners({
    eventOne: (event: CustomEvent<'hello'>) => {},
    eventTwo: (event: CustomEvent<2>) => {}
})

function registerListeners(listeners: Record<string, (e: CustomEvent<any>) => void>) {}
// Works but I can no longer constrain the event params
registerListeners({
    eventOne: (event: CustomEvent<'hello'>) => {},
    eventTwo: (event: CustomEvent<{a: string}>) => {}
})
```

How do I enforce that the callbacks passed to `registerListeners` accept an acceptable event as argument?

[TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogbhAdsACgQxAGwPZoCZQC8UAzsAE4CWiA5lAD5SICuAtgEYTkDcAUNcC4AzNAGNoAYWZlsreEmAAeACoA+KAG9eUHVDAYc+AFxRlvAL69eQ5olHBK2RFHIQalMlwAyHwYi4kABSYvkgBJgBKEKLY5HiKZFS0ADRQgRAmUjJyCMiKaIggqgCUROpw2JR4JZqWvK7unuQ+nv7kQVq6UBC5wADy-ibpvZnSwLLyeQDkABYQmDhTNYTqGubJ2ro9CsoA7thD28ij2ZNKGmgmidQ05surlubFvEA)

Comment: I think you want to use a mapped type as shown in [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WJ3Kkw). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yeah that does exactly what I want - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to use a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) where the [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter `T` corresponds to the type argument to `CustomEvent` for each key (e.g., for your example, the type argument for `T` would be `{ eventOne: "hello"; eventTwo: 2; }`.  Like this:

```
function registerListeners<T extends Record<keyof T, EventPayload>>(
    listeners: { [K in keyof T]: (e: CustomEvent<T[K]>) => void }
) { }
```

Because this is a *homomorphic mapped type* (see [What does "homomorphic mapped type" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59790508/2887218)) then the compiler knows how to infer from it when you call `registerListeners()`:

```
registerListeners({
    eventOne: (event: CustomEvent<'hello'>) => { },
    eventTwo: (event: CustomEvent<2>) => { }
})
```

If you inspect with IntelliSense, you'll see that `T` is inferred as `{ eventOne: "hello"; eventTwo: 2; }` as expected. Depending on the use case you could then go on to compute other types that depend on `T` (in general the function might return something that needs to keep track of which events go with which keys).

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogbhAdsACgQxAGwPZoCZQC8UAzsAE4CWiA5lAD5SICuAtgEYTkDcAUNcC4AzNAGNoAYWZlsreEmAAeACoA+KAG9eUHVDAYc+AFxRlvAL69eQ5olHBK2RFHIQalMlwAyHwYi4kKlAQAB5+eCRQAEoQotjkeIoA1hAg2EKmADSwCMjoWLh4qqoAFNq6mL5IASYaUADaANJQ1FApaRnKALomJRAmUjJyuUrKTV2qAJRE6nDYlASW03WWvK7unuQ+nv7kJCVausEjAPL+vRAjA9LAsvLIigDkABYQmDiPUzOaUOaZ5TpLgplAB3bAXK5QQa3YYKRQAJi+hHUKwsk14AHoMaYWoghFxXAQ0JE6kDkGd+lAAESvd7YKncY7AsEmeGM1ZAA)

Comment: To expand on this - what would the implementation look like if the keys of the object passed to registerListeners were not known statically but had an index signature of string? The mapped type wouldn't work in that case so is that something that could be typed correctly with an enforced constraint but without having to widen the type of the callbacks in the object at the call site?

Comment: The mapped type would work fine, why wouldn't it? If you're saying: "I wouldn't know what type to assign my object to in the first place" then the only safe supertype of the input you want is `{[k: string]: Listener<never>}`, but presumably you'd run into that completely independently of `registerListeners()`.  And even then, this only works because `Listener<T>` is contravariant in `T`.  What is the point of a listener whose event type you don't keep track of? Maybe you'd want it to be a *pair* like `[T, Listener<T>]`, but then it's *invariant* and there's no safe index signature you can use.

Comment: And this is out of scope for the question as asked. If you have followup questions you might want to post them separately.

Answer (score 0):

I like Jcalz playground.  I wouldn't have thought to do it that way.  It seems very elegant.  I would type the listener as a generic like so...

```
type EventPayload = string | number;
type CustomEventHandler<T extends EventPayload> = { payload: T }
type Listener <T extends EventPayload> =  (arg:CustomEventHandler<T>)=> void

function registerListeners(
  listeners: Record<string, Listener<never>>
) {}


registerListeners({
  event1:(arg:CustomEventHandler<"hello">)=>{},
  event3:(arg:CustomEventHandler<2>)=>{}
})
```

The reason your method is failing is that since you've made `regiserListeners` generic, the first type that is infered for T is expected to be the same type for all of the event listeners.  My example allows each listener to have a constraint, but is not forced to have the same constraint as its siblings.

Comment: This is a good idea. Since the question doesn't actually do anything with the `T` inferred for `registerListeners()`, then it isn't strictly necessary for `registerListeners()` to be generic, as long as it accepts a narrow-enough supertype of all `Listener`s for each property.  And since `Listener<T>` is *contravariant* in `T`, there is such a type: `Listener<never>`.  You might want to [edit] to explain why `Listener<never>` works as opposed to, say, `Listener<EventPayload>`, which is what most people might expect here.